# Plotting several functions

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, faq

I'd like to plot a function of one real and one integer variable, but I don't want them all shown in the same 2-D plot - I'd like to see them as separate curves so I can see both "axes", more like how `Plot3D` works.  I'm sure *Mathematica* can do this, but how?

**Edit:** Rephrased, I'd like to `Plot3D` a function of one real and one integer variable.  Instead of seeing a surface, I'd like a discrete set of curves in three space.

Comment: [A rather similar question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Mesh` will do the trick:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x^2 - y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 30]
```

[image: surface with mesh]

Placing the “wires” on integer values is also easy – see example below. For the range `{y, -7, 5}` there are 13 integers so you need to ask for 11 wires `Mesh -> 11` (in red) because 2 are taken by boundary (blue). With such settings "wires" fall exactly on integer values.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x^2 - y/2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -7, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 11, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

[image: surface with mesh on integers]

Comment: If one takes this route with some function `f[n, x]` where `n` can only take integer values, use the function `f[Round[n], x]` within `Plot3D[]`.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, thanks!

Comment: great answer. and very elegant.

Answer (score 41):

Do you mean something like this?

```
f[n_, x_] := Sin[x (1 + n/10)]
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[{x, n, f[n, x]}, {n, 20}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm curious to the reason Evaluate is there. Is it required?

Comment: @BeauGeste No, it's not required, but it makes the function evaluate faster and the graphs are plotted in different colours. This has to do with the fact that `ParametricPlot3D` (as well as all other members of the `Plot` family) has attribute `HoldAll` which means that without `Evaluate` the `Table` expression would be reevaluated for every value of `x`. With `Evaluate` the `Table` is expanded into an explicit list before it is used by `ParametricPlot3D` making the evaluation much faster.

Comment: @BeauGeste you want `ParametricPlot3D` to see the list of functions, not the `Table` object.  You can also use `ParametricPlot3D[#, . . .] & Table[ . . . ]` which I prefer.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1396/121

Answer (score 20):

I'm bored, so here is a recreation of Heike's plot without `ParametricPlot3D`

```
Graphics3D[
  Table[
    Cases[
      Plot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
      Line[x_] :> {ColorData[1][n], Line[{#,n,#2} & @@@ x]},
      {4}
    ],
    {n, 20}
  ],
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 17):

Once upon a time, old versions of *Mathematica* had a package called [`` Graphics`Graphics3D` ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/Graphics/Graphics3D.html), which featured a neat little utility called `StackGraphics[]` that did exactly what OP wanted. Since the current versions of *Mathematica* no longer support this package, we are lucky that the upgrading information in the help file features [some code for mimicking the functionality of `StackGraphics[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/Graphics3D.html#562121501), which you can easily adapt to your circumstances:

```
f[n_Integer, x_] := Sin[x (1 + n/10)];
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[
  Cases[#, Line[L_] :> {ColorData[1][First[#2]], 
      Line[Thread[{L[[All, 1]], First[#2], L[[All, 2]]}]]}, -1] &, 
  Table[Plot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {n, 20}]], Axes -> True, 
 ViewPoint -> {.4, -1., .5}]
```

[image: stacked graphics]

---

Of course, if your `Plot[]`s use the `ColorFunction` option, stacking graphics is a bit more complicated, since the output internally uses a `GraphicsComplex[]` object as opposed to a plain Jane `Line[]`. In that case, something like the following has to be done:

```
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[
  Cases[#1, GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[Function[pt, Riffle[pt, First[#2]]] /@ pts, rest], -1]&, 
  Table[Plot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
        ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][ArcCos[Cos[Pi (n/5 - #2)]]/Pi]&)],
        {n, 10}]], Axes -> True, ViewPoint -> {.4, -1., .5}]
```

[image: stacked graphics with ColorFunction option]

Answer (score 3):

Since *v12.3*, we have `ListLinePlot3D`, so we can do something like:

```
domain = {{-2, 2}, {-3, 3}};

ListLinePlot3D[Array[{x, y} |-> Sin[x^2 - y], {50, 15}, domain]\[Transpose], 
 DataRange -> domain, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Alternatively (slower and less elegant, but easier to understand):

```
{{xL, xR}, {yL, yR}} = {{-2, 2}, {-3, 3}};
pointsx = 50; pointsy = 15;
ListLinePlot3D[
 Table[{x, y, Sin[x^2 - y]}, {y, yL, yR, (yR - yL)/(pointsy - 1)}, {x, xL, xR, (
   xR - xL)/(pointsx - 1)}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Case of explicit functions:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[{ww, zz, Exp[-(ww - 0.5 zz)^2/zz^2]}, 
    {zz, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2}}]], {ww, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Yellow, Thick}, 
                  {Green, Thick}, {Magenta, Thick}}]
```

Case of interpolating functions:

```
mmax = 4;    
tm = Table[m, {m, 1, mmax}];
tap = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
tfp = Table[(n - 1)^m, {m, 1, mmax}, {n, 1, 10}];
tif = Table[{tap[[n]], tfp[[m, n]]}, {m, 1, Length[tfp]}, {n, 1, Length[tap]}]
tg = Table[Interpolation[tif[[m]]], {m, 1, mmax}];
ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[Table[{x, zz, tg[[zz]][x]}, {zz, tm}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}, {Magenta, Thick}}]
```

Comment: Hi ! But how is your answer different than Heike's ?