# About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, special-functions

I have some questions for multiroot search for transcendental equations. Is there any clever solution to find all the roots for a transcendental equation in a specific range?

Perhaps `FindRoot` is the most efficient way to solve transcendental equations, but it only gives one root around a specific value. For example,

```
FindRoot[BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 10}]
```

Of course, one can first `Plot` the equation and then choose several start values around each root and then use `FindRoot` to get the exact value.

1. **Is there any elegant way to find all the roots at once?**

   Actually, I come up with this question when I solve the eigenequation for optical waveguides and I want to get the dispersion relation. I find `ContourPlot` is very useful to get the curve of the dispersion relation. For example,

   ```
   ContourPlot[BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin@Sin[a*x] == 0, {x, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 4}]
   ```

   You can get

   [image]
2. **Is there any elegant way to get all the values in the `ContourPlot` for `x` when `a==0` ?**
3. **Is it possible to know how the `ContourPlot` gets all the points shown in the figure? Perhaps we can harness it to get all the roots for the transcendental equation.**

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275). Anyway, for finding the roots of a function of a single variable, you can directly use the output of `Plot[]` to find initial approximations for `FindRoot[]`. If you're interested in that approach, I can write up an answer.

Comment: @J.M.   I'm expecting for your answer ~~

Comment: A tiny comment on `Reduce[]`-based methods: all of these hinge on the fact that `Reduce[]` apparently knows quite a fair bit about the transcendental functions built within *Mathematica*. If, however, you are dealing with a black-box function that can only evaluate at numerical values (you can simulate this behavior with something like `f[x_?NumericQ] := Haversine[Pi x]`), then `Reduce[]` won't be able to do much.

Comment: @J.M.  Yes, I have tried Reduce[], and I find it is very slow, especially for a much more complex equation.

Comment: @yulinlinyu It seems you wanted to accept a few answers. You can accept ONLY ONE of the answers (clicking the green tick beside an answer), which you find the most helpful. You can upvote EVERY answer you find helpful or downvote if you find an answer misleading.

Comment: I think here should be added a tag `special-functions` and a new one `transcendental` since we have in the question e.g. `Sin[Sin[x]]`.  There were 6 editors of the OP so I wouldn't like to be another one.

Comment: @Artes,  Thank U for your advise.

Comment: @Artes: I don't quite see the point of a [tag:transcendental] tag just yet...

Comment: @J.M. Did you mean the point of a transcendental tag to this question or in general ?  I could point out right now about 5 questions (this one among them) which should be tagged with that.

Comment: In general, @Artes. An example off the top of my head: a solution to a question tagged [tag:equation-solving] would either be general or be specialized to algebraic cases, and we don't have an [tag:algebraic] tag, do we?

Comment: @J.M. We have the `polynomials` tag,   mathematics behind solving transcendental equations is really a step forward, e.g. see http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/

Comment: Not terribly convinced, @Artes. The watershed is "algebraics" and "everything else", yes? By convention we have elected to use the term "transcendental" for "everything else"; i.e., it's not a special case, and I don't see the need for a distinction for things that aren't a special case. If you want to argue further, maybe you should start a meta thread and see what other people say...

Comment: I mean programming behind transcendental mathematics deserves to be distinguished among the rest of the world. Yes, I'll start soon (as soon as find a bit of time) this thread on meta.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Borrowing almost verbatim from a recent response about finding [extrema](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/5591#5591), here is a method that is useful when your function is differentiable and hence can be "tracked" by `NDSolve`.

```
f[x_] := BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]]

In[191]:= zeros = 
 Reap[soln = 
    y[x] /. First[
      NDSolve[{y'[x] == Evaluate[D[f[x], x]], y[10] == (f[10])}, 
       y[x], {x, 10, 0}, 
       Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y[x], 
         "EventAction" :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]}]]][[2, 1]]


During evaluation of In[191]:=
NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point
x == 1.5232626281716416`*^-124. >>

Out[191]= {{9.39114, 8.98587*10^-16}, {6.32397, -3.53884*10^-16},
           {3.03297, -8.45169*10^-13}, {0.886605, -4.02456*10^-15}}

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[zeros]}]
```

[image: function and roots]

If it were a trickier function, one might use `Method -> {"Projection", ...}` to enforce the condition that `y[x]` is really the same as `f[x]`. This method may be useful in situations (if you can find them) where we have one function in one variable, and `Reduce` either cannot handle it or takes a long time to do so.

---

**Addendum by J. M.**

`WhenEvent` is now the documented way to include event detection in `NDSolve`, so using it along with the trick of [specifying an empty list where the function should be](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html#32663), here's how to get a pile of zeroes:

```
f[x_] := BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]]

zeros = Reap[NDSolve[{y'[x] == D[f[x], x], WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[{x, y[x]}]],
                      y[10] == f[10]}, {}, {x, 10, 0}]][[-1, 1]];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[zeros]}]
```

[image: function and roots]

Comment: @ Daniel Lichtblau,  it's a very clever, efficient and general way to get all the roots and can be harnessed in many other cases. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Excellent! However, this method doesn't work in v10, possibly a bug.

Comment: @luyuwuli Thanks for pointing that out. I tracked this to an option setting change wherein the default became `MaxSteps -> Infinity`. You can restore the behavior shown above with an explicit `MaxSteps -> 10000`. I will ask in house about whether the change is for the better given that it can cause an example like this to hang.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, this is a bug that I think is not related to the MaxSteps -> Automatic change - at least not directly. You can get this to work with `NDSolve[{y'[x] == Evaluate[D[f[x], x]], y[10] == (f[10])}, 
 y[x], {x, 10, 10^-16}, 
 Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> y[x], 
   "EventAction" :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]}]` where the 0 is replaced with a small number.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Neat. It seems this method with does not work for zeroes of complex functions. For example I get the error ""Part 1 of {} does not exist." with pure imaginary Sin[x]/Sin[I*x]. Can it be used for complex functions?

Comment: @Nigel I think for complex-valued functions one will need to track real and imaginary parts both as a function of a real parameter.

Answer (score 34):

I might as well elaborate on my comment. Here is a modification of Stan Wagon's `FindAllCrossings[]` function (from his book *Mathematica in Action*, second edition) that uses `Plot[]` to generate the initial approximations to be subsequently polished by `FindRoot[]`:

```
Options[FindAllCrossings] = 
  Sort[Join[Options[FindRoot], {MaxRecursion -> Automatic,
       PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotPoints -> Automatic}]];

FindAllCrossings[f_, {t_, a_, b_}, opts___] := Module[{r, s, s1, ya},
       {r, ya} = Transpose[First[Cases[Normal[
                 Plot[f, {t, a, b}, Method -> Automatic,
                 Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
                 FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings]], 
                             Options[Plot]]]]], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity]]];
       s1 = Sign[ya]; If[ ! MemberQ[Abs[s1], 1], Return[{}]];
       s = Times @@@ Partition[s1, 2, 1];
       If[MemberQ[s, -1] || MemberQ[Take[s, {2, -2}], 0], 
          Union[Join[Pick[r, s1, 0], 
                Select[t /. Map[FindRoot[f, {t, r[[#]], r[[# + 1]]}, 
                       Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
                       FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings]], 
                                   Options[FindRoot]]]] &,
                       Flatten[Position[s, -1]]], a <= # <= b &]]], {}]]
```

Try it out:

```
FindAllCrossings[BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 100},
      WorkingPrecision -> 20]

{0.88660463531346207679, 3.0329660890136683539,
 6.3239665137114782212, 9.3911434075850854017, 12.589067252797192964,
 15.687789316501627036, 18.865248000326751595, 21.976728589463954937,
 25.144727536576135544, 28.263111694495812775, 31.425621611972587076,
 34.548333253230934213, 37.707250582575859710, 40.832929091244028281,
 43.989309899299199529, 47.117149292753968158, 50.271642808648651326,
 53.401126310508732375, 56.554160423425108364, 59.684936863656120488,
 62.836808589969946989, 65.968628466404205710, 69.119552435670107405,
 72.252232119042699356, 75.402368490602128759, 78.535768909563822046,
 81.685240379776511855, 84.819253682565487033, 87.968156330842562535,
 91.102697190752433240, 94.251107663305908556, 97.386107414041584404}
```

---

A different implementation involves the use of the `MeshFunctions` option of `Plot[]` to generate the seeds. Here's how it looks:

```
FindAllCrossings[f_, {t_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{r},
    r = Cases[Normal[Plot[f, {t, a, b}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0}},
                          Method -> Automatic, Evaluate[Sequence @@
                          FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings]],
                                      Options[Plot]]]]], 
              Point[p_] :> SetPrecision[p[[1]], OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]], 
              Infinity];
    If[r =!= {},
       Union[Select[t /. Map[FindRoot[f, {t, #}, Evaluate[Sequence @@
                                      FilterRules[Join[{opts},
                                                  Options[FindAllCrossings]],
                                                  Options[FindRoot]]]] &, r],
                              a <= # <= b &]], {}]]
```

This version might be a bit faster in some cases, but it no longer has the safety feature of root bracketing in the previous version.

Comment: Of course, this method won't find even-order multiple roots (i.e. tangencies to the horizontal axis), but almost any numerical method will have difficulty with them anyway. If you know for certain that there are tangencies within the range of interest, you might consider using `FindMinimum[]`/`FindMaximum[]` instead to find them.

Comment: Usage example here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94881/193

Comment: @J. M. Nice answer. It seems this method with FindAllCrossings[] does not work for zeroes of complex functions. For example I get the error "First::first: "{} has a length of zero and no first element." with pure imaginary Sin[x]/Sin[I*x]. Can it be used for complex functions?

Comment: @Nigel, the function here would not work directly since `Plot[]` does not work for complex functions. One might try using [`FindAllCrossings2D[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/) on the real and imaginary parts, tho.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion maybe in the case of even-order multiple roots one could perturb the original function find the splitted roots, decrease the perturbation parameter by two and find them again (maybe repeat that one more time) then extrapolate (or just use the initial splitted roots and take the middle as an approximation).

Answer (score 23):

One can use `Solve` as well, e.g.

```
s = Solve[ BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[ Sin[x]] == 0 && 0 < x < 10, x]
```

> ```
> Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >> 
>
> {{x -> Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
>  0.886604635313462076794393681674}]}, 
> {x -> Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
>  3.03296608901366835385376172847}]}, 
> {x -> Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
>  6.32396651371147786252003752922}]}, 
> {x -> Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
>  9.39114340758508579766919382120}]}}
> ```

`Solve` similarly as `Reduce` cannot prove that the set of solutions is complete. It returns the result in the form of rules but we can show that they return the same set solutions e.g. :

```
r = Reduce[ BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[ Sin[x]] == 0 && 0 < x < 10, x];
s[[All, 1, 2]] == List @@ r[[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> Reduce::incs: Warning: Reduce was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>
>
> True
> ```

**Edit**

Defining

```
f[x_, a_] := BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[a x]]
```

we can visualise the graphs of functions `f[x,a]` making use of `ParametricPlot3D` (look at answers to t[his question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions)), e.g.

```
Show[ 
  ParametricPlot3D[ Evaluate[ Table[{x, a, f[x, a]}, {a, 0, 5}]],
                    {x, 0, 10}, BoxRatios -> {10, 8, 4}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, 1, f[x, 1]}, 
                   {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle->{Thick, Darker@Red}, BoxRatios -> {10, 8, 4}]
```

[image]

Red thick curve is the graph of  `f[x,1]`,

or we can make use of `Plot3D` as well in the following way :

```
Plot3D[ f[x, a], {x, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 4}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> {9, 3, 5}, Filling -> 0,
        PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

]

[image]

The option `Filling ->0` makes an impression that the level `f[x,a] == 0` is like the surface of water.

Answer (score 19):

For finding all roots in a given interval I use the following function:

```
Clear[findRoots]
Options[findRoots] = Options[Reduce];
findRoots[gl_Equal, {x_, von_, bis_}, 
   prec : (_Integer?Positive | MachinePrecision | Infinity) : MachinePrecision, 
   wrap_: Identity, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{work, glp, vonp, bisp}, 
   {glp, vonp, bisp} = {gl, von, bis} /. r_Real :> SetPrecision[r, prec];
   work = wrap@Reduce[{glp, vonp <= x <= bisp}, opts];
   work = {ToRules[work]};
   If[prec === Infinity, work, N[work, prec]]];
```

Example

```
bes[x_] := BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]]
findRoots[bes[x] == 0, {x, 0, 100}]

During evaluation of In[35]:= Reduce::incs: Warning: Reduce was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>

Out[39]= {{x -> 0.886605}, {x -> 3.03297}, {x -> 6.32397}, {x -> 9.39114}, {x -> 
   12.5891}, {x -> 15.6878}, {x -> 18.8652}, {x -> 21.9767}, {x -> 
   25.1447}, {x -> 28.2631}, {x -> 31.4256}, {x -> 34.5483}, {x -> 
   37.7073}, {x -> 40.8329}, {x -> 43.9893}, {x -> 47.1171}, {x -> 
   50.2716}, {x -> 53.4011}, {x -> 56.5542}, {x -> 59.6849}, {x -> 
   62.8368}, {x -> 65.9686}, {x -> 69.1196}, {x -> 72.2522}, {x -> 
   75.4024}, {x -> 78.5358}, {x -> 81.6852}, {x -> 84.8193}, {x -> 
   87.9682}, {x -> 91.1027}, {x -> 94.2511}, {x -> 97.3861}}
```

The parameter prec gives the precision for the calculation. prec=Infinity gives exact solutions.
wrap (default: Identity) is a function you can apply to the solutions.

Comment: With this example don't work: `findRoots[Im[Zeta[x]^(1/Log[x])] == 0, {x, 0, 1}]`?

Answer (score 17):

Regarding your first question:

For a certain set of equations, `Reduce` is able to find all roots and prove that no more roots exist in a given interval.  I am not sure how this works, but there's an interesting blog post about it [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

When it is not able to *guarantee* (using symbolic methods) that there are no more solutions, it may still return a set, but it will give a warning.  This is the case for your equation.

```
Plot[BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Reduce[BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]] == 0 && 0 < x < 10, x]

(*
Reduce::incs: Warning: Reduce was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>
*)

(* ==>
x == Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
    0.886604635313462076794393681674}] || 
 x == Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
    3.03296608901366835385376172847}] || 
 x == Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
    6.32396651371147786252003752922}] || 
 x == Root[{BesselJ[1, #1]^2 + BesselK[1, #1]^2 - Sin[Sin[#1]] &, 
    9.39114340758508579766919382120}]
*)

ToRules@N[%]

(* ==>
  Sequence[{x -> 0.886605}, {x -> 3.03297}, {x -> 6.32397}, {x -> 9.39114}]
*)
```

Note that it is important to restrict the search to an interval.  Otherwise `Reduce` will tell you that it can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 14):

Very recently, I learned a useful procedure due to [J. P. Boyd](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611973525) (see also [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036142901398325) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/110838297)) that involves expanding a function as a Chebyshev polynomial series, forming the so-called ["colleague matrix"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/qmath/12.1.61), and then finding the eigenvalues of this matrix, which are often good approximations to the roots of the original function. I shall present how to do a barebones version of this strategy in *Mathematica*.

The first step is to form the Chebyshev series coefficients of the function concerned. One could either start from the Taylor series and use any number of methods to convert these coefficients to Chebyshev coefficients. Another route, which I shall present here, is to evaluate the function at the so-called "Chebyshev nodes", suitably transformed to the domain of the original function, and then using the (type-1) discrete cosine transform to produce the Chebyshev coefficients. It goes like this:

```
f[x_] := BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]];
{xmin, xmax} = {1/2, 100};

n = 128; (* arbitrarily chosen integer *)
prec = 20; (* precision *)
cnodes = Rescale[N[Cos[Pi Range[0, n]/n], prec], {-1, 1}, {xmin, xmax}];
cc = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[f[cnodes], 1];
cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
```

`n` here should be chosen to be greater than or equal to the number of roots known to be in the given interval. That is usually determined through a preliminary `Plot[]`. (A more sophisticated version, as used in the [Chebfun package](http://www.chebfun.org/) for MATLAB, does an adaptive increase in the order of the underlying Chebyshev approximation using a technique similar to Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature. I have chosen not to implement this for now.)

With the Chebyshev coefficients now available, one can then form the colleague matrix like so:

```
colleague = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i + 1 == j :> 1/2,
                         {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 :> 1/(2 - Boole[j == 1])},
                        {n, n}] -
            SparseArray[{{i_, n} :> cc[[i]]/(2 cc[[n + 1]])}, {n, n}];
```

We can then find the eigenvalues of this matrix, filter out irrelevant eigenvalues, and then use `Rescale[]` to transform the remaining eigenvalues back to the domain of the original function:

```
rts = Sort[Select[DeleteCases[
                  Rescale[Eigenvalues[colleague], {-1, 1}, {xmin, xmax}],
                  _Complex | _DirectedInfinity], xmin <= # <= xmax &]]
   {0.8866466, 3.0327390, 6.3243343, 9.3928065, 12.5892495, 15.6908929,
    18.8634014, 21.9762069, 25.1562125, 28.3003285, 31.4743983, 34.5197235,
    37.6746911, 40.8716527, 43.9572481, 47.1394116, 50.2776398, 53.3723848,
    56.5916636, 59.6440741, 62.8638369, 66.0001767, 69.0778338, 72.2121395,
    75.3874360, 78.5335813, 81.6858635, 84.8171664, 87.9688503, 91.1015749,
    94.2504610, 97.3866141}
```

The eigenvalues obtained look a bit rough here; this is due to the ill-behavior of the original function near the origin. For more well-behaved functions, the eigenvalues are often quite accurate roots of the original function. Of course, one can always use `FindRoot[]` to polish off these approximations.

Answer (score 12):

For your first question one can use Ted Ersek's package [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) :

```
RootSearch[BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]] == 0, {x, 0, 10}]

(* {{x -> 0.886605}, {x -> 3.03297}, {x -> 6.32397}, {x -> 9.39114}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

For a finite range of interest, `NSolve` works well

```
f[x_] = BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin[Sin[x]];

Manipulate[
 Module[{sol},
  Column[{
    sol = NSolve[{f[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= xmax}, x],
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, xmax},
     Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
       Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]},
     ImageSize -> 360]}]],
 {{xmax, 16}, 1, 31, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** With later Mathematica versions (e.g., 10.4.1), some of the roots can be missed unless you use higher precision. The `//N` after `NSolve` is used to reduce the displayed precision in the results.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol},
  Column[
   {sol = NSolve[{f[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= xmax}, x,
       WorkingPrecision -> 30] // N,
    Plot[f[x], {x, 0, xmax},
     Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
       Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]},
     ImageSize -> 360]}]],
 {{xmax, 16}, 1, 31, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

using my [myRootSearch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231577/4742) and [myRootSearchShow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231577/4742)

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, a_] := BesselJ[1, x]^2 + BesselK[1, x]^2 - Sin@Sin[a*x]
Manipulate[
 Column[{Quiet@myRootSearchShow[f[#, a] &, 0, 50, ImageSize -> 250], 
   Quiet@myRootSearch[f[#, a] &, 0, 50]}], {a, 0, 4}]
```

[image]