# Iterative way to find roots of confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, special-functions

I am trying to find roots of confluent hypergeometric function and I wonder if I can choose the initial guess by the choice of $\beta$.

```
eq[n_, \[Beta]_, \[Lambda]_] :=  
                              Hypergeometric1F1[1/4 (2 - \[Lambda]/\[Beta]), n + 1, \[Beta]]
ED[n_, \[Beta]_, k_Integer: 1] := \[Lambda] /. FindRoot[eq[n, \[Beta], \[Lambda]] == 0, 
                                       {\[Lambda], (4 k - 2) \[Beta]}]
```

My goal is to plot the function (x-axis:$\beta$ and y-axis:$\lambda$). To do that, I need good $\lambda$-values for each $\beta$. The problem is that for each $\beta$ we can have lots of roots, so I want to choose $\beta$ depends on the previous $\lambda$-value for initial guess to find the next root. For example, Start from $\beta=0$. For $\beta=0$, I want to find a root, $\lambda$, around $BesselJZero[n,k]^2$. Next, For $\beta=1$, I want to get a root around $\lambda$-value at $\beta=0$. Then, for $\beta=2$, I want to get a root around $\lambda$-value at $\beta=1$ and so on.  For the iterative way I think I should use "for loop" or "if", but I am not sure how to use it. Could you help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9048/5) that you previously asked? If not, please clarify how this is different.

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10592/125) seems to be closely related (except the form of `eq[...]`). Please see if the answer to that question is of any use.

Comment: Yes, it is closely related, but when I use the previous method I had a problem. For example, for the small $\beta$ value, the code is worked perfectly, but I realized that for large $\beta$, roots are close to (4 k - 2) $\beta$. So, I wonder there is any other method to choose $\lambda$ by using iterative way of $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Is this close to what you have in mind:

```
rootslist[n_Integer, k_Integer, m_Integer] := 
 Rest@FoldList[ FindRoot[eq[n, #2, \[Lambda]] == 0, {\[Lambda], #1}][[1, 2]] &, 
    BesselJZero[n, k]^2, Range@m]

rootslist[3, 1, 8]
(* {35.1703, 30.5554, 26.8427, 24., 21.9816, 20.7285, 20.1685, 20.2179} *)
rootslist[5, 2, 7]
(* {142.68, 133.995, 126.185, 119.251, 113.189, 108., 103.682} *)
```

Please see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10599/125) to a related question for alternative methods: `While`, `NestWhile` and `NestWhileList`.

Comment: This method solves my problem perfectly! Thank you. Also, I have one more question, it seems that the rootlist starts from $\beta$=1. Is there any way to find root starting from $\beta$=0? If I want to find roots for negative $\beta$ or negative n, then what should I change?

Comment: @Sony, glad it worked. I picked `1` as the starting point for the list of betas because with `\[Beta]=0`, you get `1/0`  in the first argument of `HyperGeometric1F1`. For negative `n` it should work as is. If you change `m_Integer` to `blist_` on the LHS, and `Range[m]` to `blist` on the RHS, then you should be able to iterate over any `blist` that does not contain `0`.