# How can I differentiate numerically?

Tags: functions, numerics, calculus-and-analysis

*Mathematica* has two ways to integrate: `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`.
But what about `D`?  `D` and `Derivative` are for symbolic differentiation.

How can I differentiate a function *numerically*?

Comment: Are you aware of `ND`?

Comment: Have a look at "NumericalCalculus`".

Comment: For continuously defined functions e.g. f[x_] := Sin[x]/x + E^(-x); Plot[f'[x], {x, -1, 9}]

Answer (score 33):

There are two rather different scenarios for numerical derivatives:

1. Differentiating a continuous function that's only defined numerically
2. Approximating the derivative of a list of data that could itself be generated numerically

For **scenario 1**, here is an example function and its derivative:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := BesselJ[1, x]

Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

Plot[ND[f[x], x, y], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image: ND]

For **scenario 2**, here I discretize the above function to get a table of values in some interval:

```
l = Table[f[x], {x, 0, 10, .1}];
```

Now the derivative can be taken using `DerivativeFilter`. This *doesn't require* the `"NumericalCalculus"` package:

```
dl = With[{pad = 10},
   ArrayPad[
    DerivativeFilter[
     ArrayPad[l, pad, "Extrapolated"], {1}],
    -pad]
   ];

ListPlot[dl]
```

[image: filter]

Here, I took the list `l` and padded it (optional) with `pad` extra entries at the start and end, before taking the numerical derivative using `DerivativeFilter`. The purpose of the padding is that it allows me to extrapolate the data points so that the derivative at the interval boundaries will look smooth.

After doing the derivative, I remove the padding by using a negative argument in  `ArrayPad[..., -pad]`.

Comment: Something like `N[D[f[x], x] /. x -> 5]` also works. There is a difference between `ND` and `D`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6332142/559318)

Comment: @acl, yes - and I had upvoted your linked answer back then, too! It's very exhaustive.

Comment: Lettuce knot forget scenario 3, of Automatic Differentiation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If I look at [this Wolfram demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AutomaticDifferentiation/), it seems to me that the technique is better classified as a symbolic differentiation trick. But maybe that's a matter of taste. My criterion would be that a numerical differentiation should be able to deal with functions that are calculated by numerical root finding, or using `FixedPoint` etc. Automatic differentiation requires that the function be calculable using elementary operations.

Answer (score 14):

As others mentioned, there's the [`ND` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html) from the `` NumericalCalculus` `` package.

It's a bit less widely known that `Derivative` is also able to approximate derivatives purely numerically.

Let's create a numerical black box function:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := x^2
```

`_?NumericQ` makes sure that the innards of `f` are inaccessible to `Derivative`, so `f'[x]` returns unevaluated.  But plugging in an explicit numerical value,

```
In[]:= f'[3.]
Out[]= 6.
```

---

**Update:**  Please also see [a discussion by @acl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6332142/695132) concluding that the difference between `Derivative` and `ND` is that `ND[...]` takes the derivative from one side while `N[D[...]]` takes it symmetrically.

Comment: I think the difference between this and `ND` is that `ND` takes the [derivative from one side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6332142/559318) while `N[D[]]` takes it symmetrically.

Comment: @acl Sorry about this, it seems you already warned me once before ...

Answer (score 12):

Had `ND[]` not been implemented in the `` NumericalCalculus` `` package, one could implement any number of numerical differentiation methods in *Mathematica*. I gave a number of warnings on the use of, as well as methods for, numerical differentiation in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64302); in particular, the last two methods I described lend themselves to somewhat compact implementations:

```
(* Cauchy method *)
ND1[f_, {x_, x0_}, opts___] :=
    Chop[NIntegrate[Exp[-I t] Function[x, f][x0 + Exp[I t]], {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
                    AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, opts, Method -> "DoubleExponential"]/(2 Pi)]

(* Lanczos method *)
ND2[f_, {x_, x0_}, opts___] := Module[{prec = Precision[x0], h, pr2}, 
    If[prec === Infinity, prec = MachinePrecision]; 
    h = # (Abs[x0] + #) &[(10^-(prec/2))];
    If[prec === MachinePrecision, pr2 = $MachinePrecision, pr2 = prec];
    N[3 NIntegrate[t Function[x, f][t + x0], {t, -h, h}, opts, 
                   WorkingPrecision -> pr2]/(2 h^3), prec]]
```

Both approaches are easily generalized; the Lanczos method can be generalized to arbitrary integer-order derivatives, and the Cauchy method can be generalized to arbitrary complex-order derivatives. I won't be discussing these generalizations further in this answer, tho.

A demonstration:

```
Plot[{-BesselJ[1, x], ND1[BesselJ[0, t], {t, x}]}, {x, 0, 10}, Axes -> None,
     Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Thick, Dashed], Blue}]
```

[image: plot of exact and approximate derivatives]

It's not too hard to implement the Richardsonian method I alluded to in my MO answer, but the routine is somewhat longer; I'll edit this answer to include it if there's interest.

Comment: For the discrete case, see [this](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i3/tricks/contents/html/Links/index_lnk_2.html). There's also the possibility of using a Savitzky-Golay filter for differentiating...

Comment: can we also use acegen?

Answer (score 9):

I present here another approach to numerically differentiating a function $f(x)$. While the methods in my other answer approximate $f^\prime(x)$ at a single specified value, the following method constructs an approximate function $p(x)$ such that $p(x)\approx f(x)$ within a given interval $[a,b]$, and then proceeds to directly generate $p^\prime(x)$.

The key here is to replace the function with its Chebyshev series, and then differentiate that series. This is similar to what is done in the [Chebfun package](http://www.chebfun.org/) for MATLAB, and previously presented in a number of answers by Michael E2 and yours truly.

To recall, this is how one might derive the coefficients of the Chebyshev series of a function over a given interval (as previously shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89692)):

```
f[x_] := BesselJ[0, x];
{a, b} = {0, 19}; (* interval of approximation *)

n = 128; (* arbitrarily chosen integer *)
prec = 20; (* precision *)
cnodes = Rescale[N[Cos[π Range[0, n]/n], prec], {-1, 1}, {a, b}];
fc = f /@ cnodes;
cc = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[fc, 1];
cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
```

Then, one can either take the dot product of the Chebyshev coefficients `cc` with an appropriate list of suitably scaled Chebyshev polynomials (of the first kind), or use a more efficient evaluation method such as [Clenshaw's algorithm](http://dlmf.nist.gov/3.11#Px3), which was presented in these [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108002) [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98350). For simplicity, I will use the dot product method here:

```
Plot[{f[x], cc.ChebyshevT[Range[0, n], Rescale[x, {a, b}, {-1, 1}]]},
     {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], AbsoluteThickness[1]}]
```

[image: approximating a Bessel function]

Now, one might be tempted to use `D[]` on the constructed Chebyshev series, but the problem with this approach is that `ChebyshevT[]` automatically converts to its power basis form for non-numeric arguments, thus negating any stability gained from remaining in the Chebyshev basis. Instead, one should directly construct the Chebyshev coefficients of the derivative.

The way to do that is to use a [Chebyshev spectral differentiation matrix](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html). What follows is a routine (previously posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107418)) to generate it.

```
chebmat[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: MachinePrecision] := 
 Module[{fac, xm},
        xm = ConstantArray[N[-Cos[π Range[0, n]/n], prec], n + 1];
        fac = Flatten[{2, PadRight[{}, n - 1, {-1, 1}], 2 - 4 Mod[n, 2]}];
        xm = Outer[Times, fac, 1/fac]/(xm - Transpose[xm] + IdentityMatrix[n + 1]);
        xm - DiagonalMatrix[Total[xm, {2}]]]
```

Now to generate the Chebyshev coefficients of the first derivative, do this:

```
dc = chebmat[n, prec].fc;
cd = FourierDCT[dc, 1] Sqrt[2/n] (2/(b - a));
cd[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
```

Compare:

```
Plot[{f'[x], cd.ChebyshevT[Range[0, n], Rescale[x, {a, b}, {-1, 1}]]},
     {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], AbsoluteThickness[1]}]
```

[image: approximating the derivative, Chebyshev-style]

This approach is easily extensible to arbitrary order derivatives, just by multiplying `fc` with an appropriate power of `chebmat[n]`. For instance, here's how to generate the Chebyshev coefficients of the third derivative:

```
k = 3; (* derivative order *)
dck = MatrixPower[chebmat[n, prec], k, fc];
cdk = FourierDCT[dck, 1] Sqrt[2/n] (2/(b - a))^k;
cdk[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
```

Comment: I think you've got a typo: `dc` should read `dc = chebmat[n, prec].(f /@ cnodes)`.  Might oughtta check `dck`, too.  (I guess I didn't check this when I upvoted...Probably too busy.)

Comment: @Michael, whoops. I must've mixed up lines during pasting. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

There is another possibility, and that is to differentiate an `InterpolatingFunction`.

Here is an example of a rather poorly behaving function whose derivative we can recover by this technique. The transfer function of a Butterworth filter looks like

```
h[s_] := 1 / (1 + 2s + 2s^2 + s^3)
```

for `s` complex.  The `Arg` of this function, which, for purely imaginary frequencies, is the phase of the filter, suffers a branch cut at an inconvenient place:

```
Plot[Arg[h[I s]], {s, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

The symbolic derivative of this thing, which is group delay for the filter, bogusly produces `Complex` values, even if we didn't have the problem of the inconvenient branch cut:

```
Table[D[Arg[h[I s]], s] /. s -> t, {t, 0, 2}]
```

> ```
> { -2 I Arg', 
>   (-(1/2) + 2 I) Arg'[-(1/2) - I/2], 
>   (824/4225 - (118 I)/4225) Arg'[-(7/65) + (4 I)/65] }
> ```

We can get a better-behaved function by adding `2 Pi` and then modding it out:

```
Plot[Mod[2 Pi + Arg[h[I s]], 2 Pi], {s, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But now we have a "dimple" where we had the branch cut, and, **sure enough**, `ND` from `NumericalCalculus` has problems:

```
<< NumericalCalculus`
Plot[ND[Mod[2 Pi + Arg[h[I w]], 2 Pi], w, s], {s, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

The `DerivativeFilter` method above works great to fix this, but here is another way. First, sample the original `Arg` or phase function:

```
ListPlot[args$ = Table[{s, Mod[2 Pi + Arg[h[I s]], 2 Pi]}, {s, .05, 6, .05}]]
```

[image]

Build an interpolation function from it:

```
iargs$ = Interpolation[args$]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.05, 6.}}, <>]
> ```

and differentiate that (notice carefully the tick mark in the following expression, a convenient shorthand for derivatives of functions of single variables):

```
Plot[iargs$'[s], {s, 0, 6}]
```

[image]