# Precompiling a Whittaker function

Tags: compile, special-functions

Is there a way to speed up the evaluation of special functions in Mathematica? I am particularly interested in the Whittaker W function. For instance, the following piece of code:

```
f[x_, y_] := Re[WhittakerW[2, I*x, y]];
RepeatedTiming[f[0.4, 2]]
```

takes about the same amount of time to execute as does the following one

```
g = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, Re[WhittakerW[2, I*x, y]]];
RepeatedTiming[g[0.4, 2]]
```

I was hoping that by precompiling the function I would sacrifice the versatility but gain performance. Yet although the versatility did get lost, the performance didn't change one bit. Any suggestions?

Comment: ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort`` gives you a list of compilable functions, `WhittakerW` is not one of them.

Comment: @paw so does that mean the answer to my question is no?

Comment: It means that `WhittakerW` is not compiled by `Compile` and you can therefore not get any speed advantage. Your only option is to implement the function yourself and compile it.

Comment: Usually compiling numerical functions does not result in speed-up; they are computed as efficiently as the engineers at Wolfram know how to do.  What speed-up there is, is mostly likely due to less overhead (e.g. no pattern-checking, machine precision, packed arrays, etc.). But there is relatively little overhead for simple function evaluations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Original answer

J.M.'s answer in [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/89692#89692) shows how to approximate an analytic function in a finite interval by its Chebyshev series.  We can do the same here, if we avoid the singularity at zero.

Here is a utility function for evaluating a Chebyshev expansion whose coefficients are stored in the array `c`.  We can even compile it, using the identity $T_n(x) = \cos(n\,\arccos x)$. *[Edit notice: See improvements to `chebeval` below.]*

```
Clear[chebeval];
chebeval[c_] :=
  Compile[{x}, c.Table[Cos[(n - 1) ArcCos[x]], {n, Length@c}]];
chebeval[c_, x_?NumericQ] :=
 c.Table[ChebyshevT[n - 1, x], {n, Length@c}]
```

*Example.*  We'll fix `x = 0.4` and approximate over `1 <= y <= 4`.

```
w = WhittakerW[2, I*0.4, #] &;
{ymin, ymax} = {1, 4};
n = 32;
cnodes = Rescale[N[Cos[Pi Range[0, n]/n], 20], {-1, 1}, {ymin, ymax}];
wcoeff = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[w /@ cnodes, 1];
wcoeff[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
Clear[wcheb];
wcheb[y_] := chebeval[wcoeff, Rescale[y, {ymin, ymax}, {-1, 1}]];
wcomp = With[{w = chebeval[wcoeff]}, w[Rescale[#, {ymin, ymax}, {-1, 1}]] &];
```

It's accurate to almost machine precision:

```
Plot[
 (Re[w[y]] - Re@wcheb[y]) / ($MachineEpsilon + $MachineEpsilon Abs@Re[w[y]]),
 {y, ymin, ymax}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *Error relative to precision and accuracy goals of `$MachineEpsilon`.*

The compiled version is especially faster:

```
Re@w[2] // RepeatedTiming
Re@wcheb[2] // RepeatedTiming
Re@wcomp[2] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.0011, -0.129877}
  {0.00017, -0.129877}
  {9.03*10^-6, -0.129877}
*)
```

#### Greater speed and greater accuracy

[J.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) points out that  [Clenshaw's algorithm](http://dlmf.nist.gov/3.11#Px3) for computing truncated Chebyshev series is numerically more stable, and "algorithmically faster," if that is the right way to say it.  I mean that in terms of floating-point operations, it should be faster than computing trigonometric functions.  However internal optimization  `Cos` and `ArcCos` may mean it is computed faster than compiled *Mathematica* code.  This is the case on my Mac and the `Cos/ArcCos` implementation of `chebeval`.  If you can compile to C, then the Clenshaw method will probably be faster; it is on my machine.  Then Clenshaw algorithm has about 70% of the error of the `Cos/ArcCos` implementation on average.

Here are three routines for computing a truncated Chebyshev series.  One is a more efficient "vectorized" variation on the `Cos/ArcCos` method above.  The other two implement Clenshaw's algorithm, the only difference between them is that one is compiled to C.  Further notes on speed and accuracy are given further down.

```
Clear[chebeval];
chebeval["TrigVectorized"][c_?VectorQ] := With[{deg = Length@c - 1},
   Compile[{x}, Block[{ac = ArcCos[x]}, c.Cos[Range[0, deg] ac]],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
   ];
chebeval["Clenshaw"][c0 : {__Real}] :=
  With[{c1 = Reverse[c0], deg = Length@c0 - 1},
   Compile[{x},
    Block[{c = c1, s = 0., s1 = 0., s2 = 0.},
     Do[
      s = c[[i]] + 2 x*s1 - s2;
      s2 = s1; s1 = s,
      {i, deg}];
     Last@c + x*s1 - s2
     ],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
   ];
chebeval["Clenshaw-C"][c0 : {__Real}] :=
  With[{c1 = Reverse[c0], deg = Length@c0 - 1},
   Compile[{x},
    Block[{c = c1, s = 0., s1 = 0., s2 = 0.},
     Do[
      s = c[[i]] + 2 x*s1 - s2;
      s2 = s1; s1 = s,
      {i, deg}];
     Last@c + x*s1 - s2
     ],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True,
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]
   ];
```

Note that if complex values are needed, then the local variables in the Clenshaw routines should be initialized to complex values, that is, `s = 0. + 0. I, s1 = 0. + 0. I, s2 = 0. + 0. I`; and of course, the argument pattern `c0 : {__Real}` would need to be changed to something like `c0_?VectorQ`.  (See also the notes on speed below.)

*Timings*

```
y0 = RandomReal[{ymin, ymax}, 10^5];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
TableForm@Join[
 {{"Name", 1, Length[y0]}},
 Table[
  wcomp = chebeval[s][Re@wcoeff];
  {s, AccurateTiming@Re@wcomp[Rescale[2, {ymin, ymax}, {-1, 1}]],
   AccurateTiming@Re@wcomp[Rescale[y0, {ymin, ymax}, {-1, 1}]]},
  {s, {"Clenshaw", "TrigVectorized", "Clenshaw-C"}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Each is faster than the timing `9.03*10^-6` of the original answer (on a single element).

*Accuracy*

There is no difference between the two Clenshaw routines.  They are somewhat better than the `Cos/ArcCos` method.

```
  (* input and values *)
input = Range[N@ymin, N@ymax, (ymax - ymin)/10013.];
wvec = w[input];
input = Rescale[input, {ymin, ymax}, {-1, 1}];
trig = chebeval["TrigVectorized"][Re@wcoeff][input];
clen = chebeval["Clenshaw-C"][Re@wcoeff][input];
  (* norms -- see notes below *)
svn2 = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[2, {$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon/8}];
svnInf1 = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[Infinity, {$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon}];
svnInf8 = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[Infinity, {$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon/8}];

Grid[
 {{"Norm"[p, a], "Cos/ArcCos", "Clenshaw"},
  {"RMS"[ϵ, ϵ/8], svn2[trig - wvec, wvec], svn2[clen - wvec, wvec]},
  {∞[ϵ, ϵ], svnInf1[trig - wvec, wvec], svnInf1[clen - wvec, wvec]},
  {∞[ϵ, ϵ/8], svnInf8[trig - wvec, wvec], svnInf8[clen - wvec, wvec]}},
 Dividers -> {{False, True}, {False, True}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below is a pointwise comparision of the `Cos/ArcCos` and Clenshaw methods.  Note that as `w[y]` approaches zero (the green line shows `5 * w[y]`), the scaled error increases; this depends on the "accuracy" parameter `$MachineEpsilon/8`

```
ListLinePlot[
 {MapThread[svnInf8[{#1 - #2}, {#2}] &, {trig, wvec}],
  MapThread[svnInf8[{#1 - #2}, {#2}] &, {clen, wvec}],
  Abs[5 wvec]},
 DataRange -> {ymin, ymax}, PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *The W function (green); scaled error, Clenshaw (yellow); scaled error, `Cos/ArcCos` (blue)*

*Some notes on speed*

- In this case the function is real-valued, but `FourierDCT` returns coefficients with negligible imaginary parts. It's faster to compute with real than with complex numbers, so getting rid of the imaginary parts with `Re@wcoeff` helps slightly with speed, especially with the slower (WVM) Clenshaw routine. Of course, one can work with complex coefficients as indicated above.
- The usual description of the Clenshaw algorithm counts down from the $n^{\rm th}$ coefficient to the zeroth.  However in the compiler, `Do[.., {i, max, min, -1}]` is slower than `Do[.., {i, min, max}]`.  Hence, we reverse the coefficient array before compiling (a one-time cost).
- The relative timings may vary.  It seems likely that the MKL would use the built-in hardware arc cosine command on my Intel i7 chip and that *Mathematica* would use the MKL for machine-precision computation.  This may explain why the WVM-compiled `Cos/ArcCos` routine is faster than the WMV-compiled Clenshaw routine, and why compiling to C reverses the comparison.  (Compiling the `Cos/ArcCos` routine to C makes no difference in speed since it is a one-liner with no loops.)

*Some notes on precision and accuracy*

- The typical measure of function approximation in *Mathematica* is the "scaled vector norm," described in the tutorial [Norms in NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveVectorNorm.html). A given `PrecisionGoal` of $pg$ and `AccuracyGoal` of $ag$ corresponds to tolerances $t_p=10^{-pg}$ and $t_a=10^{-ag}$. An absolute error $\delta$ related to an exact value $v$ has the *scaled error* of
  $$se = {\delta \over t_a + t_p\,|v|}$$
  The joint precision/accuracy goal is considered to be "met" if $se < 1$.  Just what this means changes depending on the relative sizes of $t_a$ and $t_p\,|v|$.  When $t_a$ is much greater (so that $|v|$ is very small), the goal is met when the approximation accurate to $-\log_{10}(t_a)$ decimal places; that is, it depends on the absolute error. At the other extreme, the goal is met with the first $-\log_{10}(t_p)$ digits are accurate; that is, it depends on the relative error.
- `` svn = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[p, {precTol, accTol}] `` returns a function `svn` that `svn[eVec, vVec]` computes the $p$-norm of a vector of absolute errors `eVec` scaled relative to a vector of exact values `vVec` with the precision and accuracy tolerances `precTol` and `accTol` respectively.  (See the linked tutorial on norms.)

Comment: This is great! Can this be extended to the case when $x$ is not fixed, but rather is limited to the interval, say between 0 and 5?

Comment: @Alex You mean over a rectangular domain as a function of both `x` and `y`?  There has been [some work on a 2D version](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130908002), but I haven't had a chance to look into it.  How accurate do you need it to be? One might be able to use an interpolation.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for providing the link, let me have a look.

Comment: @Michael_E2 Actually, your solution with $x$ fixed might be sufficient for my needs, because in my case $x$ is predetermined, i.e., I effectively need to approximate the Whittaker function as a function of $y$ for several particular values of $x$. To do this, would it be sufficient to wrap your code in a loop over values of $x$ and within each iteration once $x$ changes to its next value just approximate the Whittaker function as you did above?

Comment: @Alex Sounds like it would work.  It doesn't take long to compute the approximation for each `x`.  If, for some values of `x`, it seems the error is too great, try bumping `n = 32` up to `n = 64`.

Comment: @Michael, I'd actually been able to hack out a procedure for the bivariate case; now I'm just looking for a question to use it on... :) On that note, for the compiled `chebeval`, it is cheaper and more stable to use the Clenshaw recurrence for evaluating the Chebyshev series.

Comment: @J.M. There is some improvement in accuracy with the Clenshaw recurrence but it's slower, unless you compile to C.  That's what I would have thought about the speed.  I'll update eventually.  Will you post a 2D solution?

Comment: Here's the Clenshaw implementation I use: `chebeval[c_?VectorQ] := Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Module[{n = Length[c], u, v, w}, u = c[[n - 1]] + 2 x (v = c[[n]]); Do[w = v; v = u; u = c[[k]] + 2 x v - w, {k, n - 2, 2, -1}]; c[[1]] + x u - v], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]`. Testing it against the one using trigonometric functions, I get consistently faster results. As for the bivariate Chebyshev proxy, somehow I don't think it's needed here, and your suggestion above is quite adequate. So, still looking for another question... :)

Comment: With respect to mitigating singular behavior, a trick similar to what you did for solving singular ODEs can be used: factor out the singular parts in either end of the interval, perform Chebyshev approximation on the now-regular function, and multiply back the singular factors.

Comment: Yet again I feel bad that I cannot upvote an answer twice.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  Words of appreciation are even better.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great, thank you for such a detailed answer.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for the accept.