# Solving equation

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve this equation:

```
((a^2 - 1)*((a^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[a] - a))/(2*Sqrt[2*(a^2 - 1)^4]) == C*x
```

I am looking a solution for $a$ in function of $x$. I tried `Solve` and similar methods but I got unevaluated expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way: Derive the differential equation of the family (solve for the constant and differentiate); and use `DSolve` to solve it.

```
D[(1/x)((a^2 - 1)*((a^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[a] - a)) /
     (2*Sqrt[2*(a^2 - 1)^4]) /. a -> a[x], x] // Together // Numerator;
{dsol} = DSolve[% == 0, a, x] /. C[1] -> c
(*
  {{a -> Function[{x}, 
      InverseFunction[-(1/2) Log[1 - #1^2] + 
          1/2 Log[-ArcTanh[#1] - #1 + ArcTanh[#1] #1^2] &][c + Log[x]/2]]}}
*)
```

Evaluating an `InverseFunction` on exact input can sometimes take a long time.  Be sure to use approximate machine reals when plotting or doing other numerical work.  (This is accomplished by `N` below. Alternatively one could use the iterator `{x, -1., 1.}` instead of `{x, -1, 1}` to specify the plot domain.)

```
Block[{c = 1},
 Plot[a[N@x] /. dsol, {x, -1, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While `InverseFunction` can be inconvenient at times, the solution `dsol` does present `a` as a function of `x` and the parameter `c`.

---

*Update:* I guess I should point out that the inverse function is basically just the solution to the equation written in the form of an inverse function.

This simpler solution is equivalent to the produced by `dsol`:

```
{a -> Function[{x}, 
   InverseFunction[1/(1 - #1^2)*(-ArcTanh[#1] - #1 + ArcTanh[#1] #1^2) &][Exp[2 c] x]]}
```

It is equivalent to the OP's original equation via `Exp[2 c] == 2 Sqrt[2] C`.  (Please note that capital [`C`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) is a [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html) *Mathematica* symbol.)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your graph (_dsol_) presents solution to this equation and it looks like `Tanh[Constant*x]`, where _Constant_ is related to _c_. For different values of _c_ the shape of `Tanh[]` will be different. So, how can I find this _Constant_? For example, to have solution in form of `Tanh[x]`.

Comment: @JohnM. You're welcome. I think you can see from [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MOTqP.png) that, while `dsol` produces a sigmoid-like plot similar to `Tanh`, it is not in fact the same.

Comment: Thank you again. This was useful. I noticed that I can not represent _dsol_ with `Tanh[x]`, they are similar but not the same. However, is there a way to represent this curve (sigmoid function) with some function (approximate solution) in term of _x_?

Comment: @Michael E2 Why you have another functional course?

Comment: @JohnM. Over a finite interval, one can construct an interpolating function with `NDSolve` or `FunctionInterpolation`, which would evaluate faster than `InverseFunction`. Or one could use another approximation method, such as a Chebyshev series expansion I used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98350). One might try fitting a formula (see `FindFit`, `LinearModelFit`, and the whole `*Fit` family).

Comment: @rewi I'm not sure what you mean by "course."  The second formula, which I got from manipulating the `DSolve` result, has for its argument to `InverseFunction` the left-hand side of the OP's equation up to a constant factor, with `#1` replacing `a`. I thought that clarified the relationship of the `DSolve` solution to the equation, especially the relationship between the constants.  But perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @Michael E2  Your function is mirrored at the x axis

Comment: @rewi Do you mean `Log[x]` should be an issue?  In *Mathematica* `Log` is defined for negative real numbers. It's complex-valued, but the logarithms  in the inverse function cancel out the imaginary part of `Log[x]`.  E.g., `Solve[Log[-1] == Log[x]]` and `FindRoot[Log[-1] == Log[x], {x, -0.1}]`.  Is that what you meant? (Otherwise it is clear from the equation that the solution should be symmetric in this way.)

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks Michael E2. Is my thinking wrong when I build the inverse of f in my solution? Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @rewi Don't you just need to use a negative value for `c` and then they'll look the same?  `DSolve` probably just did something like that, since the `c` disappears from my DE.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you very much. You solved my problem. Comments from _@rewi_ are also useful. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If it may also be a graphic solution?
Consider:

```
FunctionDomain[ArcTanh[a], a]
(* -1 < a < 1 *)


((a^2 - 1)*((a^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[a] - a))/(2*Sqrt[2*(a^2 - 1)^4]) == c*x;
x[a_] = 1/c*((a^2 - 1)*((a^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[a] - a))/(2*Sqrt[2*(a^2 - 1)^4]);
```

With c as parameter

```
p = Plot[x[a] /. c -> 1, {a, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
p1 = Join @@ Cases[Normal@p, Line[x1__] :> x1, Infinity];
a = Interpolation@Thread@{Last /@ p1, First /@ p1}

Plot[a[x], {x, -3, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The easiest way to find the function a(x) is to build the inverse of f(a).

```
f = 1/c*((#^2 - 1)*((#^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[#] - #))/(2*Sqrt[2*(#^2 - 1)^4]) &;
a = InverseFunction@f
```

[image]

This function can be evaluated numerically with c as parameter, e.g.

```
c = 1;
Table[a[x], {x, -2, 2}] // N
(* {-0.888998, -0.76291, 0., 0.76291, 0.888998} *)

Plot[{f[x], a[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f[x]", "a[x]"}, AspectRatio -> 0.8]
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

Please forgive me, I have a problem with the solutions. I follow here Michel E2's method.

```
f = ((a^2 - 1)*((a^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[a] - a))/(2*Sqrt[2*(a^2 - 1)^4]) - c x /. a -> a[x];
df = D[f, x] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
sol = DSolve[df == 0, a, x] /. C[1] -> 0
```

[image]

```
c = 1;
Plot[a[x] /. sol, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your solution. Using _@MichaelE2's_ and your method I solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to give a generic answer which work in such cases. The main idea is to go numerical. You solve it for some parameter values and get an idea of the function which might be the answer.

```
dat = Table[{c, x, 
           a /. NSolve[((a^2 - 1)*((a^2 - 1)*ArcTanh[a] - a)) /(2*Sqrt[2*(a^2 - 1)^4])
       == c x && 0 < a < 10, a][[1]]}, {c, 0.1, 1, .1}, {x, 0.1, 1., .1}]

dat1 = Flatten[dat, 1];
f = Interpolation[dat1];
Plot3D[f[c, x], {c, 0.1, 1}, {x, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image]

Ignore the `Solve::rantz` error message. Note that I use `[[1]]` and a range `0 < a < 10`. This comes handy if you have multiple root and also gives faster result because it looks for root only within that region.