# Function inversion

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, inverse

I have an expression of this kind

```
t = 2 m (Sqrt[4 x^2 (1 - m^2) + m^4 + 4 m^2 x]/(1 - m^2) + 
  m^2/(4 (1 - m^2) Sqrt[m^2 - 1]) ArcSin[(2 (1 - m^2) x + 4 m^2)/(4 m^3)])
```

that I would like to invert so that to have `x[t]`.

I have tried with

```
InverseFunction[2 m (Sqrt[4 x^2 (1 - m^2) + m^4 + 4 m^2 x]/(1 - m^2) + 
  m^2/(4 (1 - m^2) Sqrt[m^2 - 1]) ArcSin[(2 (1 - m^2) x + 4 m^2)/(4 m^3)]) - t][0]
```

but it does not seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong or it is just that the function is not invertible?

Comment: ArcSin is the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Still seems not to be working.

Comment: look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112795/solving-equation/112812#112812)

Comment: Can you say something about the range of `m`? It looks like it must be less than 1 in order to use real numbers.

Comment: Hey Jack Lavigne, I actually found out that the expression that I wrote has some typos. Here is the corrected version


`2 m (Sqrt[4 x^2 (1 - m^2) + m^4 + 4 m^2 x]/(1 - m^2) + m^2/(4 (1 - m^2) Sqrt[m^2 - 1]) ArcSin[(2 (1 - m^2) x + 4 m^2)/(4 m^3)])`


that I tried to invert using `InverseFunction[]`, but still cannot be solved. The condition for m is m>1

Comment: you should edit the question with the correction

Answer (score 6):

define a function of two variables,

```
f[x_, m_] = 2 m (Sqrt[4 x^2 (1 - m^2) + m^4 + 4 m^2 x]/(1 - m^2) +
     m^2/(4 (1 - m^2) Sqrt[m^2 - 1]) ArcSin[(2 (1 - m^2) x + 
          4 m^2)/(4 m^3)]);
```

then tell InverseFunction to invert w.r.t. the first argument:

```
inv = InverseFunction[f, 1, 2];

Show[{Plot[f[x, 2], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPlot[Table[{inv[y, 2], y} // N, {y, -7, -1/2, 1/4}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

of course this is actually inverted numerically and so is rather slow. Also the inverse is not single valued and you get no control over which solution you get.

Comment: Thank you george2079, I will try with this solution