# Interpolating functions and Look-up tables

Tags: interpolation

This is just a general question about how InterpolatingFunctions work:

If I have a complicated function that I don't want to have to evaluate many times over, does turning it into an InterpolatingFunction make it behave more like a lookup table, or will every call to an InterpolatingFunction still have to do a complicated calculation?

Does adding NumericQ to the argument of this function have an effect on this aspect of its behavior?

Comment: "...does turning it into an `InterpolatingFunction` make it behave more like a lookup table?" - more or less; the function will use piecewise polynomials to "connect the dots".

Answer (score 1):

I ran a simple scenario:

```
func[x_] := x^3

AbsoluteTiming[func[192999292992292992];]
Output: {0.000019737327747406418`, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[func[155];]
Output: {9.47391731875508`*^-6, Null}

pts = Table[{i, func[i]}, {i, 1, 200}];
intfunc = Interpolation[pts];

AbsoluteTiming[intfunc[192999292992292992];]
Output: {0.005909355927573481`, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[intfunc[155];]
Output: {0.00004500110726408663`, Null}
```

So as you can see, using the original function should take a shorter time, especially when the Interpolation has to extrapolate data.

Of course, I don't know how complex your function is, so try running an AbsoluteTiming on both cases if you're curious.

Comment: Well sure, for a simple polynomial function, `Interpolation[]` is slow; that's not what it's really intended for. More illustrative would be to use a (complicated) transcendental function.

Comment: The function has a polynomial in the numerator and the denominator is a sum of terms that have polynomial exponents. The InterpolatingFunction appears to be about 50 times faster. Thanks!

Comment: @basementDweller Is accuracy at all a concern, or only speed?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right now speed is more important, but obviously I don't want to scrap accuracy altogether...Why do you ask?

Comment: @basementDweller `InterpolatingFunction` will usually be fast, slowing down somewhat as the `InterpolationOrder` (degree of the polynomials used) increases and as the number of interpolation nodes/points increases, but one does not usually need to sacrifice accuracy for speed here. There are a few methods for constructing an IF, depending on the function, `FunctionInterpolation[]` and `NDSolve[]` being common. See, for instance, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85103), [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98343), or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59891).