# Constructing an arbitrary dimensional matrix with a certain rule

Tags: matrix

I want to construct the following matrix $M$ of dimension $(N+1)\times(N+1)$ with the following rule (for arbitrary N). Below, in the subscript, as usual, the 1st index gives the row and the second one the column. The subscript indices go from 0 to $N$.

\begin{equation}
M_{00}=\frac{2N^2+1}{6},\, M_{NN}=-\frac{2N^2+1}{6}\\
M_{jj}=-\frac{x_j}{2(1-x_j^2)}\quad\mbox{for}\quad j=1\dots N-1\\
M_{ij}=\frac{c_i}{c_j}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(x_i-x_j)}\quad\mbox{for}\quad i\neq j,\, i,j=0\dots N\\
\end{equation}

Above, $c_i=2$ for $i=0$ or $N$, and 1 otherwise. The $x_j$'s ($j=0\dots N$) are defined as $x_j=\cos(j\pi/N)$.

The above rule should unambiguously tell us all the matrix entries, but how to implement it in *Mathematica* is beyond me. A nice, understandable program will be very helpful. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is this homework? Why are are using Mathematica for your problem?

Comment: It's not a homework per se. For our research, I am solving a book's problem (which uses MATLAB) one by one. And we decided to do everything in Mathematica, so we're sticking to mathematica. Now and then, I can't solve a problem. We are even worse in other programming languages, so we are sticking to mathematica.

Comment: Although your matrix is not sparse, perhaps you could still construct it using [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and rules, then converting the `SparseArray` object to a [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) matrix.

Comment: Trust me, I am trying for a long time and I will keep trying. But if someone comes along, and does it in 5 minutes, then I have nothing to complain.

Comment: Anyway, I am going offline for half an hour or so.

Comment: As you should know, Mathematica list indexes start at one, not zero. **At least** you may have converted your expressions that way.

Comment: -1. Pretty much no effort of your own to be seen here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution without the mess of reindexing:

```
NN = 5;

c[i_] = If[i == 0 || i == NN, 2, 1];
x[j_] = Cos[j Pi/NN];

result = Table[Switch[{i, j},
    {0, 0}, (2 NN^2 + 1)/6,
    {NN, NN}, -(2 NN^2 + 1)/6,
    {xy_, xy_}, -x[j] / (2 (1 - x[j]^2)),
    {_, _}, c[i] (-1)^(i + j)/(c[j] (x[i] - x[j]))],
   {i, 0, NN},
   {j, 0, NN}
   ];

result // Simplify // TableForm
```

Result different from the other answer !
To be verified !

[image: the matrix]

Comment: Okay, this one I just checked and it works!! I will understand the code now. Thanks Andre!! Yes, the other one was giving a wrong answer. Yours is correct.

Answer (score 6):

**(Update: fixed incorrectly translated rules)**

Remember that **array indices start at 1** in *Mathematica*, so you have to adapt your definitions accordingly. Perhaps you could have started there...

You can *quite literally* translate your requirements into conditions and feed them to `SparseArray`, then  use `Normal` to get a standard representation:

```
Clear[matrixgenerator]

matrixgenerator[n_Integer] :=
 Module[{x, c},
  x[j_] := Cos[(j - 1) Pi/n];
  c[i_] := If[i == 1 || i == n + 1, 2, 1];
  Normal@Simplify@SparseArray[{
      {1, 1} -> (2 n^2 + 1)/6,
      {n + 1, n + 1} -> -(2 n^2 + 1)/6,
      {j_, j_} /; 1 < j <= n -> -x[j]/2/(1 - x[j]^2),
      {i_, j_} /; i != j -> c[i] (-1)^(i + j)/c[j]/(x[i] - x[j])
      }]
 ]

matrixgenerator[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`SparseArray` can be a very powerful tool even if you are not dealing with sparse arrays at all!

Comment: +1. I though that indices for *matrices* in general start with 1? (Just to start one of those religious discussions... :)

Comment: @gwr Eh, some people may disagree there: [Edsger W. Dijkstra's article "Why numbering should start at zero"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). I have also heard the argument that, for a base $b$ the first $b^N$ non-negative integers are represented by exactly $N$ digits (including leading zeros) only if the numbering starts at $0$, so that's the convention that makes the most sense on computing systems. I, for one, don't care either way :-)

Comment: That's the *zeroest* time I hear about this. ;-)

Comment: @MarcoB: Actually there are probably some mistakes. First of all, I think in the definition of c_i that you wrote, it will be i=1 as the first condition instead of i=0. Also, for the [i,j] component, both are c[i]. Even though I corrected them, the problems are still there. For example, for n=1, it's a 2X2 matrix with M_{12}=-1/2 and M_{21}=1/2. Using the code you wrote, I am getting -1 and +1 respectively.

Comment: @Student Very possible. I suggest that you amend the definitions in your original question by taking into consideration that `Mathematica`'s array indices start at $1$. That will make it much easier to troubleshoot my code.

Comment: @Student Finally got round to fixing the formula translation mistakes I had.

Comment: @gwr and Marco, in at least this case, it makes sense to begin at 0, since it corresponds to the indexing of the Chebyshev polynomials, which also start at 0.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick *Mathematica* translation of [Trefethen](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html)'s [`cheb.m`](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/cheb.m) MATLAB routine for generating a Chebyshev spectral differentiation matrix:

```
chebmat[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: MachinePrecision] := 
 Module[{fac, xm},
        xm = ConstantArray[N[-Cos[π Range[0, n]/n], prec], n + 1];
        fac = Flatten[{2, PadRight[{}, n - 1, {-1, 1}], 2 - 4 Mod[n, 2]}];
        xm = Outer[Times, fac, 1/fac]/(xm - Transpose[xm] + IdentityMatrix[n + 1]);
        xm - DiagonalMatrix[Total[xm, {2}]]]
```

For instance, `FullSimplify[chebmat[5, ∞]]` quickly generates the matrix in andre's answer. However, a more appropriate demonstration of the use of the differentiation matrix would be to use it for what its name is implying. ;)

Here goes:

```
tst[x_] := Exp[x] Sin[5 x]
With[{n = 20},
     chebnodes = Cos[π Range[0, n]/n];
     diff = Reverse[chebmat[n].tst[chebnodes]]];

Plot[tst'[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], ColorData[97, 2]], 
                Point[Transpose[{-chebnodes, diff}]]}]
```

[image: derivative of a function, Chebyshev-style]

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to MarcoB's solution (but using their definitions), use a `Table` and a `Which` or a `Piecewise`. This is strictly for the purpose of showing more methods.

```
matrixgenerator[n_Integer] :=
 Module[{x, c}, x[i_] := Cos[i Pi/n];
   c[i_] := If[i == 0 || i == n, 2, 1];
   Table[
    Which[
     i == j == 0, (2 n^2 + 1)/6,
     i == j == n, -(2 n^2 + 1)/6,   
     i == j, -x[j]/(2 (1 - x[j]^2)),
     i != j, c[i] (-1)^(i + j)/c[j]/(x[i] - x[j])
     ],
    {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]
   ] // Simplify

matrixgenerator[n_Integer] :=
 Module[{x, c}, x[i_] := Cos[i Pi/n];
   c[i_] := If[i == 0 || i == n, 2, 1];
   Table[
    Piecewise[{
      {(2 n^2 + 1)/6, i == j == 0},
      {-(2 n^2 + 1)/6, i == j == n},    
      {-x[j]/(2 (1 - x[j]^2)), i == j},
      {c[i] (-1)^(i + j)/c[j]/(x[i] - x[j]), i != j}
      }],
    {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]
   ] // Simplify
```

Comment: I upvoted both the answers and accepted them. I will run, check and understand them now. But I am really grateful to see so many people gave some thoughts to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Student. I fixed my solution. (It had the same problem as MarcoB's.)