How to explain the behaviour ahout Interpolation?
I encountered an issue while calculating the derivative of an interpolation function. To illustrate the problem, I provide a simple example below, along with the corresponding code:
ClearAll["`*"]
inf = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {0.1, .3}, {0.5, .6}, {1, -.2}, {2, 3}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3];
F[X_?NumericQ] := inf[X]
F'[1]
F'[1.]
inf'[1.]
(*Derivative[1][F][1]*)
(*-1.76942*)
(*-2.05556*)


I have two questions regarding the results obtained above:

Why does F'[1] fail to produce a result, whereas F'[1.] works as expected?
Why is there a slight difference between the results of F'[1.] and inf'[1.]?


My Mathematica version is 14.0 .Any insights or suggestions on these issues would be greatly appreciated!

The first question is not about a problem with Interpolation; it's a problem with derivatives of set-delayed functions: Evaluate g[x_?NumericQ] := x, then g'[1] and g'[1.], and you'll see the same issue. This might be an issue with Evaluation order, but I'm not sure. Traceing the evaluations of g'[1] and g'[1.] yields no hints as to what the difference is, so I'm not sure what's going on.

For the second issue, I suspect it's related to the first. It's certainly true that inf'[1.]yields the correct derivative, and F'[1.] doesn't: see here. All of that said, why are you doing F[X_?NumericQ] := inf[X] to begin with and not just using inf[x] and inf'[x], etc?

I think I'm zeroing in on the issue. There is a discontinuity in the derivative of the interpolating function at $x=1$ that is fixed if you take InterpolationOrder->4. See this code. The issue is probably something like the following: if the interpolation order is smaller thanN-1 (where N is the number of points), then there will be discontinuities in the derivative of the function at certain points. As for why it's different for F vs inf, perhaps Mathematica understands that F is a numerical function while inf is symbolic.

Isn't it very convenient, that Interpolation returns a pure function int? No need to define F !

See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14463/4999

If you execute On[F] to turn on tracing of F and then execute  F'[1.] and F'[1`32], you'll that F is evaluated several times, more for the higher precision input; these values are used internally to approximate the derivative using a high-order central difference approximation. For a piecewise interpolation, the result might not be very good near an abscissa of the interpolation. You may want to consider Method -> "Spline".
