# How can I combine several 2D-plots to one big 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, graphics3d, display

So I've been able to make a list given by

```
list = Table[{xValues, f[xValues, t (*fixed*)]}, {xValues, xmin, xmax}]
```

For example:

```
list = 
 Table[{x, Sin[x/(2*Pi)*1/10]*Cos[1/(2*Pi)]}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

this list is easily plotted with the command `ListPlot[list]` (or even `ListLinePlot` if I wanted some kind of interpolation between my points).

Now if I go to the 3D-case it becomes slightly harder! So I again make my list of data, this time given by:

```
Plotdata = 
 Table[{x, y, Sin[x/(2*Pi)*1/10]*Cos[y/(2*Pi)*1/10]}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 
   1, 10}]
```

This now gives me a nested list, and my attempt to plot it with `ListPlot3D` is futile. I'm wondering if I need to do something special to get this done? My goal would be to get a nice 3D-plot of the whole.

I know I could do it for my example with the regular `Plot3D` command, but that's just an example, the real case involves a lot of functions which can't be done by the plot-command (or would demand to much time). My problem comes essentially down to the above. I'm hoping someone could help me.

Comment: your list is nested; is this what you want: `ListPlot3D[Flatten[Plotdata, 1]`? (if so, you might want to look at documentation of `ListPlot3D`)

Comment: Well that was what I was thinking first to, but it doesn't give the right plot. I used this example to analyze my mistake because then I can compare with Plot3D[Sin[x]*Cos[y],{x,0,2*Pi},{y,0,2*Pi}]. Using the "Flatten" command doesn't give the same result for the plot. So just applying flatten doens't really solve the problem (unfortunately)

Comment: @Nick Take a look at this answer for a general idea: [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/5670#5670). There have been many similar answers at this site.

Comment: Maybe you want to multiply by `2 * Pi` instead of divide?

Comment: or just use: `Plotdata = 
 Table[{x, y, Sin[x]*Cos[y]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]`

Comment: @PinguinDirk the last one fixed my problem (in combination with your first answer). Seems kindoff strange since it should yield the same answers :s.

Comment: @Nick: see Michael's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extended your range for illustrative purposes. Two ways:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x/(2*Pi)*1/10]*Cos[y/(2*Pi)*1/10], {x, 1, 100}, {y, 1, 
  100}]
ListSurfacePlot3D[
 Partition[
  Flatten@Table[{x, y, Sin[x/(2*Pi)*1/10]*Cos[y/(2*Pi)*1/10]}, {x, 1, 
     100, 1}, {y, 1, 100, 1}], 3], Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, 
 PlotRange -> All, MaxPlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]