# How can I solve my system of differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a question pertaining to my code below: I require to find the values of the roots `E2` that will set the function `f1[E2] - f2[E2]` to zero. I know how to obtain the roots one at a time: for instance a root of `E2` lying between, say 0 and 2. But I would like to know whether it is possible to get *Mathematica* to generate all the roots that lie within a certain interval at once, say those lying between 0 and 10. I have tried using `NSolve` and `Reduce`, but I got nothing, so any help will be most appreciated!

```
xmin = -6.5; 
xmax = 6.5; 
xmatch = 1.5; 
eq1[x_, x0_, E2_] := {Derivative[2][y][x] + (E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, 
                      y[x0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][x0] == 1/10^6}; 

y1[x_, E2_] := y[x] /. NDSolve[eq1[x, xmin, E2], y, {x, xmin, xmatch}][[1]]; 
f1[E2_] := Abs[D[y1[x, E2], x]/y1[x, E2] /. x -> xmatch]; 
y2[x_, E2_] := y[x] /. NDSolve[eq1[x, xmax, E2], y, {x, xmax, xmatch}][[1]]; 
f2[E2_] := Abs[D[y2[x, E2], x]/y2[x, E2] /. x -> xmatch]
f[(E2_)?NumericQ] := f1[E2] - f2[E2]; 
(* The following trial doesn't success *)
NSolve[f[(E2_)?NumericQ] == 0 && 0 < E2 < 10, E2]
rts = Reduce[f == 0 && 2.5 < E2 < 10., E2]
c2 = N[E2 /. {ToRules[rts]}]
Print["The value of E2   was=", c2]
```

---

this is the code that i have written to numerically try to solve the DEs to obtain the roots E2. i am able  to obtain the roots by plotting "exp" versus E2. however, when i try to use the erzek root finder, an error message is generated

```
xmin = (-8.5);

xmax = 8.5;

xmatch = 0.50;

eq[x_, x0_, E2_] := {y''[x] + (2 E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x0] == 0, 
   y'[x0] == 1/10^6};

exp := (# - #2) & @@ ((y'[xmatch]/y[xmatch] /. 
        NDSolve[eq[x, #, E2], y, {x, #, xmatch}][[1]]) & /@ {xmin, 
      xmax});

Plot[exp, {E2, 0, 10}]

Needs["Ersek`RootSearch`"];

rst = RootSearch[exp == 0, {E2, 0, 5}](* gives an error message  *)
```

Comment: `eq1[x_, x0_, E2_] := {(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + (E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][x0] == 1/10^6};` is highly suspect. Did you really mean `y''[x]` rather than `(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]`

Comment: hi,yes..it should have been y''[x].

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in your notebook first to change your code into `InputForm` before you post your code here so it will be cleaner and probably draw more attention. (This time I've done it for you :) )

Then I'd like to point out why your effort leads to nothing. `NSolve` and `Reduce` are functions that only work on analytic expression, while `InterpolatingFunction` generated by  `NDSolve` isn't the case, by the way, the syntax of your equations in `NSolve` and `Reduce` are also incorrect, a correct one should be:

> ```
> f[E2] == 0 && 0 < E2 < 10
> ```

Finally, let me fix your code. In fact some posts for similar issue already exists in this site. (Have a look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5663/1871).), but for your question, considering the nature of your equation, we can turn to a even simpler approach, that's all because, your equation can be solved symbolicly:

```
xmin = -(65/10);
xmax = 65/10;
xmatch = 15/10;
eq[x_, x0_, E2_] = {y''[x] + (E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x0] == 0, y'[x0] == 1/10^6};

exp = # - #2 & @@ ((Abs[y'[xmatch]/y[xmatch]] /. 
       DSolve[eq[x, #, E2], y, x][[1]]) & /@ {xmin, xmax})
(* The result is a little long so I'd like to omit it here *)
```

Now what we should do is just solve `exp == 0`. Unfortunately `Solve` and `NSolve` and `Reduce` are still unavailable, but don't worry, there already exists [a robust package called RootSearch](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) for this! After installing it:

```
rst = RootSearch[exp == 0, {E2, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {{E2 -> 1.}, {E2 -> 1.76087}, {E2 -> 3.}, 
>  {E2 -> 5.}, {E2 -> 5.30345}, {E2 -> 7.}, {E2 -> 9.}}
> ```

Some errors generate but the result is reliable:

```
pts = {Red, Point[{E2, 0} /. rst]}
Plot[exp, {E2, 0, 10}, Epilog -> pts]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

For the new problem you mentioned in the comment below, after some trial, I think what you mean is not `2(E2 - x^2)`, but `(2 E2 - x^2)` by saying "inserted a factor of 2 in front of (E2-x^2)", right? Then, to resolve it, some modification for my `exp` is needed. It should be modified like this:

```
xmin = -(85/10);
xmax = 85/10;
xmatch = 15/10;
eq[x_, x0_, E2_] = {y''[x] + (2 E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x0] == 0, y'[x0] == 1/10^6};

exp = (# - #2) & @@ ((y'[xmatch]/y[xmatch] /. 
        DSolve[eq[x, #, E2], y, x][[1]]) & /@ {xmin, xmax}) // FunctionExpand
(* The result is a little long so I'd like to omit it here *)
```

Here, two modifications are made.

First, I removed the `Abs` function in the `exp`, though I still don't understand the physics background of this expression very well, my intuition told me that the `Abs` is just used to avoid very small complexes, but unfortunately it hasn't been used properly so it causes redundant roots, am I right?

Second, which is the most important, is that I've add a `FunctionExpand` in the definition of `exp`, this function only changes the form of `exp`, but with this modification, `RootSearch` won't lose roots anymore. I thought of adding this after noticed the warning of `RootSearch` seems to suggest some errors in numerical computation, and a simplification for expressions can sometimes avoid this. Anyway, this time we got the desired result, no fake, no lose:

```
rst = RootSearch[exp == 0, {E2, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
>  {{E2 -> 0.5}, {E2 -> 1.5}, {E2 -> 2.5}, {E2 -> 3.5}, {E2 -> 4.5}, 
>   {E2 -> 5.5}, {E2 -> 6.5}, {E2 -> 7.5}, {E2 -> 8.5}, {E2 -> 9.5}}
> ```

---

**Update 2**

Well, before fixing your new code, I'd like to remind you that, it's not good to completely rewrite your question. (Consider how confused the late-comers be.) Also, after your question being edited for several times, you should have noticed that, you can simply add 4 spaces in front of your codes, or select your codes and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to format it.

<strike>The reason for the error of your new code is simple: Just like `Solve`, `NSolve` and `Reduce`, `RootSearch` is also a function for analytic equations i.e. it can't handle the `InterpolatingFunction` generated by `NDSolve`.</strike> As I already mentioned in the comments below, in order to find the roots of an equation containing `InterpolatingFunction`, <strike>the best choice is to</strike> we can use `ParametricNDSolve` or `ParametricNDSolveValue` together with [Ｊ．Ｍ．'s `FindAllCrossings`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/5666#5666):

```
xmin = (-8.5); xmax = 8.5; xmatch = 0.50;
eq[x_, x0_, E2_] = {y''[x] + (2 E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x0] == 0, y'[x0] == 1/10^6};
exp = (# - #2) & @@ ((y'[xmatch]/y[xmatch] /. y -> 
      ParametricNDSolveValue[eq[x, #, E2], y, {x, #, xmatch}, E2][E2]) & /@ {xmin, xmax});

ParallelTable[FindAllCrossings[exp, {E2, i - 1, i}, PlotRange -> 1], {i, 10}]
```

> ```
> {{0.5}, {1.5}, {2.5}, {3.5}, {4.5}, {5.5}, {6.5}, {7.5}, {8.5}, {9.5}}
> ```

Notice that the numeric method isn't that robust (at least when compared to `RootSearch`) so careful adjustments are made here.

---

**Update 3**

OK… after a second look, I noticed that actually `RootSearch` can handle non-analytic equations under certain conditions. I haven't look into the source code of `RootSearch` so I can't confirm the exact condition (maybe "the expression should be derivable"?), but it did manage to solve the `exp` formed by `ParametricFunction`:

```
xmin = (-8.5); xmax = 8.5; xmatch = 0.50;
eq[x_, x0_, E2_] = {y''[x] + (2 E2 - x^2) y[x] == 0, y[x0] == 0, y'[x0] == 1/10^6};

exp = (# - #2) & @@ ((y'[xmatch]/y[xmatch] /. 
        y -> ParametricNDSolveValue[eq[x, #, E2], y, {x, #, xmatch}, 
           E2, WorkingPrecision -> 32][E2]) & /@ {xmin, xmax});

RootSearch[exp == 0, {E2, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
>  {{E2 -> 0.5}, {E2 -> 1.5}, {E2 -> 2.5}, {E2 -> 3.5}, {E2 -> 4.5}, 
>   {E2 -> 5.5}, {E2 -> 6.5}, {E2 -> 7.5}, {E2 -> 8.5}, {E2 -> 9.5}}
> ```

Notice I've added `WorkingPrecision -> 32` in `exp`.

Comment: brilliant-tqvm xzczd! never imagined that the equation can be solved symbolically

Comment: @raj Glad it helped, and will be more glad if you accept this answer by clicking the tick at the top left corner of my answer :D  (If you still feel confused, feel free to continue to ask in the comment :) )

Comment: hi.. have a couple of qns . i've noticed that you have used the  # & syntax in line number 5 of the code. i don't quite follow . can you kindly explain this to me ?  i reran the code for xmin = -8.5, xmax =8.50 , xmatch=1.50 and inserted a factor of 2 in front of (E2-x^2). This is the famous harmonic oscillator problem in quantum physics and the roots are well known =(n+1/2), n=0,1,2,3 etc  An error message was generated. i got some of the roots 0.5,1.5, 2.5 ,7.5, 8.5..but root search missed out on 3.5,4.5,5.5. is there another algorithm to get all the roots? cheers raj

Comment: @raj For the # & part, it's pure function. You can find very detailed explanation in the document by searching `Function` in it, also, have a look at [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871). For the second question, see my edit.

Comment: once again, a big thank you, xzczd. you've been a great help. another qn if i may. suppose i have another  function, not a nice x^2 function( which gives a pleasant analytical solution in terms of hermite polynomilas ), but  something "uglier" like -20/(1  + exp[0.2 x]) without a chance of an  analytical solution. How would we be able to generate  the roots in this case? My guess would be to use NDsolve and rid the function expand command. I tried that but got no where.any ideas? cheers raj

Comment: @raj You want to use `20/(1 + Exp[2 x/10])` instead of `x^2`? It's still solvable for `DSolve`, and there seems to be no root (at least between `0` and `10`) in this case!…… :D OK, I actually know you're asking for an approach without `DSolve`, and the best solution should be [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5666/1871) together with `ParametricNDSolveValue` in v9, while I'm still in v8 so I feel unwilling to write an untested example for it. I believe it won't be a hard task, you can have a try. If you still find it difficult, I don't mind adding a v8 approach.

Comment: hello there xzczd. hope you're well .have relooked at the problem ..works beautifully for functions of x that are solvable analytically.  Tried using the NDSolve method. i need to give the independent variable x a range of values running from, say, 1.1 to 3.3,right?  But i don't get the interpolating function. Is it because of the unknown E?

Comment: @raj As I mentioned in the comment above, the best choice here is to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` in v9, `NDSolve` approach should also be available, but I can't figure out where the shoe pinched without your specific code.

Comment: hi xzczd....please see my code above.not able to get the roots using erzek's root finder.. will appreciate your expert feed-back . cheers raj

Comment: @raj See my edit.

Comment: hi xzczd, very many thanks for the code. It runs  on V9 &10 ,right? i will have to upgrade my version then