# Solving coupled differential equations with an eigenvalue

Tags: differential-equations

I have 2 coupled differential equations with an eigenvalue `Ei` and want to solve them

```
 ϕ''[r] + (2/r) ϕ'[r] - mb^2 ϕ[r] + (Ei + g*A[r])^2 ϕ[r] == 0
 A''[r] + (2/r) A'[r] - mv^2 A[r] - 2 g (Ei + g*A[r]) (ϕ[r])^2 == 0
```

where `mb`, `mv` and `g` are constants equal to `1`. The boundary conditions of these equations are

```
ϕ[0] = 1, ϕ'[0] = 0, A[0] = 0, A'[0] = 0
```

Because of the singularity of `r`, we assume `r = 1*10^-8`. What I want to find is  the maximum radius `(r)` when `ϕ[rmax] = 0`, `ϕ'[rmax] = 0`, `A[rmax] = 0`, `A'[rmax] = 0`.
I've with this

```
mb = mv = g = 1; 
b = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ϕ''[r] + (2/r) ϕ'[r] - mb^2 ϕ[r] + (Ei + g A[r])^2 ϕ[r] == 0,
          A''[r] + (2/r) A'[r] - mv^2 A[r] - 2 g (Ei + g A[r]) (ϕ[r])^2 == 0,
          ϕ[0.00000001] == 1, ϕ'[0.00000001] == 0, A[0.00000001] == 0,
          A'[0.00000001] == 0}, {ϕ, A},
     {r, 0.00000001, 100}, {Ei}]
```

but it didn't work when I wanted to find `Ei` like this

```
val = Map[FindRoot[b[Ei][100], {Ei, #}] &, {1, 2, 3}]
```

and the maximum radius. How should I solve this issue ? 
Also I want to plot `ϕ` and `A` vs `r`.

Comment: What approach do you want to take for finding `Ei`? `b[Ei]` actually returns 2 `InterpolatingFunction` while you only have 1 unknown! If you replace the `{ϕ, A}` inside  `ParametricNDSolve` with `ϕ` or `A`, you'll get a solution, whether the solution is correct or not is another story. BTW, you may want to try this package: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/

Comment: I want to find `Ei` where the `ϕ` and the `ϕ'`  when r (maximum radius) are equal to 0.  So I think I can use findroot.

Comment: As mentioned above, `ϕ[Ei] == 0` and `ϕ'[Ei] == 0` give two equations, use either of them inside `FindRoot` or `RootSearch` will give you a result.

Comment: How do I have to write the code of `FindRoot` like what you've said in Mathematica?

Comment: I noticed that you've modified your equations for several times, are you sure it's correct this time? Maybe you can show us the original problem?

Comment: Yes, I think. I just change the sign of some parts of the equations.
The original problem is I want to solve those 2 differential equations where there is an eigenvalue that I have to get. The boundary conditions are still the same.
Till now, I don't get the eigenvalue because there will always an error when I want to find eigenvalue by using FindRoot. Maybe you can tell me the other way how to find eigenvalue like I want. Thanks

Comment: Seems that this hasn't been done: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let me explain why your attempt doesn't succeed. Here I'll modify your sample a little for clarity (Of course the troublesome part is leaved untouched ):

```
lb = 10^-8;
mb = mv = g = 1;

eqn = {ϕ''[r] + (2/r) ϕ'[r] - mb^2 ϕ[r] + (Ei + g*A[r])^2 ϕ[r] == 0,
       A''[r] + (2/r) A'[r] - mv^2 A[r] - 2 g (Ei + g*A[r]) (ϕ[r])^2 == 0};
bc = {ϕ[lb] == 1, ϕ'[lb] == 0, A[lb] == 0, A'[lb] == 0};

b = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, {ϕ, A}, {r, lb, 100}, {Ei}]
```

[image]

As you see, `ParametricNDSolveValue` returns a `ParametricFunction`, and again when you give a numeric value to the `ParametricFunction`, it will return something: it will return what? Let's have a try:

```
pb = b[1]
```

[image]

Hmm… the calculation stopped at about `t = 8.95`, far below `100`, but it's not the key point here, the key point is, `b[1]` doesn't return a `InterpolatingFunction`, it returns a `List` of `InterpolatingFunction`! Then what will something like `pb[1]` return? A expression that `FindRoot` doesn't understand:

```
pb[1]
```

[image]

There're many way to circumvent this problem, let me show several here. Since you only have one unknown `Ei`, only one equation is needed. I'll use `ϕ[Ei]` for example:

```
(* Circumvention 1 *)
fb[x_?NumericQ] := b[x][[1]]
FindRoot[fb[Ei][5], {Ei, 1}]

(* Circumvention 2 *)
fb2[x_?NumericQ] := b[x][5] // Through // First
FindRoot[fb2[Ei], {Ei, 1}]

(* Circumvention 3 *)
newb = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn, bc}, ϕ, {r, lb, 100}, {Ei}]
FindRoot[newb[Ei][5], {Ei, 1}]

(* Circumvention 4 *)
newb2 = ParametricNDSolve[{eqn, bc}, {ϕ, A}, {r, lb, 100}, {Ei}]
fϕ = ϕ /. newb2
FindRoot[fϕ[Ei][5], {Ei, 1}]
```

You'll still see some warnings when you execute the above code, but it's mainly because of the nature of your equation and it's another issue, at least `FindRoot` *works* this time!

Well, personally I feel the behavior of `ParametricNDSolveValue` undesirable, why it doesn't return a `List` of `ParametricFunction`?

Finally, my intuition told me that you may be interested in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38603/1871).

Comment: It's very helpful. Thank you for your help.