# what to do when NSolve does not solve

Tags: equation-solving

```
f = 696.1125540355472 + 3.9668099604385043 x + LogGamma[1 + x] - LogGamma[169 + x]

Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}]

Solve[f == 0, x, Reals]
NSolve[f == 0, x]
```

I know that the LogGamma probably is causing problems, but is there a way to solve this type of equations? In fact, I have all my functions involve `LogGamma`, and these need to be solved numerically, for x>0.

Thanks!

Comment: After observing the plot you can numerically solve the equation using `FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ {-0, 6}` in this case. Also look at the interesting answers here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An additional option, that might not be known (I did not know about this until Daniel mentioned this on another post), is that if one have an idea about the range of values of the variable being solved for, and possibly other parameters, then `NSolve` and `Solve` will now be able to find solutions.

At least from the examples I've tried so far

```
f = 696.1125540355472 +3.9668099604385043 x +LogGamma[1 + x] -LogGamma[169 + x];
Solve[{f == 0 && (0 <=  x <= 10)}, x]
NSolve[{f == 0 && (0 <=  x <= 10)}, x]
```

Both of the above produce the solution

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

If you only need a numerical solution, then `FindRoot` should be one option:

```
FindRoot[f, {x, 4}]
(* {x -> 6.91844} *)
```

and

```
Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[{x, f}] /. FindRoot[f, {x, 4}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very detailed and pretty answer. Thanks too!