# slwcon and eincr in integrating multivariate Gaussian random variables

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

Why is the following integration involving multivariate Gaussian distribution so slow and generating an error? Is there a better integration strategy? All that I'm doing is considering $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and computing the (trivial expectation) $E[1]$, which obviously equals to $1$.

```
muvec = ConstantArray[0.1, 4];
sigmat = IdentityMatrix[4];
npdf[x_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[muvec, sigmat], x]; 
NIntegrate[ 1 * npdf[{x1, x2, x3, x4}], 
           {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
           {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
           {x3, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
           {x4, -Infinity, Infinity} ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This results in the errors

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 1.000000567592556` and 0.000021505642234874004` for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

and the result

```
{12.521, 1.}
```

The result is correct, but it has taken far too long (in my opinion), and moreover, I'm a little bit puzzled by the error message (despite reading http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html), and I've tried other integration methods and it's still relatively slow.

In the actual application I have in mind, I want to consider $h(y) := E[ g(y;X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)] $, where $g$ is somewhat complex and I need to use the expression $h(y)$ over and over again, and hence if I can't even compute $E[1]$ quickly and accurately, I have little hopes for computing the more difficult expectation.

**Edit** I emphasize that a symbolic integration of the solution is not of interest. In particular, since the question at hand is a "toy example", of which the real application is computing a more complex expectation $E[g(X_1,\ldots, X_n)]$ of which the function $g$ is sufficiently complex that there's no hope of a symbolic integral solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the integrand is highly localized at the origin; e.g.,

```
Log[10, npdf[{6, 0, 0, 0}]] // N
(* -9.16177 *)
```

limiting the range of integration reduces run time by a factor of three and moderately improves accuracy.

```
muvec = ConstantArray[1/10, 4];
sigmat = IdentityMatrix[4];
npdf[x_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[muvec, sigmat], x];
NIntegrate[1*npdf[{x1, x2, x3, x4}], {x1, -6, 6}, {x2, -6, 6}, {x3, -6, 6}, 
    {x4, -6, 6}, PrecisionGoal -> 5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Not nearly as good as the answer by ciao but perhaps helpful.  (Note that only the error message `NIntegrate::slwcon` persists.)

By the way, I first tried several `NIntegrate` methods but with little improvement.  The issue, it seems to me, is that the integrand becomes ever more localized as the dimension increases.  3D works fine, for instance.  Also, if a `Precision` of, say, `3` is acceptable, big savings can be achieved: `{0.275684, 1.00009}`.  Decreasing the range of integration in this case helps further, because it concentrates the integration more on the central peak: `{0.241199, 1.00001}`.  Taking advantages of symmetries, if any, also could be helpful.  Finally, a coordinate transformation to spread the central peak relative to the wings could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! This does answer my original question about computing $E[1]$ using numerical integration techniques. The subsequent follow up on $E[g(\ldots)]$ is an afterthought.

Answer (score 4):

While the unknown `g` might or might not be amenable to this approach, it's really fast on `g == 1`:

```
Expectation[
  1, {x1, x2, x3, x4} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[muvec, sigmat]] // RepeatedTiming
```

(23000 times faster than `NIntegrate`.)

Then there's also [`NExpectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html) to try, too.

---

Ever since I came across Guess who it is's use of the Chebyshev polynomial proxy this morning in [How to find numerically all roots of a function in a given range?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range/92042#92042), I've been itching for something to try it out on.  It's really cool.  It approximates a univariate function, but [chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org) has a bivariate method; perhaps it is extensible.  What I want to show here is how well this works on the following.

We approximate `g` over the interval from `-10` to `10`; outside that the Gaussian is so small that practically there is no contribution to the integral.

```
r = 10;
g = BesselJ[2, #] &;
n = 32;
cnodes = Rescale[N[Cos[Pi Range[0, n]/n], 30], {-1, 1}, {-r, r}];
cc = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[g /@ cnodes, 1];
cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;

gcheb = Expand[cc.Table[ChebyshevT[n - 1, x1/r], {n, Length@cc}]] /. 
   c_ /; c == 0 :> 0;
Expectation[gcheb,
   {x1, x2, x3, x4} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[muvec, sigmat]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.081965, 0.0988631125184331759104}  *)
```

There are coefficients of the form ``` 0``23.443340842020458 ```, and it saves time with the integration to remove them; hence the replacement `c_ /; c == 0 :> 0`.  The use of `n = 32` was inherited from @Guess; the precision of `cnodes` was adjusted from `20` to `30` after examining `gcheb`, but it made little difference in the result.

The first `NIntegrate` misses the mark widely.  Increasing `MinRecursion` helps, but it takes much, much longer, even though it recognizes a convergence problem.

```
NIntegrate[
  BesselJ[2, x1]*npdf[{x1, x2, x3, x4}], {x1, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {105.429, 0.00890915}  *)

NIntegrate[
  BesselJ[2, x1]*npdf[{x1, x2, x3, x4}], {x1, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  MinRecursion -> 3] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> NIntegrate::eincr:...

```
(*  {1563.69, 0.0988631}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks. For $g \equiv 1$, this is indeed a great approach (I suspect the same as symbolic integration). But for general $g$, it seems like `NExpectation` collapses back to `NIntegrate` anyway.

Comment: Nice to see someone excited about this like I am. :) I've seen the [paper on the bivariate Chebyshev approximant](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130908002); there's still a lot to digest before I can try implementing it myself (unless you beat me to it ;) ). BTW: `NIntegrate[]` is capable of (tensor product) Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature, so at least that one is able to avoid an *ad hoc* choice of `n` like mine.

Comment: +1 for link to most interesting answer...

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thanks for introducing it to the site. (I had missed your earliest answer, somehow.)  Students arrived on campus yesterday and I was too busy to do any real work on it.  Boyd's simplified overview makes choosing $n$ *seem* simple, but I didn't have time to look into it.

Comment: Thanks, @ciao.  It's a fairly simple, if advanced, technique and seems quite powerful.  I hope people will appreciate Guess's other answers.  My first thought was, "I wonder if this is what `NSolve` does?"  But WRI claims the breakthrough in `NSolve` was [due to their own research.](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/).

Comment: I think this is one point where our use of *Mathematica* can have an edge over the use of MATLAB by Chebfun. Since the powerful idea of Chebfun is the very simple idea of approximating a function with a polynomial, and *Mathematica*'s polynomial handling seems pretty okay (Gröbner methods require symbolic manipulation, and MATLAB doesn't have that), in principle it should be possible to do stuff that is difficult for Chebfun. I'm dreaming of so many possibilities right now… :D

Comment: Anyway: I'd believe the claim that the transcendental roots idea in its current form is based entirely on Germundsson's own research; he has been working on this for quite a while.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I do not doubt the claim and did not mean to insinuate there is any reason to doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

About 30X faster integration, no errors...

```
Clear[x, x1, x2, x3, x4]
muvec = ConstantArray[1/10, 4];
sigmat = IdentityMatrix[4];
pdf = PDF[MultinormalDistribution[muvec, sigmat], {x1, x2, x3, x4}] //
   FullSimplify
Integrate[
  1*pdf, {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
         {x3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think this is getting at the spirit of the problem. In particular, you are using symbolic integration and where I'm explicitly considering numerical integration (i.e. the real problem I have in mind is not to simply compute $E[1]$ but rather $E[g(X_1,...X_n)]$ of which there's no chance for a symbolic evaluation. Hence, I'm most interested in understanding what is the best strategy to even numerically integrate $E[1]$.

Comment: @user32416 Then update your question with appropriate details for readers, else it's tilting and windmills...

Comment: @user32416 and what is *g*?

Comment: It's a highly problem specific function and I don't think that specifying it here is of general interest to the community. But we can simply think of $g$ as a continuous function in all the arguments. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @user32416: In that case, sorry, voting to close for insufficient information.

Comment: @user, in general, without at least knowing the structure of what's multiplying the Gaussian, it's hard to give good advice. Cubatures are **hard**, dude. Coming up with efficient ones more so. That's why any opportunity to exploit structure is relentlessly pursued.