# Avoiding the suppression of messages by NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, debugging, message-coding, testing-and-verification

Consider the following code:

```
test[x_] := If[1 < x < 2, Message[Test::message]; x^2, x];
NIntegrate[test[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> 5.33333333333334

I.e. it gives me the result, suppressing all messages emitted by `test`. OTOH, this code does emit the messages:

```
N@Sum[test[x] 1/1000, {x, 0, 3, 1/1000}]
```

> Test::message: -- Message text not found --
> Test::message: -- Message text not found --
> Test::message: -- Message text not found --
> General::stop: Further output of Test::message will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> 5.3338335

I'd really like to receive the messages from the integrand, because in *Mathematica* 11 they allow to see stack trace. How can I stop `NIntegrate` from suppressing the messages?

Comment: Do you want to trace your function or `NIntegrate`?

Comment: @Shadowray I want to trace my function, and only if it generates a message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a workaround to the message suppression that still allows the subdivision of the interval of integration $[0,3]$ at $x = 1, 2$.  You have to protect the message-generating code sufficiently deep so that the symbolic processing takes care of the singularities.  Then inside a `?NumericQ` protected function, turn on messages again by resetting `$Messages`.

```
ClearAll[test, ftrue];
With[{$m = $Messages},
 ftrue[x_?NumericQ] := Block[{$Messages = $m}, Message[Test::message]; x^2];
 ];
test[x_] := If[1 < x < 2, ftrue[x], x];
NIntegrate[test[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> `Message::msgl`: `$MessageList` `$MessageList` not a list; reset to `{}`.
>   `Test::message`: -- Message text not found --
>   `Test::message`: -- Message text not found --
>   `Test::message`: -- Message text not found --
>   `General::stop`: Further output of `Test::message` will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> `Out[56]= 5.33333`

**The extra message**

There's an extraneous `Message::msgl` that is the fault of `NIntegrate`.  (It doesn't seem to matter or wasn't detected, since messages are turned off.)  It seems easy enough just to ignore it, but if that's unacceptable, you could reset `$MessageList` yourself, or `Quiet` the message:

```
If[! ListQ[$MessageList], $MessageList = {}];  (* OR *)
Quiet[Message[Test::message], Message::msgl];
```

Using this definition of `ftrue`, you can see the message generation, even though the messages themselves are not printed:

```
ftrue[x_?NumericQ] := (
   If[Length@$MessageList < 4, Print[$MessageList]];
   Message[Test::message]; x^2);

NIntegrate[test[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> `$MessageList`
>   `{Message::msgl,Test::message}`
>   `{Message::msgl,Test::message,Test::message}`
>
> `Out[69]= 5.33333`

**A glimpse at the symbolic processing**

It may be of interest to inspect how `NIntegrate` breaks down the integrand.
With the OP's `test[]`, it looks like the following.  We get three integration regions

```
NIntegrate[test[x], {x, 0, 3}, IntegrationMonitor :> ((regions = #) &), MaxRecursion -> 0];
Column[regions /. r_NIntegrate`GeneralRule :> Short[r], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

With my version of `test[]`, the `x^2` in the first region in the table (from `1` to `2`) is replaced with `ftrue[x]`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer below is for the first version of the question:

> I'd really like to receive the messages from the integrand. How can I stop `NIntegrate` from suppressing the messages?

There are several reasons for this behavior. Generally speaking, `NIntegrate` pre-evaluates and localizes the integrands in order to facilitate different symbolic pre-processing and numerics algorithms.

If we redefine the integrand with `Piecewise` we will get the message once, when [`PiecewiseNIntegrate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95260/34008) does the preprocessing:

```
In[142]:= ClearAll[Test, test]
test[x_] := Piecewise[{{Message[Test::message]; x^2, 1 < x < 2}}, x];
NIntegrate[test[x], {x, 0, 3}]

During evaluation of In[142]:=
 Test::message: -- Message text not found --

Out[144]= 5.33333
```

Further, we can prevent the symbolic processing with `_?NumericQ` and use `Print` or `Echo`. (Note that the integral converges too slowly.)

```
ClearAll[Test, test]
test[x_?NumericQ] := 
  If[1 < x < 2, (Echo[Row[{Test::message, " : ", x}]]; x^2), x];
NIntegrate[test[x], {x, 0, 3}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
(*
Test::message : 1.08055

Test::message : 1.5

Test::message : 1.91945

... 

5.34841 *)
```

I am not sure what kind of testing you want to do. You might consider using [`EvaluationMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) or [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/34008) instead.

Comment: The way with `Piecewise` defies the purpose of this check: the message is emitted when `test[x]` is called with a symbolic `x`. And the way with `Echo` doesn't allow me to see Stack Trace, unlike messages (new feature of Mathematica 11).

Comment: Right. As I mentioned in my answer you might be better off using `EvaluationMonitor`.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated to issue a General::stop message**

Maybe the following does what you want?

```
handler[Hold[Message[Test::message], True]] := With[
    {stop = Flatten@Position[$MessageList, HoldForm[General::stop]]},

    Which[
        FreeQ[$MessageList[[stop-1]], HoldForm[Test::message]],
        CellPrint @ Cell[
            BoxData[Internal`MessageTemplate[Test, "message", "Test message", StandardForm]],
            "Message","MSG"
        ];
        If[Count[$MessageList, HoldForm[Test::message]] > 2,
            CellPrint @ Cell[
                BoxData[Internal`MessageTemplate[General, "stop", StringForm[General::stop, HoldForm[Test::message]], StandardForm]],
                "Message", "MSG"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

test[x_] := If[1<x<2, Message[Test::message];x^2, x];

Internal`HandlerBlock[{"Message", handler}, NIntegrate[test[x], {x,0,3}]]
```

Test::message: Test message

5.33333

Comment: Are you sure this works? The function is called 11 times between `x == 1` and `x == 2`, but I only get one message.  Shouldn't there be 3, followed by a General::stop?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you have lingering definitions, e.g., something like `test[x_?NumericQ] := ..`?

Comment: Also, some more work is needed to enable `General::stop` to do its thing.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Just did it again with a fresh kernel: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1L14.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 `test` is only called once between 1 and 2. `test[x]` evaluates to `If[1<x<2, Message[Test::message];x^2, x]` but then stops because `x` is not numeric. Then, the `NIntegrate` piecewise code analyzes the `If` object and converts it into a `Piecewise` object (which is when the one message gets generated). Then, NIntegrate uses the `Piecewise` object instead of `test`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. My interpretation of what the OP wanted was slightly different, but now I see it does what you wanted it to do, which might indeed be what is sought.

Comment: Is there a reference for ``Internal`HandlerBlock``?

Comment: There is some discussion of it here on MSE, but I don't know of any official documentation.