# How to make this kind of integration with the trigonometric function?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to make the following integration. But I am not sure about the result obtained as follows.

**Is there some way to get more reliable and accurate results?**

Thanks.

```
NIntegrate[
    (x1 x2 x3)/((1 + x1^2)^(3/2) (1 + x3^2)^(3/2) (1 + x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4]) Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 - x1 x2 Cos[x5]] Sqrt[ 1 + 9 (x1^2 + x2^2 - x1 x2 Cos[x6])])
     , {x1, 0, ∞}
     , {x2, 0, ∞}
     , {x3, 0, ∞}
     , {x4, 0, 2 π}
     , {x5, 0, 2 π}
     , {x6, 0, 2 π}
]
```

**Edit:**

To avoid the singularity problem, I revise the above problem and make the integral as follows,

```
        fexp = (x1 x2 x3)/((1 + x1^2)^(3/2) (1 + x3^2)^(
        3/2) (1 + x2^2 - x2 Cos[x4]) Sqrt[
        3 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 2 x1 x2 Cos[x5]] Sqrt[
        1 + x1^2 + x2^2/4 - x1 x2 Cos[x6]]);

    NIntegrate[fexp
               , {x1, 0, ∞}
               , {x2, 0, ∞}
               , {x3, 0, ∞}
               , {x4, 0, 2 π}
               , {x5, 0, 2 π}
               , {x6, 0, 2 π}]

   Out=75.0157  (with warning messages, Numerical integration converging 
                too slowly; .... )
```

In addition, I want to get the results numerically by taking some proper algorithms. Of course, we can check the results analytically (partly).

Comment: The integrand has a singularity `1 + x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4] == 0` in `x2` and `x4`. I have strong doubts about the convergence of the improper integral under consideration.

Comment: I think this kind of singularity is not so serious in integrations.  The difficult part is from the oscillation and multi-dimensional integral.

Comment: `1 + x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4] ==(x2 - 1/2 (7 Cos[x4] - Sqrt[41 + 49 Cos[2 x4]]/Sqrt[2])*(x2 - 
     1/2 (7 Cos[x4] + Sqrt[41 + 49 Cos[2 x4]]/Sqrt[2])`. Wee see non- integrable singularities at `x2 ==-1/2 (7 Cos[x4] - Sqrt[41 + 49 Cos[2 x4]]/Sqrt[2]` and `x2 == 1/2 (7 Cos[x4] - Sqrt[41 + 49 Cos[2 x4]]/Sqrt[2]` in `x2`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494  Thanks. Now, I think we cannot neglect singularity.  But, that's not the intent of the question. I revise the questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do most of the inegrations analyticlly. As the other comments mention, you have to consider singularities.

```
f = (x1 x2 x3)/((1 + x1^2)^(3/2) (1 + x3^2)^(3/2) (1 + x2^2 - 
        7 x2 Cos[x4]) Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 - x1 x2 Cos[x5]] Sqrt[
       1 + 9 (x1^2 + x2^2 - x1 x2 Cos[x6])]) // Together;

int21 = Integrate[f, {x5, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {x6, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Assumptions -> {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, 0 < x4 < 2 Pi}]

(*   (16 x1 x2 x3 EllipticK[-((2 x1 x2)/(
     x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2))] EllipticK[-((18 x1 x2)/(
     1 + 9 (x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2)))])/(Sqrt[(x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2) (1 + 
      9 (x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2))] ((1 + x1^2) (1 + x3^2))^(
   3/2) (1 + x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4]))   *)

int22 = Integrate[int21, {x3, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, 0 < x4 < 2 Pi}]

(*   (16 x1 x2 EllipticK[-((2 x1 x2)/(x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2))] EllipticK[-((
   18 x1 x2)/(1 + 9 (x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2)))])/((1 + x1^2)^(
 3/2) Sqrt[(x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2) (1 + 9 (x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2))] (1 + 
   x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4]))   *)
```

Singularities at

```
ContourPlot[(1 + x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4]) == 0, {x2, 0, 10}, {x4, 0, 
  2 Pi}]
```

In this range, integral is zero.

```
int23 = Integrate[int22, {x4, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> x1 > 0 && x2 > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]

(*   ConditionalExpression[0, 
 3 Sqrt[5] + 2 x2 >= 7 && 2 x2 <= 7 + 3 Sqrt[5]]   *)

{red = Reduce[int23[[2]], x2], red // N}

(*   {1/2 (7 - 3 Sqrt[5]) <= x2 <= 1/2 (7 + 3 Sqrt[5]), 
 0.145898 <= x2 <= 6.8541}   *)

int24 = Integrate[int22, {x4, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  x1 > 0 && (0 < x2 < 1/2 (7 - 3 Sqrt[5]) || 
     1/2 (7 + 3 Sqrt[5]) < x2)]

(*   (32 \[Pi] x1 x2 EllipticK[-((2 x1 x2)/(
   x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2))] EllipticK[-((18 x1 x2)/(
   1 + 9 (x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2)))])/((1 + x1^2)^(
 3/2) Sqrt[(x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2) (1 - 47 x2^2 + x2^4) (1 + 
    9 (x1^2 - x1 x2 + x2^2))])   *)

int25 = NIntegrate[
   int24, {x1, 0, Infinity}, {x2, 0, 1/2 (7 - 3 Sqrt[5])}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15] + 
  NIntegrate[
   int24, {x1, 0, Infinity}, {x2, 1/2 (7 + 3 Sqrt[5]), Infinity}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(*   3.820016280311350   *)
```

**Edit**

What i did with int23, is regarding x1 and x2 as parameters and calculating the principal value for x4. This is affirmed by inserting parameters.

```
ii22[x1_, x2_, x4_] = int22; Manipulate[
 Plot[ii22[x1, x2, x4], {x4, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> 5], {{x1, 2}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{x2, 1/E}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
int23b = Integrate[int22 /. {x2 -> 1/E}, {x4, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> x1 > 0]

(*   0   *)

Reduce[0 < x4 < 2 Pi && 0 == (1 + x2^2 - 7 x2 Cos[x4]) /. 
  x2 -> 1/E, x4, Reals]

(*   x4 == 2 \[Pi] - ArcCos[(1 + E^2)/(7 E)] || 
 x4 == ArcCos[(1 + E^2)/(7 E)]   *)

NIntegrate[
 int22 /. {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 1/E}, {x4, 0, ArcCos[(1 + E^2)/(7 E)], 
  2 Pi - ArcCos[(1 + E^2)/(7 E)], 2 Pi}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

(*   3.71023*10^-14   *)
```

I'm no pure mathematician to be able to proof this kind of proceeding. But otherwise you must state, integral is not integrable.

Comment: I have never seen the notion of principal value for multiple integrals. In fact, `int23` is an iterated integral where the outer integral is treated as the principal value. I repeat, the double improper integral under consideration diverges and `NIntegrate` of the integrand under consideration bears witness to this, reporting of a possible singularity.

Comment: See [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Improper_integral) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) for info.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what you mean by "integral is not integrable"? TIA.

Comment: Example: Suppose $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the ball with radius 2 centered at the origin, set $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}$.
Is $\int_Bf(x,y)dxdy$ defined? Clearly $\int_B |f(x,y)| dx dy$ is infinite. But using polar coordinates $x+iy=re^{i\varphi}$ (and using $dxdy = r dr d\varphi$ as a recipe, no theorem) and using `PrincipalValue->True` for the $r$-integral yields the result $\pi\log 3$. Is this a meaningful number? Can the notion of the integral be extended, with good properties, to such functions $f$? Cf. [this 6-year-old post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92684).

Comment: @user293787: Thank you for the link. As far as I understand it, that is an invention of [Dr. Wolfgang Hintze](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16361/dr-wolfgang-hintze) only.  The convergence of an improper integral should not depend on an exhaustion of the domain of the integration and coordinates (see G.H. Hardy, "A course of pure mathematics" , Cambridge Univ. Press (1975) for info.). Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user64494 If we insist on "not depend on an exhaustion of the domain of the integration" then we also exclude the usual [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) so not sure why you bring that up. The question of coordinate independence is more interesting, which is what I was trying to hint at in my example.