# WorkingPrecision in a sum

Tags: plotting, summation, precision-and-accuracy

If I am interested in getting a fairly precise plot of `f2` below, can I use `WorkingPrecision` to do this?

```
f1 = Sin [ x Log [ Prime [ i ] ] ]/( Prime [ i ] );
f2  = Sum [ f1, {i, 1, 50} ];
```

I did look at some of the questions under `WorkingPrecision`. None seemed quite on point. If I specify a precision in the code, do I have to do so in the plotting as well (and conversely)?

Comment: Have you tried plotting what you have already? Can you show the code for that? What is wrong with the plot you obtain currently?

Comment: @MarcoB: Yes, I just used Plot[ f2, { } ] with limits. But I doubt I get the benefit of 50 terms if I don't increase precision. What's wrong with it? Nothing, but I would like to identify zeros of the sum with good precision. My experience with 9.0 (home) is that there is often a big diff. in results from precision unspecified to precision specified.

Comment: For the exact expression should the sum be to infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in obtaining approximations of the zeros of that function, you don't really need to plot it to high precision.

In this case, `NSolve` is able to give you **numerical solutions** for specific ranges of $x$, and it can do that at an arbitrary precision that you specify using the `WorkingPrecision` option:

```
NSolve[f2 == 0 && 0 <= x <= 15, x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

(* Out: 
{{x -> 0}, 
 {x -> 3.80400271741859550812071773878}, 
 {x -> 10.3253913711535069593238631633},
 {x -> 14.0297407505371491584516215691}}
*)
```

---

A much faster approach uses numerical root-finding methods to **find all the zeros of your function in a given interval**. A few methods have been proposed on this site to do so using numerical methods; I'll refer you to a [recent post by yohbs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91784/27951) on this topic.

For instance, you could use [yohbs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/367)'s excellent `rootSearchD` function from [his answer in that thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91785/27951) (where you can also find the code for it). `rootSearchD` needs a pure function to work on, so I generate such a function `f` from your expression of `f1` and `f2`. I then look for zeros of that function in the interval $[\text{rangemin}, \text{rangemax}]=[100,106]$ setting the desired precision of the results using `WorkingPrecision`.

```
f = Sum[Sin[# Log[Prime[i]]]/Prime[i], {i, 1, 50}] &;
rangemin = 100; rangemax = 106;

nsols = rootSearchD[f, rangemin, rangemax, WorkingPrecision -> 35]

Plot[f[x], {x, rangemin, rangemax},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Tooltip[Point[{#, 0}], #] & /@ nsols},
  ImageSize -> Large
]

(* Out: {100.19626209644848914285986869397657,
         101.59999375978473413106702727668323,
         101.84542249631610381942296725497735,
         105.15676371559998831763738622073285} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is very much what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @daniel I'm glad to hear that my answer was helpful. If it satisfies your requirements, you might consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it. Thank you!

Comment: With pleasure.  I usually give it 24 hours but got occupied.