# FindRoot of interpolating function from NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

I am having issues finding the root of an interpolating function obtained from NDSolve. For example:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]

(*  {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>]}}  *)
```

Of course, the solution is simply $y=\cos(t)$ (this is a simpler example, my actual function doesn't have an analytic solution), but absurd things happen when I try to find roots:

```
FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, 0}]

(*  {t -> -1.77636*10^-15}  *)
```

It gives me a number close to 0, which is not a root of $\cos(t)$. If I start elsewhere I get other stuff that is also wrong. For example, starting near 0.1, I get 10.99 which is not a zero either...

```
FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, 0.1}]

(*  {t -> 10.9973}  *)
```

If I start the search near $\pi/2$ then I do get that answer, but I want to find the *first* positive zero and my actual function has a parameter that can push the zero arbitrarily close to $t=0$, so I need to start the search near 0 but then it just always returns something close to zero which is *not* the solution... is there any way to make this work?

My second attempt was to use `FindInstance`, but with interpolating functions it doesn't evaluate at all, it just returns the same thing I wrote...

```
FindInstance[y[t] == 0 /. sol, t]

Out[36]= FindInstance[{InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t] == 0}, t]
```

And it just does that and won't give me a number no matter what I do... am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Show us your real function. In your simple case providing two starting values to avoid using derivatives (e.g. `FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, 0.5, 0.7}]`) leads to the $\pi/2$ solution. On the other hand, if you start with $0$ but restrict the search domain to that over which you solved the differential equation (e.g. `FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, 0, 0, 10}]`) you get an error explaining the weird behavior you observed ("The point {0.} is at the edge of the search region {0.,10.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.").

Comment: I did not get any error messages, but that makes sense. I tried changing the domain of the differential equation's solution to {t,-10,10}, however, and it is still returning 0 as a root when I search near 0.

Giving it two starting points does give me a root, but since I want it to work for arbitrary parameters, there is no way to warranty that that root will be the smallest one.

Comment: My actual problem is a system of equations: 

eq = {phib''[
    t] == (m2*l2*ls)/(m1*l1^2 + m2*l2^2 + Ib)*(phis''[t]*
        Cos[phib[t] - phis[t]] + (phis'[t])^2*
        Sin[phib[t] - phis[t]]) - 
    g*(m1*l1 - m2*l2 + mb*(l2 - l1)/2)/(m1*l1^2 + m2*l2^2 + Ib)*
     Sin[phib[t]], 
  phis''[t] == 
   l2/ls*(phib''[t]*Cos[phis[t] - phib[t]] + (phib'[t])^2*
        Sin[phis[t] - phib[t]]) - g/ls*Sin[phis[t]], 
  phib[0] == 3*Pi/4, phis[0] == Pi/2, phib'[0] == 0, phis'[0] == 0}

and I need a function that returns the value of t for which phib[t]=0 as a function of l1,l2,ls.

Comment: Could you put the actual equations back into the main question instead of as a comment? I tried running them from the comment but got back "NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0..", so I'm guessing the cut and paste didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You're experiencing the typical and, in the simple example, expected limitations of searching for roots.  The two `FindRoot` results are easily understood in terms of Newton's method.  The best way to proceed, assuming given the example is typical, is to use [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html).

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, firstzero = t; "RemoveEvent"]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
firstzero
(*  1.5708  *)
```

If `firstzero` is not accurate enough, use it as a starting point for `FindRoot`.

```
FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, firstzero, 0, 10}]
(*  {t -> 1.5708}  *)
```

---

*Addendum -- What's happening in Newton's method*

Basically the first step in both of the OP's examples goes outside the domain of the solution.  Stepping outside the domain of an interpolating function usually leads to unpredictable results.

```
FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, 0, 0, 10}]
```

> FindRoot::reged: The point {0.} is at the edge of the search region {0.,10.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region. >>

```
(*
  {t -> 0.}
*)
```

Note the derivative is slightly positive at the initial point `t == 0`, indicating that the next step should be in the negative direction.

```
y'[0] /. sol
(*
  {2.71051*10^-20}
*)
```

In the second case, the starting is just not close enough to the root.

```
FindRoot[y[t] == 0 /. sol, {t, 0.1, 0, 10}]
```

> FindRoot::reged: The point {10.} is at the edge of the search region {0.,10.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region. >>

```
(*
  {t -> 10.}
*)
```

The derivative is so small that the first step goes just beyond the domain again:

```
y'[0.1] /. sol
0.1 - y[0.1]/y'[0.1] /. sol
(*
  {-0.0998334}
  {10.0666}
*)
```

If you do not have any information about the roots, then a direct search, which is what `WhenEvent` is essentially doing above, seems necessary.  In terms of built-in functions, `NDSolve` seems hard to beat when you are already using it to construct the function.  One could use `Plot`, but it seems more likely to miss two close zero-crossings.  Even if a function `f[t]` is obtained by other means, if it is differentiable, this should be efficient and robust:

```
NDSolve[{y'[t] == f'[t], y[0] == f[0], 
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, firstzero = t; "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
```

If the derivative `f'[t]` cannot be calculated, then `Plot` is probably the best bet.  Then one could use [Brent's method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html#509557818).

Related: [How to find numerically all roots of a function in a given range?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range/91790#91790)

---

*Update 2021.5.25*

At some point in the past, I believe the following did not work, but a few versions ago (I think), `NSolve` was updated to call `InverseFunction` when the interpolating function can be isolated.  Perhaps `InverseFunction` was updated to handle `InterpolatingFunction`, too.  `NSolve` and `InverseFunction` seem to return the first root only.

```
NSolve[y[x] == 0 /. sol, x]
```

> NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> ```
> (*  {{x -> 1.5708}}  *)
> ```

```
InverseFunction[y /. First@sol][0.`]
```

> ```
> (*  1.5708  *)
> ```