# How to get "x" value from a interpolating function?

Tags: functions, interpolation, coordinate

I measured a parameter over time and get this List: (where fisrt value (x) is time and second the value (y) the vale of the parameter)

```
j = List[{0, 0.205004}, {0.1, 0.259237}, {0.2, 1.059125}, {0.3, 0.832184},
         {0.4, 0.587992}, {0.5, 0.565537}, {0.6, 0.527323}];
```

I did Interpolation:

```
f = Interpolation[j, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"]
```

and got this Plot:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

I want to get the x value for a certain y point.

I tried:

```
f[0.4]
```

and

```
InverseFunction[f][0.4]
```

But it's giving me the opposite.

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me: `f[0.4]` gives `0.587992`. What is your `$Version`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistaked. I want to get x value for a certain y value.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

j = {{0, 0.205004}, {0.1, 0.259237}, {0.2, 1.059125}, {0.3, 0.832184}, 
     {0.4, 0.587992}, {0.5, 0.565537}, {0.6, 0.527323}};

f = Interpolation[j, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"];
```

The function range is

```
{fmin, fmax} = (#[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 0.6}, x] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue})

(* {-0.0275476, 1.08927} *)
```

The range of `x` for this function range is

```
{xmin, xmax} = (#[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 0.6}, x] & /@ {ArgMin, ArgMax})

(* {0.0424198, 0.219855} *)
```

To restrict the function such that its inverse is single-valued, require `xmin < x < xmax`

```
f2[x_?NumericQ] :=
 ConditionalExpression[f[x], xmin < x < xmax]
```

Plotting,

```
Plot[{f[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 0.6},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[0.75], {Red, Dashed}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   {StringForm[
     "``, multi-valued inverse",
     HoldForm[f[x]]],
    StringForm["``, single-valued inverse",
     HoldForm[f2[x]]]},
   {0.6, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

The inverse of `f2` is

```
g[y_?NumericQ] :=
 x /. FindRoot[f2[x] == y, {x, 0.15}]
```

Plotting the inverse function,

```
Legended[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{f[x], x}, {x, 0, 0.6},
   PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.75]],
  Plot[g[y], {y, fmin, fmax},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}],
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio,
  ImageSize -> 252],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[
   {Directive[ColorData[97][1], AbsoluteThickness[0.75]],
    Directive[Red, Dashed]}, {"multi-valued inverse",
    StringForm["``, single-valued inverse",
     HoldForm[g[y]]]}],
  {0.45, 0.39}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at your function:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 0.52}]
```

As you can see, for some y values there are several x values. This makes the inverse function multivalued. And MMA seems to take randomly one of several values as you can see:

```
Plot[InverseFunction[f][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Therefore, using InverseFunction is not a good idea.

Instead try e.g. FindInstance with restrictions on x like:

```
FindInstance[{f[x] == 0.4, 0 < x, x < 0.2}, x]
(* {{x -> 0.118044}} *)
```

Comment: `NSolve[{f[x] == 0.4 , 0 < x < 0.6}, x] ` should give all solutions ( but doesn't evaluate in MMA v12.2 )

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann I think NSolve uses inverse functions. See above.

Comment: @DanialHuber Might be, but `NSolve[{Sin[x] == .8, 0 < x < 6 Pi}, x]` for example works!?!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann "Sin" is not an a numerical interpolated function.

Comment: Understood, but InverseFunction  of `Sin` also isn't unique

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Daniel: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105036/4999 -- `InterpolatingFunction` gets special handling. (Also trigonometric functions get handled differently than polynomials, etc.). For `InterpolatingFunction`, `NSolve` calls `InverseFunction`, which calls `FindRoot`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for you helpful hint.