# Robust FindRoot search

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the following simulation that models a rocket landing (flat Earth, no atmosphere, constant gravitational acceleration), which uses root finding to figure out when to start and stop the engines from firing.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
g = 9.81; (*Gravitational acceleration*)
mprop = (409500)*0.15 ;(*15% of propellant mass left after MECO*)
mstruct = 22200; (*Structural mass*)
mtotal = mprop + mstruct;(*Total mass*)
T[n_] := 845000 n;(*Thrust from n engines*)
Isp = 282; (*Specific impulse*)
tmax = 1000;(*Maximum value for t*)

theta = Pi;(*Initial thrust angle in radians*) 

Solution = ParametricNDSolve[{
   x''[t] == If[t < tburn1end, T[3]/m[t] Cos[theta], If[tburn2start < t, -(T[1]/m[t]) Cos[gamma[t]], If[m[t] < mstruct, 0, 0]]],
   y''[t] == If[t < tburn1end, T[3]/m[t] Sin[theta], If[tburn2start < t, -(T[1]/m[t]) Sin[gamma[t]], If[m[t] < mstruct, 0, 0]]] - g, 
   m'[t] == If[t < tburn1end, -(T[3]/(g Isp)), If[tburn2start < t, -(T[1]/(g Isp)), If[m[t] < mstruct, 0, 0]]], gamma'[t] == D[ArcTan[x'[t], y'[t]], t],
   x[0] == 30000, y[0] == 90000, x'[0] == 1900 Cos[70 Degree], y'[0] == 1900 Sin[70 Degree], m[0] == mtotal, gamma[0] == 70 Degree},
  {x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t], x''[t], y''[t], m[t], gamma[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, {tburn1end, tburn2start}, 
  MaxSteps -> 1000000(*, Method\[Rule]"StiffnessSwitching"*)]

rootxy = FindRoot[{x[t][tburn1end, tburn2start] == 0, y[t][tburn1end, tburn2start] == 0, y'[t][tburn1end, tburn2start] == 0} /.Solution, {{t, 400}, {tburn1end, 25}, {tburn2start, 300}}]
tburn1end = rootxy[[2]][[2]]
tburn2start = rootxy[[3]][[2]]
tburn2end = rootxy[[1]][[2]]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t][tburn1end, tburn2start], y[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]} /. Solution], {t, 0, tburn2end}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {{-20000, 200000}, {-10000, 300000}}, PlotStyle -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Animate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t][tburn1end, tburn2start], y[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]} /. Solution], {t, 0, a}, AxesLabel -> {x, y},PlotRange -> {{-20000, 200000}, {-10000, 300000}}, PlotStyle -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large], {a, 0, tburn2end}, AnimationRate -> 5, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]

Plot[{x[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]} /. Solution, {t, 0, tburn2end},AxesLabel -> {t, x}] 
Plot[{y[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]} /. Solution, {t, 0, tburn2end},AxesLabel -> {t, y}] 
Plot[{x'[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]} /. Solution, {t, 0, tburn2end}, AxesLabel -> {t, vx}] 
Plot[{y'[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]} /. Solution, {t, 0, tburn2end}, AxesLabel -> {t, vy}]
```

However, I've noticed that FindRoot isn't very robust, and the guessed values have to be fairly close to the actual roots for a solution to be found. It would be great if I was able to set my search limits from `{t,0,tmax}` and use something like Brent's method which, as far as I know, is guaranteed to find a solution if it exists within the search bounds due to its use of the bisection method. But unfortunately Mathmatica says it only works with univariate functions. As such, I'm wondering if there is another way to be able to find the required engine start and stop times that is more reliable than what I'm currently doing. I've had a go at changing various settings in `ParametricNDSolve` and `FindRoot`, such as `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, but nothing has seemed to work so far. Any help would be great, thanks!

**EDIT:** In response to Michael E2, I tried using `NMinimize[]` instead of `FindRoot[]`, but my results were even worse. Here's the code I used in case I did something wrong which may have produced the bad results:

```
QuadraticMin[t0_?NumericQ, tburn1end_?NumericQ, tburn2start_?NumericQ] := Module[{tem = (x[t][tburn1end, tburn2start])^2 + (y[t][tburn1end,tburn2start])^2 + (y'[t][tburn1end, tburn2start])^2 /.Solution}, tem /. t -> t0];

Constraints[t0_?NumericQ, tburn1end_?NumericQ, tburn2start_?NumericQ] := Module[{tem = (y[t][tburn1end, tburn2start]) /. Solution}, tem /. t -> t0];

minimize = NMinimize[{QuadraticMin[t, tburn1end, tburn2start],Constraints[t, tburn1end, tburn2start] > 0, 0 < tburn1end < tmax, 0 < tburn2start < tmax, 0 < t < tmax}, {{t, 0, tmax}, {tburn1end, 0, tmax}, {tburn2start, 0, tmax}}]
```

The results were as follows:

```
{9.00056*10^9, {t -> 7.82522*10^-9, tburn1end -> 406.714, tburn2start -> 1.6873*10^-8}}
```

Comment: You might want to use `WhenEvent[]` instead to determine when your components become zero.

Comment: Also, take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range

Comment: @J.M. I'm a little confused as to how I'd use `WhenEvent[]` to find the values for the parameters `tburn1end` and `tburn2start` that will give me values of `x[t]  == 0 && y[t] == 0 && y'[t] == 0`. I thought `WhenEvent[]` was used to set values when certain events occur and could not be used to find parameters that produce desired results.

Comment: Have you tried `NMinimize[]` on $x^2+y^2+(y')^2$ (or perhaps `FindMinimum[]`)?

Comment: @MichaelE2, unfortunately `NMinimize[]` seems to fare even worse. What is the difference between `NMinimize[]` and `FindMinimum[]`?

Comment: `FindMinimum[]` searches for a single local minimum, somewhat like `FindRoot[]` searches for a single root. `NMinimize[]` attempts to find the global minimum. Each has several methods, some that use derivatives, some that don't.  You can constrain the search region or add a penalty function to the sum of squares outside the search region to force the minimum to be inside the search region.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I've posted the `NMinimize[]` code in the main post if you'd be kind enough to see if I am doing something incorrectly that is producing the bad results :)

Comment: Did you notice that `m[t]` can approach zero in this code, `m'[t] == If[t < tburn1end, -(T[3]/(g Isp)), If[tburn2start < t, -(T[1]/(g Isp)), If[m[t] < mstruct, 0, 0]]]`? Once `t` is big enough that `tburn2start < t`, `m[t]` will steadily decrease. That leads to a singularity if `tburn2start` is small and messes up `FindRoot` & `NMinimize`.

Comment: Yes, `m[t]` can go to zero since it is the mass of the rocket that changes as more fuel is used.