# Which root does FindRoot give?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I think that usually, `FindRoot` will give the root that's closest to the starting point. But see the example below, where I try to find the root of $\cos x=0$. If I started from $x=0.1$, then I get $10.9956$, but if I started from 1, I get $1.5708$. What's wrong?

[image: example]

Comment: Draw a graph of the function and its tangent at `x == 0.1`.  `FindRoot` is using Newton's method.

Comment: I believe its because `FindRoot[]` uses Newton's Method.  The tangent line hits further out.  In general, Newtons method requires a good initial guess or you "can" get a root quite far away.

Comment: FindRoot gives the root that it finds. :-)

Comment: To have more control over which root is obtained, give FindRoot two intial guesses, which prompts it to use the use secant method.  Then `FindRoot` usually returns the value of a root bracketed by the two guesses.  For instance, `FindRoot[Cos[x], {x, -1, 4}]`.

Answer (score 13):

When in doubt as to whether `FindRoot[]` is functioning as expected for a given nonlinear problem, one should try to use the diagnostic capabilities of the options `EvaluationMonitor` and `StepMonitor`. You've already been told in other answers as to why you should have expected your result, considering that you started the iteration with a seed that is uncomfortably near an extremum. Thus, let me demonstrate the use of `EvaluationMonitor`:

```
Reap[FindRoot[Cos[x], {x, 0.1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]
   {{x -> 10.9956}, {{0.1, 10.0666, 11.4045, 10.9711, 10.9956, 10.9956}}}
```

where we use `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` to get the values where `Cos[x]` was evaluated. We can also demonstrate the effect of damping, as shown by Michael:

```
Reap[FindRoot[Cos[x], {x, 0.1}, "DampingFactor" -> 1/5, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]
// Short
   {{x -> 1.5708}, {{0.1, 2.09333, 1.97814, <<76>>, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708}}}
```

where I have mercifully truncated the output, showing that damping gives better results at the cost of an increased number of iterations.

One could choose to use [Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent's_method) instead by specifying explicit brackets. The convergence is not as fast as Newton-Raphson, but it is certainly much safer:

```
Reap[FindRoot[Cos[x], {x, 1., 2.}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]
   {{x -> 1.5708}, {{1., 2., 1.5649, 1.57098, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708}}}
```

---

If, like me, you like pictures to help with diagnostics, there is a function called `FindRootPlot[]` (more information [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPlottingSearchData.html)) that can be used:

```
Needs["Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`"]
FindRootPlot[Cos[x], {x, 0.1}] // Last
```

[image: FindRootPlot[] result]

```
FindRootPlot[Cos[x], {x, 0.1}, "DampingFactor" -> 0.2] // Last
```

[image: FindRootPlot[] with "DampingFactor" result]

Answer (score 12):

Technically, `FindRoot` uses a damped Newton's method.
In an undamped Newton's method, the first step would look like this, the tangent striking the x-axis just above `10`:

```
Plot[{Cos[x], Cos[0.1] - Sin[0.1] (x - 0.1)}, {x, 0, 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can keep large steps from occurring by decreasing the `DampingFactor`:

```
FindRoot[Cos[x], {x, 0.1}, DampingFactor -> 0.2]
(*  {x -> 1.5708}  *)
```

The damping factor multiplies the change in `x`. The undamped step would be `x == 10.066644423259238`, so the damped first step is

```
0.1 + (10.066644423259238` - 0.1) 0.2
(*  2.09333  *)
```

That lands `x` close enough to the root nearest `0.1` that `FindRoot` will converge on it.

Of course, damping slows down convergence. In the following, it slows it down too much:

```
FindRoot[1/x - 1/1000, {x, 0.1}, DampingFactor -> 0.2]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

```
(*  {x -> 999.984}  *)
```

The regular method has no problem with it, though:

```
FindRoot[1/x - 1/1000, {x, 0.1}]
(*  {x -> 1000.}  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

To see what is happening, implement a quick Newton iteration algorithm. For instance:

```
NewtonsMethodList[f_, {x_, x0_}, n_] := 
 NestList[# - Function[x, f][#]/Derivative[1][Function[x, f]][#] &, 
  x0, n]
```

Now see what happens when we have 0.1 and 1 as starting values, and with, say, 5 iterations:

```
In[2]:= NewtonsMethodList[Cos[x], {x, 0.1}, 5]

Out[2]= {0.1, 10.0666, 11.4045, 10.9711, 10.9956, 10.9956}

In[5]:= NewtonsMethodList[Cos[x], {x, 1.}, 5]

Out[5]= {1., 1.64209, 1.57068, 1.5708, 1.5708, 1.5708}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This question has been asked in different context [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1).
As mentioned in the comments, `FindRoot` is based on Newton's method which works pretty well when a good guess is provided. But I think, it fails to provide you with multiple roots.
To find multiple roots, you can use `NDSolve`

```
f[x_] = Cos[x];
Module[{sol}, 
 Column[{sol = NSolve[{f[x] == 0, -10 <= x <= 10}, x], 
   Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]}, 
    ImageSize -> 360]}]]
```

[image]

I adopted this idea from [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1)'s answer to same sort of question.

Comment: The `NDSolve` Method you linked in your answer is very different from the code you posted (you used `NSolve`). Otherwise this is a good answer :)

Comment: @zhk: For one function your `Code` works fine. Have you used the same method for a system of non-linear equations? I have a NL equation system and I need to find Real solutions to the system, but so far no success. Can you show me how to use your `Code` for a system?