# Finding roots of a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

```
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
L = 4;
ζ = L/2;
K = 100*(Y*Iyy)/L^3;
a = (2*β^3*Sin[β*L]*Sinh[β*L]);

(*This is my main equation*)
eq1 = 
  (1 - K/(Y*Iyy) *
    ((Sin[β*(L - ζ)]*Sin[β*ζ]*Sinh[β*L] - Sinh[β*(L - ζ)]*Sinh[β*ζ]* Sin[β*L])*1/a));

P = FullSimplify[eq1];
T = P;,
Plot[T, {β, -10, 10}]

S = FindRoot[T == 0, {β, 3}] (* finding the root at 3*)
β /. % (* printing that value*)
```

I first plotted that equation and later, wherever it crosses the x-axis, in that neighborhood I  was trying to find the root. I used `FindRoot` command. This program is about finding the root of the equation `P`.

Comment: Paste your code not Image PLEASE!

Comment: Here its considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. This [question in Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-i-include-code-samples-in-posts) could be useful.

Comment: The code works and there's no question asked -- what do you want?  If you want a particular root, try bracketing it: `FindRoot[eq1 == 0, {\[Beta], 3, 3, 4}]`

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134106/which-root-does-findroot-give

Comment: But when I plot my equation I did not find  that function cross X axis

Comment: I get [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MDWtu.png), if I set the `PlotRange` to include `0` and raise the `PlotPoints` to over `1000`.

Comment: You can get an idea what `P` looks like with `Plot[Evaluate @ P, {β, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 1.2]`. It looks like it has many singularities and roots near -2 and 2. `FindRoot[P == 0, {β, 2}]` returns `{β -> 2.34143}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all roots in a given domain, you can use

```
NSolve[T == 0 && 0 < β < 10]
```

Clearing the trig. denominators with

```
NSolve[Expand[T*Cos[2 β] Sinh[4 β]] == 0 && 0 < β < 10]
```

is faster.

Even faster for this example is a direct search with `FindRoot`, bracketing the search domain to subintervals in a partition of the domain into intervals of length less than half the smallest period of the trig. functions:

```
Table[Check[FindRoot[T == 0, {β, n, n, n + 1}], Nothing], {n, 9}]
(* ignore errors *)
```

They all return

```
{{β -> 2.34143}, {β -> 3.92378}, {β -> 5.49661}, {β -> 7.06803}, {β -> 8.63908}}
```

Comment: You can use `Quiet[]` to suppress the printing of the `FindRoot` errors, but I feel on this educational forum that unless the question is about suppressing them, it is better for the users to see them and think about whether they are serious or can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, MichaelE2 (best answer) and also  m_goldberg.

Comment: @VijayKumarS It is a good practice to accept the most helpful answer, you know...