# Finding the roots of quintic equation

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I want to solve my quintic equation with methods Newton and Bisection , and compare them. And I want to know, how to call Nsolve or Roots and told them that they use only for example Bisection algorithm.

PM: I dont want to write these algorithms myself

Comment: "I want to know, how to call `NSolve` ... and tell them that they use only for example Bisection algorithm. I don't want to write these algorithms myself." - none of the built-ins use bisection, so you really will need to write it yourself. (OK, technically, the Brent algorithm used by `FindRoot[]` can take a bisection step, but it has a lot of other things going on.) OTOH, `FindRoot[]` can be made to use Newton's method, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158437) for example.

Comment: Search this site for "bisection method."  One almost never has to write things themselves these days, if one is resourceful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Newton

```
FindRoot[{x^5 - x + 1 == 0}, {x, 1}]
```

Then check the details with

```
Options@FindRoot
```

Check in the documentation the option Method in particular.

For the bisection method, NSolve may use it but it is a such a big machine that you will never know what it has done.  NSolve gives all the roots.  It knows it is a polynomial equation.  It has special methods for this.

```
NSolve[{x^5 - x + 1 == 0}, x]
```

If you would like to experiment with bisection, doing it yourself would be easier and more instructive than trying to know what NSolve is doing.