# The coefficients with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I try to compute the coefficients `b[i]` , $i=2,...,m$.
I got the following output:

```
m := 20; 
μ := 0.5
u[x_] := (12*μ^2)/25 + (6/25)*μ^2* Sech[(x*μ)/5]^2 - (12/25)*μ^2*Tanh[(x*μ)/5]; 

T[n_, x_] := 
  Sum[(-1)^i*2^(n - 2*i - 1)*((n*(n - i - 1)!)/(i!*(n - 2*i)!))*x^(n - 2*i), 
       {i, 0, Ceiling[n/2]}];

Table[b[n] = (2/Pi)*NIntegrate[(u[0.5*x + 0.5]*T[n, x])/Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
          {x, -1, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 12], {n, 2, m}]
```

Here the message that before the results.

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} =
>   {-0.99999999999999667104594803109799410885580269090806374709815354529}. NIntegrate obtained -0.0001047215230431864 and 7.698445916412437`*^-11
>   for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} =
>   {0.99999999999999667104594803109799410885580269090806374709815354529}.
>   NIntegrate obtained 2.330428756121359`*^-6 and 7.096561136045723`*^-11
>   for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} =
>   {-0.99999999999999667104594803109799410885580269090806374709815354529}. NIntegrate obtained 4.308639728030708`*^-8 and 7.540153824713211`*^-11
>   for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>

```
 {-0.00006666779216173972, 1.483597024240845*10^-6, 
 2.742965242872827*10^-8, -4.361781616250265*10^-10,
-9.55048318138621*10^-12, 1.324805938959673*10^-13, 
 3.053277276241757*10^-15, 
 6.813896661329826*10^-16, -2.257310336427579*10^-15,
-1.279952387436186*10^-15, 4.762549327712297*10^-15, 
 8.651550477286525*10^-15, 6.111965912879058*10^-14, 
 5.913733424919787*10^-14, -2.416647291094786*10^-13,
-5.98964708075444*10^-13, -5.167457130207156*10^-13, 
 8.120386801889474*10^-13, 3.653845513969105*10^-12}
```

Comment: By the way, the function `T` is already in *Mathematica* as `ChebyshevT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exact numbers, and adjust [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision) as well:

```
m = 20; 
\[Mu] = 1/2;
u[x_] := (12*\[Mu]^2)/25 + (6/25)*\[Mu]^2* Sech[(x*\[Mu])/5]^2 - (12/25)*\[Mu]^2*Tanh[(x*\[Mu])/5]; 

T[n_, x_] := Sum[(-1)^i*2^(n - 2*i - 1)*((n*(n - i - 1)!)/(i!*(n - 2*i)!))*x^(n - 2*i), 
   {i, 0, Ceiling[n/2]}];

Table[b[n] = (2/Pi)*NIntegrate[(u[1/2*x + 6/5]*T[n, x])/Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
      {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision->60, PrecisionGoal -> 12], {n, 2, m}]
```

> {-0.0000530269922322758700872406031298674120821932821983747589387163, 
>    1.75261542689904550105630367593488021854698740535599027651498*10^-6, 
>    2.03174943882974894986350353242628992979051384185133054522738*10^-8, \
>   -5.71381464509516823277911551847652467633881431176887724116102*10^-10, \
>   -6.37328149248641908321589282844941763150469420469053816298615*10^-12, 
>    1.87011744413795397954172376476016957818471258995457314173343*10^-13, 
>    1.75068011813384050090653986140979403776340305968235591804942*10^-15, \
>   -5.97686457967731296979103077829952153428513260249359486336513*10^-17, \
>   -4.26446546741900038202004327572870149796469823164759633901685*10^-19, 
>    1.85208901415995012427155570308574586021728606537005677375062*10^-20, 
>    8.94550465566852889943538290071348096418450173316421494793794*10^-23, \
>   -5.55865347380339884310848480886507901940568338741575442041513*10^-24, \
>   -1.42039361968678957657596810831771654198253211270604202264774*10^-26, 
>    1.61716665239712597324147883468714582375220102302954973310439*10^-27, 
>    5.12461112860934563767464690082079472604671608476673843091573*10^-31, \
>   -4.56568185693845647383269288596444770199336794356696282143777*10^-31, 
>    8.78178394761340122535830010605721994209448116711339777120330*10^-34, 
>    1.25183364269025093541820893853862105582025612063513904034290*10^-34, \
>   -5.29261315659887056938709191085499138650450119587992124610381*10^-37}

Comment: Thank you very much sir Carl Woll.

Answer (score 2):

The Chebyshev interpolation coefficients converge to the Chebyshev series coefficients `b[i]` quite rapidly, and the FFT is an efficient way to compute the interpolation coefficients.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92042/4999) by J.M. for more, or search the site for "Chebyshev Boyd" or "Chebfun", which is a MATLAB package for using Chebyshev approximations to solve a wide variety of numerical problems.

```
m = 20; μ = 1/2;
u[x_] := (12*μ^2)/25 + (6/25)*μ^2*Sech[(x*μ)/5]^2 - (12/25)*μ^2*Tanh[(x*μ)/5];

Clear[chebnodes, chebcoeffs];
chebnodes[n_] := chebnodes[n] = Sin[Pi/2*Range[-n, n, 2]/n];
chebcoeffs[f_, n_, wp_] := Module[{xx, cc},
   xx = N[chebnodes[n], wp];
   cc = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[f /@ xx, 1];
   cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
   cc
   ];

prec = 52;  (* this working precision yields a precision of 16+ in the b[i] *)
n = 2^Ceiling[Log2[2. m]];  (* the interpolation of order n >= 2m is sufficient *)
cc = chebcoeffs[u[1/2*# + 6/5] &, n, prec];
cc[[3 ;; m + 1]]   (* the array cc equals {b[0], b[1], ..., b[n]} *)
(*
{-0.00005302699223227587008724060312986741208219328219847, 
 -1.75261542689904550105630367593488021854698740536*10^-6, 
  2.031749438829748949863503532426289929790513832*10^-8, 
  5.7138146450951682327791155184765246763388143*10^-10, 
 -6.37328149248641908321589282844941763150480*10^-12, 
 -1.8701174441379539795417237647601695781848*10^-13, 
  1.75068011813384050090653986140979403765*10^-15, 
  5.976864579677312969791030778299521534*10^-17, 
 -4.2644654674190003820200432757287029*10^-19, 
 -1.852089014159950124271555703085746*10^-20, 
  8.945504655668528899435382900713*10^-23, 
  5.55865347380339884310848480887*10^-24, 
 -1.420393619686789576575968108*10^-26, 
 -1.61716665239712597324147883*10^-27,
  5.1246111286093456376746*10^-31,
  4.5656818569384564738327*10^-31, 
  8.7817839476134012254*10^-34,
 -1.2518336426902509354*10^-34, 
 -5.2926131565988706*10^-37}
*)
```

The loss of precision is really because the accuracy is roughly constant and the magnitude of the coefficients decreases:

```
Accuracy /@ cc // MinMax
(*  {53.2505, 53.8266}  *)
```

Comment: Wow, we sure are getting a lot of mileage out of Chebyshev... :D