# Plot of roots with sliders

Tags: plotting

Even though there is a good example of how to plot roots with slider
[example by Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80649/finding-roots-of-transcendental-equation-and-collecting-into-a-list)
,  I am still struggling in implementing a modified one for my purpose.  I have a very complicated polynomial (quartic) whose coefficients are represented with a long formulas made of coefficients (a,b,c,d). For sake of simplicity, I have the following code:

```
f=a-b*x^2+c*d*x^4
f1[x,a,b,c,d]:=f
solution= NSolve[f==0,x]
g[x,a,b,c,d]:=solution
```

I am struggling to understand how to include `a,b,c,d` coefficients for solution as sliders so that solution is plotted as red dots as shown by Hanlon.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Although there are no sliders, basically this should be instructive: [Factoring a two variable polynomial in a special way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/factoring-a-two-variable-polynomial-in-a-special-way/38607#38607)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := a - b*x^2 + c*d*x^4

Manipulate[
 roots = x /. NSolve[f[x, a, b, c, d] == 0, x];
 pts = Select[{#, 0} & /@ roots, Element[#[[1]], Reals] &]// Union;
 {xmin, xmax} = If[Length[pts] > 1,
   MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]], {-1, 1}];
 Column[{
   StringForm["roots = ``", roots],
   Plot[f[x, a, b, c, d], {x, xmin, xmax},
    Epilog -> If[Length[pts] > 0,
      {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]}, {}],
    ImageSize -> 500]}],
 Grid[{{Control[{{a, 0}, -5.0, 5.0, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{b, 1}, -5.0, 5.0, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{c, 1}, -5.0, 5.0, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{d, 1}, -5.0, 5.0, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  For versions prior to v10.1 when [`MinMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) was added, change the above definition of `{xmin, xmax}`to

```
{xmin, xmax} = 
 If[Length[pts] > 1, {Min[pts[[All, 1]]], Max[pts[[All, 1]]]}, {-1, 
   1}]
```

Comment: Min,Max are not the same shape error message

Comment: Is it possible to have NSolve for root outside Manipulate so that already calculated solution can be used inside Manipulate

Comment: @Aschoolar - To make use of the `Manipulate`'s parameters, the `NSolve` (or equivalent) must be inside the `Manipulate`. You could use `Show` inside the `Manipulate` to display an externally generated `Plot` along with the `Plot` inside.

Comment: @ Bob, Two error messages 1) Set::shape: {xmin,xmax} and MinMax{-1,0,0,1} are not the same shape.   2)  Plot::plln Limiting value in xmin {x, xmin, xmax} is not a machine-sized real number

Comment: I copied and pasted twice and verified each line....the same results....error occurs maybe because of different version of mathematica.  Mine is v9.  I have seen cases of different version collision.

Comment: As stated in the documentation for `MinMax`, it was introduced in version 10.1 Change the code to

`{xmin, xmax} = 
  If[Length[pts] > 1, {Min[pts[[All, 1]]], Max[pts[[All, 1]]]}, {-1, 1}];` This highlights why you should specify your version number if not using the current version.

Comment: It solves the problem...however when moving a slide...at some values usually less that 1 for parameter d I get run time warning message, that says Endpoints for x in {x, xmin, xmax} must have distinct machine precision numerical values....Should I use SetPrecision for x?

Comment: Duplicate roots result in `xmin` being the same as `xmax`, To avoid this change the definition of `pts` to `pts = Select[{#, 0} & /@ roots, Element[#[[1]], Reals] &] // Union;`