# Computing planet conjunctions with 2D circular orbits still hard?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, astronomy, periodic-function

All methods I've seen for computing planetary/stellar conjuctions 
(when two planets or a planet and a star appear close together in the 
sky because their angular separation, as measured from Earth, is 
small) are iterative: they look at the positions day by day and find 
the smallest angular separation.

EDIT (per comment): All of the constants (a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, c3) are known values. I'm trying to solve for t given these constants. There are, of course, an infinite number of solutions, so solutions for t in any given interval are fine too. Numerical solutions (where I plugin the constants as approximate numbers) are fine too, provided they are reasonably efficient (moreso than iterating).

I thought it would be easier with circular 2-dimensional orbits, so I 
tried this:

```
 
o[t_] = {Cos[t],Sin[t]} 
o1[t_] = a1*{Cos[a2*t+a3],Sin[a2*t+a3]} 
o2[t_] = b1*{Cos[b2*t+b3],Sin[b2*t+b3]}
```

The above are the circular 2-dimensional orbit of 3 planets, where one 
planet's orbit has been normalized to have radius 1, period 2*Pi, and 
o[0] = {1,0}.

Treating "o" as Earth, the position of "o1" as viewed from Earth at 
time t is "o1[t]-o[t]", and "o2[t]-o[t]" for "o2".

The angles from Earth are "Apply[ArcTan,o1[t]-o[t]]" and 
"Apply[ArcTan,o2[t]-o[t]]". The difference between these angles is:

```
 
Abs[Apply[ArcTan,o1[t]-o[t]]-Apply[ArcTan,o2[t]-o[t]]]
```

which is what I'm trying to minimize. In fact, because we're in 2 
dimensions, the minimum value will be 0, so I just need to find the 
zeros of the function above (of course, the Abs[] becomes superfluous 
at this point).

I've tried several approaches, and nothing worked. Solve[] won't solve 
the equation for Reals and hangs when I don't give it a domain.

I've tried using dot products, and even tried solving the simpler 
problem of when two planets appear perpendicular (dot product is 0), 
to no avail.

Graphing with actual vales show there's no real pattern to the zeros 
of my function, or even a minimum distance between zeros.

I could try an iterative solution of some sort, but then I'm back to 
square one.

Comment: Do you want a solution in terms of the `a` and `b` variables, or is a numerical solution (for particular choices of the `a`s and `b`'s all right?

Comment: Thanks! Edited the question to reflect I'm looking for solutions in t given the constants, and that efficient numerical solutions are fine too.

Comment: I won't have time to look at this until later. In the meantime, look up NSolve and FindRoot, and probably someone else will post an answer.

Comment: As suggested by @march, `FindRoot` certainly works.  For instance, with `{a1 = 3.6, a2 = 1.3, a3 = 1.6, b1 = .9, b2 = 2.1, b3 = 2.6}`, FindRoot[Apply[ArcTan, o1[t] - o[t]] == Apply[ArcTan, o2[t] - o[t]], {t, 0}]` yields `{t -> 7.09798}`.  `NSolve` and `Reduce`, on the other hand, appear not to work here.

Comment: Finding multiple roots is discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding zeroes of the function

```
Apply[ArcTan, o1[t] - o[t]] - Apply[ArcTan, o2[t] - o[t]]
```

does not work well, because `ArcTan` changes discontinuously from `-Pi` to `Pi`, creating numerous spurious roots.  For instance, with

```
{a1 = 2, a2 = 13/10, a3 = 16/10, b1 = 3, b2 = 21/10, b3 = 26/10};
Plot[Apply[ArcTan, o1[t] - o[t]] - Apply[ArcTan, o2[t] - o[t]], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

A better choice is to equate slopes, even though this function does not distinguish between planets on the same side and on opposite sides of the reference planet.

```
Plot[First[o1[t] - o[t]] Last[o2[t] - o[t]] - First[o2[t] - o[t]] Last[o1[t] - o[t]], 
    {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

We now apply [`FindAllCrossings`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations)

```
FindAllCrossings[First[o1[t] - o[t]] Last[o2[t] - o[t]] - 
    First[o2[t] - o[t]] Last[o1[t] - o[t]], {t, 0, 20}]
(* {3.09583, 6.54554, 9.66901, 14.3135, 19.458} *)
```

and retain only those solutions for which the planets are on the same side of the reference planet.

```
Cases[%, t_ /; First[o1[t] - o[t]] First[o2[t] - o[t]] > 0]
(* {6.54554, 14.3135} *)
```

For completeness, alignment can be tested visually from

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Arrow[{o[t], o1[t]}], Arrow[{o[t], o2[t]}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], {{t, 1}, 0, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The first alignment occurs at about `t == 6.55`.

[image]

**Simpler approach**

Although `NSolve` cannot handle the function involving `ArcTan` introduced in the Question, it can handle the simpler expression introduced above in this Answer.

```
NSolve[First[o1[t] - o[t]] Last[o2[t] - o[t]] - First[o2[t] - o[t]] 
   Last[o1[t] - o[t]] == 0 && First[o1[t] - o[t]] First[o2[t] - o[t]] > 0 && 0 < t < 20, t]
(* {{t -> 6.54554}, {t -> 14.3135}} *)
```

`Reduce` also works.

```
N@Reduce[First[o1[t] - o[t]] Last[o2[t] - o[t]] - First[o2[t] - o[t]] 
   Last[o1[t] - o[t]] == 0 && First[o1[t] - o[t]] First[o2[t] - o[t]] > 0 && 0 < t < 20, t]
(* t == 6.54554 || t == 14.3135 *)
```

Comment: Took me a second to figure out "A better choice is to equate slopes". The slope of a vector (vx,vy) is vy/vx so equating vy/vx=uy/ux for two vectors yields `vy*ux = uy*vx`, or `vy*ux-uy*vx==0`