# Numerical integration with special function over the positve half line

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

Is there a way to compute the following integral numerically?,

$\int_0^{\infty}\left(-\frac{2 x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \, _1F_3\left(\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{x^4}{256}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}+x^2 \, _1F_3\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{x^4}{256}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)dx$
[image: plot]

I know that $-\frac{2 x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \, _1F_3\left(\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{x^4}{256}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}+x^2 \, _1F_3\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{x^4}{256}\right) \rightarrow -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty.$

Mathematica file is [here](http://uocmath.wikispaces.com/file/view/ma_file.nb/615770393/ma_file.nb).

Comment: Mathematica file is here http://uocmath.wikispaces.com/file/view/ma_file.nb/615770393/ma_file.nb
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Please post your actual Mathematica code, not an image of it. Without real code no one will be able to work with it to see what you might have done wrong, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: @m_goldberg: The nb file with the code  is available through the link http://uocmath.wikispaces.com/file/view/ma_file.nb/615770393/ma_file.nb
     under the question.

Comment: For reference, the integrand can be expressed in terms of the $G$ function: `2 Sqrt[π] - 2 MeijerG[{{1/2, 3/4}, {1/4, 1}}, {{0}, {}}, 4/x, 1/4]`

Answer (score 1):

The integral over the half-oscillations between roots of the integrand seems to be decreasing rapidly, so one can estimate the whole integral as an alternating sum:

```
(* Integrand from @user64494 *)
g = x^2*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, x^4/256] - 
   2*Gamma[1/4]/(Sqrt[Pi])*x*
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4}, {1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, x^4/256] + 
   Sqrt[2/π] Gamma[1/4] Gamma[3/4];

(* Find roots of the integrand *)
(roots = With[{f = g}, 
     Reap@NDSolve[{t'[x] == 1, t[0] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[f == 0, Sow[x]]}, {}, {x, 0, 200}, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 7, WorkingPrecision -> 500, 
       MaxStepSize -> 1/2]][[2, 1]];
 roots2 = FindRoot[g, {x, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 500] & /@ roots;
) // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {64.5725, Null}  *)

(* terms to sum 0..Infinity *)
ClearAll[term];
mem : term[i_?NumberQ] := 
  mem = Module[{iRes}, 
    Check[iRes = 
      NIntegrate[g, {x, x /. roots2[[i]], x /. roots2[[1 + i]]}, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 100 + 2 i, 
       Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 15}], 
     Print["i = ", i]];
    iRes];
term[0] = NIntegrate[g, {x, 0, x /. roots2[[1]]}, PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 200, 
   Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 15}];

NSum[term[Round@i], {i, 0, ∞}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns",
   "VerifyConvergence" -> False, WorkingPrecision -> 100] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {61.4593, 
   -9.41471026473132271164542801174142339911608047122339101*10^-58}
*)
```

Checking the last term calculated by `NSum` gives an upper bound on the error, assuming the terms continue to be alternating and monotonically decreasing:

```
DownValues[term][[-2]]
(*  HoldPattern[term[131]] :> -1.76932...88*10^-104  *)
```

Comment: If you use `PrecisionGoal -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 150 + 3 i`, then the integral decreases to `~10^-81`, so the errors in the terms computed by `NIntegrate` in this answer dominate the result.  All it shows is that the integral is probably very small.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of summing an alternating series, for which `NIntegrate` seems to have trouble doing accurately enough, we can integrate out to a finite value.  The integrand seems to be oscillating and decreasing rapidly, so the error of trunction will be less than the area between the next hump in its graph and the `x` axis.  It turns out that as I pushed the interval of integration further and further, the value of the integral would decrease and always be around the error estimate.  It makes me think the integral might actually be zero.  If so, one would rather want a proof than an approximation.

We can use the Fourier DCT to approximate the Chebyshev series of `g` (see [this answer by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89692/4999)).  The series is easily integrated. The biggest trouble is evaluating the function accurately.  I used `N[g /. x -> exactValue, precision]` to hopefully ensure that accurately values of `g` are computed.

```
(* Integrand from @user64494 *)
g = x^2*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, x^4/256] - 
   2*Gamma[1/4]/(Sqrt[Pi])*x*
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4}, {1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, x^4/256] + 
   Sqrt[2/π] Gamma[1/4] Gamma[3/4];

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
  nn = 1024;
  xmax = 220;
  gvals = N[g /. x -> #, 150] & /@
    Rescale[Sin[Pi/2*Range[nn, -nn, -2]/nn], {-1, 1}, {0, xmax}];
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {45.0455, Null}  *)

(* approximate Chebyshev series *)
cc = foo = Sqrt[2/nn] FourierDCT[gvals, 1];
cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
cc = Drop[cc, -LengthWhile[Reverse@cc, Precision[#] < 2 &]];
Length@cc
(*  610  *)

(* Integrate a Chebyshev series over its complete domain *)
i0Cheb[c_, {a_, b_}] := Total[(b - a)/(1 - Range[0, Length@c - 1, 2]^2) c[[1 ;; ;; 2]]];
i0Cheb[cc, {0, xmax}]
(*  -1.508526852*10^-138  *)
```

Notes: (1) `N[g /. x -> 220, 150]` needs a `$MaxExtraPrecision` of at least `400` and takes nearly a second to evaluate on my machine.  The integrand is numerically very hard to evaluate. For `N[g /. x -> 1000, 150]`, we need  a `$MaxExtraPrecision` of at least `3079` and nearly 7 seconds.  `NIntegrate` is going to take a long time, as will any accurate method. (2) The precision `150` allows the integral to be computed up to about 150 decimal places after the decimal point, since `Max@Abs@cc` is about `0.196`. The answer shows 147 decimal places of [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
g = x^2*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, x^4/256] -  
2*Gamma[1/4]/(Sqrt[Pi])*x*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4}, {1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, x^4/256] + 
Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Gamma[1/4] Gamma[3/4];
NIntegrate[g, {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", 
 AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

> 2.53237432183970183831603063456*10^-11

Comment: Interestingly, the terms you have written out exactly cancel.  Try, eg. `N[31 Sqrt[2/3]/9 - 31 Gamma[1/4] Gamma[3/4]/(9 Sqrt[3] \[Pi]), 10]`.

Comment: (and `FullSimplify[(2 2^(5/6))/Sqrt[3] == (2 2^(1/3) Gamma[1/4] Gamma[3/4])/(Sqrt[3] \[Pi])]` )

Comment: @evanb: Thank you for your valuable comment. I changed my mind and edited my answer. The plot produced with WorkingPrecision ->15 is  exacter.

Comment: The `AccuracyGoal -> 10` indicates that `NIntegrate` should accept a result with an error estimate of `10^-10` or less, which is greater than the result returned in this case.  Playing with your option settings, I can get positive and negative values down to `10^-35`.  The integral might be zero.