# Points of Intersection of Cosh(x) and Sec(x)

Tags: equation-solving

How can I find the points of intersection of cosh(x) and sec(x)?

Plotting the two, I can see that it has a root around 4.7, but then I can't tell where the next root is.

But when I use `FindRoot` with a guess of 4.7 I don't get the root but if I use a guess between 4.72 and 4.8 then I find the root - 4.730040744862704.

Also, another root - 7.8532046241 can be found by guessing between 7.83 and 7.85.

Q: Is there a better way to solve the equation: `Cosh[x]==Sec[x]`?
Q: How do I see the other points of intersection of the graphs `y=Cosh[x]` and `y=Sec[x]`?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI `FindRoot` uses newtons method when you give it a single point and the secant method when you supply 2. The derivative of your function is very large near the root so newtons method shoots off far away from your guess on the first iteration.

Comment: Q: How do I see the other points of intersection of the graphs y=Cosh[x] and y=Sec[x]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Solve` or `Reduce` if you add a domain restriction:

```
N @ Solve[Cosh[x] == Sec[x] && -10<x<10, x]
N @ Reduce[Cosh[x] == Sec[x] && -10<x<10, x]
```

> {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 
>      0.}, {x -> -7.8532}, {x -> -4.73004}, {x -> 4.73004}, {x -> 7.8532}}
>
> x == -7.8532 || x == -4.73004 || x == 0. || x == 4.73004 || x == 7.8532

*(using NSolve directly seems to miss roots)*

Comment: Solving `N@Solve[Cosh[x]*Cos[x] - 1 == 0 && -10 < x < 10, x]` is 20 times faster, presumably because it removes the singularity.

Comment: Q: How do I see the other points of intersection of the graphs y=Cosh[x] and y=Sec[x]?

Answer (score 0):

From: [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
Clear[findRoots]
Options[findRoots] = Options[Reduce];
findRoots[gl_Equal, {x_, von_, bis_}, 
prec : (_Integer?Positive | MachinePrecision | Infinity) : 
MachinePrecision, wrap_: Identity, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{work, glp, vonp, 
bisp}, {glp, vonp, bisp} = {gl, von, bis} /. 
r_Real :> SetPrecision[r, prec];
work = wrap@Reduce[{glp, vonp <= x <= bisp}, opts];
work = {ToRules[work]};
If[prec === Infinity, work, N[work, prec]]];
```

A domain restriction is `-10 < x < 10`

```
findRoots[Cosh[x] == Sec[x], {x, -10, 10}]

(* {{x -> -7.8532}, {x -> -4.73004}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 4.73004}, {x -> 7.8532}} *)
```

**Or:**

```
findRoots[Cosh[x]*Cos[x] == 1, {x, -10, 10}](* 33 times faster *)

(* {{x -> -7.8532}, {x -> -4.73004}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 4.73004}, {x -> 7.8532}}*)
```