# Problem with NSolve Speed

Tags: equation-solving

I have a very complicated function but only of 1 variable. I want to find the first value for which that function is zero. Mathematica can easily plot it:

```
func = Det[coeffMatrix];
Plot[func, {\[Beta]1, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

From that plot, one can easily see that the first value would be ~2.556.

To show that $\beta_1$ = 2.556 is actually the approximate solution:

```
func /. \[Beta]1 -> 2.556
```

> -0.00139597

However, when I try to find it numerically:

```
NSolve[func == 0 && 0 < \[Beta]1 < 10, \[Beta]1]
```

...it just runs and runs and runs and never gives an answer. Why ? and how can I fix it ?

**The complete code**

```
constants = {b1 -> (-(Cosh[
          0.68*\[Beta]1]*(0.6553600000000004*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*
            Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1] - 
           0.6553600000000004*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*
            Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
           1.2621440000000002*Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
           0.7378559999999998*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1]*
            Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1])) + 
      Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*(-0.7378559999999998*Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1] - 
         1.2621440000000002*Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1])*
       Sinh[0.68*\[Beta]1])/(Cosh[
        0.68*\[Beta]1]*(-0.6553600000000004*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*
          Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
         1.2621440000000002*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
         0.7378559999999998*Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1] - 
         0.6553600000000004*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1]) + 
      Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*(0.7378559999999998*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
         1.2621440000000002*Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1])*Sinh[0.68*\[Beta]1]),
   b2 -> (2.5*
      Sec[0.68*\[Beta]1]*(Cosh[
          0.68*\[Beta]1]*(-0.26214400000000015 + 
           0.26214400000000015*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*
            Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1] - 
           Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1]) + 
        0.8*(Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1] - 
           Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1])*
         Sinh[0.68*\[Beta]1]))/((0.7378559999999998*
          Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
         1.2621440000000002*Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1])*Sinh[0.68*\[Beta]1] +
       Cosh[0.68*\[Beta]1]*(-0.6553600000000004*Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1] - 
         0.6553600000000004*Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
         1.2621440000000002*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Tan[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
         0.7378559999999998*Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Tan[0.68*\[Beta]1])), 
  d2 -> (2.5*
      Sech[0.68*\[Beta]1]*(-0.26214400000000015*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
        0.8*Cosh[
          0.15*\[Beta]1]*(0.3276800000000002*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*
            Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
           Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1]*
            Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1]) + (Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*
            Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1] - 
           0.8*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1])*
         Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1]))/(-0.6553600000000004*
       Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
      1.2621440000000002*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1] - 
      0.6553600000000004*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*Sinh[0.15*\[Beta]1] + 
      0.7378559999999998*Cos[0.15*\[Beta]1]*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*
       Tanh[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
      Cosh[0.15*\[Beta]1]*(0.7378559999999998*Sin[0.68*\[Beta]1] + 
         1.2621440000000002*Cos[0.68*\[Beta]1]*Tanh[0.68*\[Beta]1]))}

matrix = {{a1 (Sin[u \[Beta]1] - Sinh[u \[Beta]1]), 
    b1 (Cos[u \[Beta]1] - Cosh[u \[Beta]1]), -b2*
     Cos[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1], -d2*
     Cosh[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1]}, {a1 (Cos[u \[Beta]1] - 
       Cosh[u \[Beta]1]), b1 (-Sin[u \[Beta]1] - Sinh[u \[Beta]1]), 
    b2*\[Theta]*Sin[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1], -d2*\[Theta]*
     Sinh[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1]}, {a1 (-Sin[u \[Beta]1] - 
       Sinh[u \[Beta]1]), b1 (-Cos[u \[Beta]1] - Cosh[u \[Beta]1]), 
    b2*\[Alpha]^4*\[Theta]^2*
     Cos[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1], -d2*\[Alpha]^4*\[Theta]^2*
     Cosh[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1]}, {a1 (-Cos[u \[Beta]1] - 
       Cosh[u \[Beta]1]), 
    b1 (Sin[u \[Beta]1] - 
       Sinh[u \[Beta]1]), -b2*\[Alpha]^4*\[Theta]^3*
     Sin[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1], -d2*\[Alpha]^4*\[Theta]^3*
     Sinh[y*\[Theta]*\[Beta]1]}};

testingParam = { \[Theta] -> 0.8, \[Alpha] -> 0.8, u -> 0.15, 
   y -> 1 - 0.15} ;

coeffMatrix = (matrix /. a1 -> 1) /. constants /. testingParam ;

func = Det[coeffMatrix];
NSolve[func == 0 && 0 < \[Beta]1 < 10, \[Beta]1]
```

Comment: Since you can use `Plot[]` on your function, use the `MeshFunctions` option, like what was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5666).

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thank you for your comment and suggestion. However, I am not such an advanced user. Would you mind to post an answer of how to use the MeshFunctions ? I did not quite understand it from the example following your link. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/5666#5666)

```
f[\[Beta]1_] = Det[coeffMatrix];
zeros = Reap[
   NDSolve[{y'[x] == D[f[x], x], WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Sow[{x, y[x]}]],
      y[1] == f[1]}, {}, {x, 3, 0.01}]][[-1, 1]]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[zeros]}]
```

> {{2.61534, -5.0246*10^-18}}

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to work. I still need to understand it though...

Answer (score 3):

```
FindRoot[func == 0, {\[Beta]1, 2.566}]
{\[Beta]1 -> 2.61535}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you always need an initial guess ?

Comment: When there are many roots, it is advisable to specify the one that you want to get. Otherwise there may be other roots.

Comment: I see, but most of the times I just know that I want to get the first root, but I don't know where it is...

Comment: In this case, this is not the first root, but the second.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant the first non-zero root.

Comment: Do you mean that the function is always looks like you described above, but different parameters?