# How to solve this equation numerically or analytically

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

In the paper, entitled:

> A Closed Form Solution for the Pull-in Voltage of the Micro Bridge

(Link to PDF: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d31/33707b1243f6b4e3344c4fa19b831b010b8b.pdf)

... the following equation appears:

[image]

I really don't know how to solve this for $\eta_{PI}$, even if all constants are known... do you have any idea ?

EDIT:
Mathematica Input: ($n_{PI}$ was replaced with a simple $n$)

The nominator:

```
nom = Integrate[
  b*\[Phi][x]/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^2 + 
   0.265*b^0.25*\[Phi][x]/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^1.25 + 
   0.53*h^0.5*\[Phi][x]/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^1.5, {x, 0, L}]
```

The denominator:

```
denom = Integrate[
  2*b*(\[Phi][x])^2/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^3 + 
   0.33125*b^0.25*(\[Phi][x])^2/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^2.25 + 
   0.795*h^0.5*(\[Phi][x])^2/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^2.5, {x, 0, L}]
```

A typical $ \phi (x)$ function:

```
\[Phi][x] := a*Sin[x] + b*Cos[x] + c*Sinh[x] + d*Cosh[x]
```

Some arbitrary constants for numeric solutions to test:

```
constants = {a->2,b->4,c->7,d->10,g->3,h->2,L->5}
```

**For easier copy-paste:**

```
Clear[\[Phi]]
nom = Integrate[
  b*\[Phi][x]/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^2 + 
   0.265*b^0.25*\[Phi][x]/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^1.25 + 
   0.53*h^0.5*\[Phi][x]/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^1.5, {x, 0, L}]

denom = Integrate[
  2*b*(\[Phi][x])^2/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^3 + 
   0.33125*b^0.25*(\[Phi][x])^2/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^2.25 + 
   0.795*h^0.5*(\[Phi][x])^2/(g - n*\[Phi][x])^2.5, {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: The first thing you could do is to translate the image into Mathematica code. Otherwise, chances are nobody will bother to do it for you, and you won't get any answers.

Comment: Presumably, some of the terms in the integrand have an implicit dependence on `x`.  You will have to work out what this is and make it explicit.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you for your comment. Please have a look at my update.

Comment: @mikado Thank you for your comment. I added a typical function to my question. Please have a look at the update.

Comment: `constants = {b->4,b->1}` ?,decide.  `b` constant is in meters or micrometers ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Sorry. My mistake. I fixed it ! For now, any unit. In the end it will be micrometers.

Comment: From paper `ϕ[x]` is :`ϕ[x] == (Cosh[λ x] - 
    Cos[λ x]) - (Cosh[λ L] - 
     Cos[λ L])/(Sinh[λ L] - 
     Sin[λ L])*(Sinh[λ x] - Sin[λ x]) ` then:  `λ` is ? or from eq (3) ?. Solving eq(3) for `λ` then: `λ =0` ,and then `ϕ[x]=0` ?

Comment: I am mildly amused at the loose use of "closed form" in the paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = 50*10^-6;
g = 3*10^-6;
h = 2*10^-6;
L = 250*10^-6;
λ = 10; (* λ = ? .You may change. *)

ϕ[x_?NumericQ] := (Cosh[λ x] - Cos[λ x]) - (Cosh[λ L] - Cos[λ L])/(Sinh[λ L] - Sin[λ L])*(Sinh[λ x] - Sin[λ x])

nom[n_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(b ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2 + 53/100*( h^(1/2) ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^(3/2) + 
53/200*( b^(1/4) ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^(5/4), {x, 0, L}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

denom[n_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(2 b ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^3 + 159/200*( h^(1/2) ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^(5/2) + 
53/160*( b^(1/4) ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^(9/4), {x, 0, L}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

Solve for n:

```
FindRoot[n - nom[n]/denom[n] == 0, {n, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxIterations -> 1000]

(* {n -> 1.2897501610140538697} *)
```

Comment: Wow ! This is great! Thank you so much !! What doe  x_?Numeric do and why do you use it ?

Comment: @james .It's defintion of a function that only evaluates when its argument is numeric. More in Documentation, exectute: `?NumericQ`.

Comment: @james Here's a site reference for `NumericQ`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the link to the documentation.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you for the explanation !

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk How do you set the initial point (here n=2) ? What criteria do you use ? It could be anything, right ? I tried with n=100 and it failed.

Comment: At the beginning it is some random value. I don't know where is root.I do a plot `ListLinePlot[Table[{n, n - nom[n]/denom[n]}, {n, 0, 3, 1}]]` and see where is a root.The starting  initial point should be as close  to the root. Read documentation  of `FindRoot` it's all there or on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com,  putt on search `Find Root` an see question about it.

Comment: Try: `FindRoot[n - nom[n]/denom[n] == 0, {n, -10000}, 
 Method -> {"Newton", "UpdateJacobian" -> 3}]` or `FindRoot[n - nom[n]/denom[n] == 0, {n, -10000, 1}, Method -> "Secant"]` 
no longer complains .

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you very much for your detailed answer and your suggestion. Very helpful ! Thanks !

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I also like to use this function, it seems very robust to find roots: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183236/problem-with-nsolve-speed/183240?noredirect=1#comment478213_183240

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I am trying to calculate nPI for a piece wise defined function... I cannot find my error. I posted a question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183381/help-for-solving-complicated-function