# Finding all roots to equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm currently doing some Mathematica exercises, and I'm stuck on this one task where you're supposed to plot the functions h(t)= |3-t^2|+|t-1|-t^2 ,  g(t)=3sin(t)
in the same grap, and then find all the roots. This is what I've got so far:

[image]

The instructions say that I should use FindRoot to exactly decide all the roots, but I don't think I've done it right. What should I change with the function in order to make it find **all** of the roots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Solve[{Abs[3 - t^2] + Abs[t - 1] - t^2 == 3*Sin[t], -5 <= t <= 5}, t]` works for me in V11.3, but not `NSolve` for some reason.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I would guess that `NSolve` uses a derivative and cannot handle `Abs`. Since the values are real, a workaround is `NSolve[{Abs[3 - t^2] + Abs[t - 1] - t^2 == 3*Sin[t] /. 
   Abs[z_] :> Sqrt[z^2], -5 <= t <= 5}, t]`

Comment: @BobHanlon You can see in the comments to @zhk's answer below that `NSolve` works in earlier versions of *Mma*. While there's some plausibility in your suggestion, it stills seems a backslide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `NSolve` to find multiple roots,

```
NSolve[{Abs[3 - t^2] + Abs[t - 1] - t^2 == 3*Sin[t], -5 <= t <= 5}, t]
```

> {{t -> -4.92954}, {t -> -3.77452}, {t -> 0.762901}, {t -> 3.35745}}

or `FindAllCrossings` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/5666#5666),

```
FindAllCrossings[Abs[3 - t^2] + Abs[t - 1] - t^2 == 3*Sin[t], {t, -10, 10}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> {-4.9295434376879868373, -3.7745180124835511931, 0.76290087955924483126, 3.3574487606850113852}

or `FindRoot` providing good initial guesses,

```
FindRoot[{Abs[3 - t^2] + Abs[t - 1] - t^2 == 3*Sin[t]}, {t, #}] & /@ {-5, -3, 1, 4}
```

> {{t -> -4.92954}, {t -> -3.77452}, {t -> 0.762901}, {t -> 3.35745}}

Comment: When i try NSolve i get nothing back as output? Also, the FindAllCrossings isn't working either.

Comment: @wznd You should input the interval of interest.

Comment: @wznd. For me `NSolve` and `FindAllCrossings` works fine,I checked on Mathematica `10.2` and `11.3`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk `NSolve` does not work for me in 11.3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sAq7R.png

Comment: @MichaelE2. With little modification works on MMA `11.3`: `NSolve[{RealAbs[3 - t^2] + RealAbs[t - 1] - t^2 == 3*Sin[t], -5 <= 
   t <= 5}, t]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Also if you use `PiecewiseExpand[eqn, t \[Element] Reals]`, but I'm curious which version gives @zhk's result.  Is it 10.2 for you?

Comment: @MichaelE2 "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)"