# Is there any alternative for NSolve or Solve to obtain all the roots of the given function?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerics, numerical-value

I have this function for reals $0<x<\pi$.
$$f(x)=(3 \pi -2 x)^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 \pi  (\pi -x) \csc \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{\pi -x}\right)}{4 x^2-8 \pi  x+5 \pi ^2}\right)-\frac{\pi  x}{\pi -x}+\pi \right)\right)\\-(\pi -2 x)^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\csc ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 \pi  (\pi -x) \csc \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{\pi -x}\right)}{4 x^2-8 \pi  x+5 \pi ^2}\right)+\frac{\pi ^2}{\pi -x}\right)\right)$$

I try  `NSolve` to obtain all the roots of the function over the domain, but, it seems that Mathematica needs much time to produce all the roots.

Is there any alternative for  `NSolve` or  `Solve` to obtain all the roots? Any comments are appreciated.

```
f = -(\[Pi] - 2 x)^2 Sin[ 1/2 (\[Pi]^2/(\[Pi] - x) +   ArcCsc[(4 \[Pi] (\[Pi] - x) Csc[\[Pi]^2/(\[Pi] - x)])/( 5 \[Pi]^2 - 8 \[Pi] x + 4 x^2)])] + (3 \[Pi] - 2 x)^2 Sin[ 1/2 (\[Pi] - (\[Pi] x)/(\[Pi] - x) +  ArcCsc[(4 \[Pi] (\[Pi] - x) Csc[\[Pi]^2/(\[Pi] - x)])/( 5 \[Pi]^2 - 8 \[Pi] x + 4x^2)])];

x/.NSolve[f==0 &&  0<x<\[Pi]]
```

Comment: `Is there any alternative for  NSolve or  Solve to obtain all the roots?` You can look at these:  [find-all-roots-in-range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63663/find-all-roots-in-range) and [finding-all-roots-to-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187605/finding-all-roots-to-equation) and [find-all-roots-in-the-interval-of-nonlinear-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51115/find-all-roots-in-the-interval-of-nonlinear-equation)

Comment: ... and [how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range) and [about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations)

Comment: Have you tried Reduce?

Comment: @bills It says "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce."

Answer (score 1):

Plotting `f` suggests that it has very many, if not an infinite number of zeros.

```
Plot[f, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 10000, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, "f"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f, {x, 3, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100000, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, "f"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

So, it is unlikely that all can be found, even with the powerful methods cited by Nasser.  Some can be found with `NSolve`, however.

```
NSolveValues[f == 0 && 0 < x < Pi, x, Reals]
(* {1.5708, 1.5708, 2.35619, 2.61799, 2.74889, 2.82743, 2.87979, 
    2.91719, 3.10132, 3.11079, 3.12922, 3.13224, 3.14024} *)

NSolveValues[f == 0 && 3 < x < Pi, x, Reals]
(* {3.13105, 3.13267, 3.13291, 3.13306, 3.13473, 3.13485, 3.13515, 
    3.13648, 3.13735, 3.13767, 3.13816, 3.1397, 3.14003, 3.14034, 3.1412, 
    3.14142, 3.14148} *)
```

Be sure to specify that only `Real` roots are sought to speed the computation.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it can be easily checked that all the roots these methods give are rational multiples of $\pi$.  `x={1/2, 3/4, 5/6, 7/8, 9/10, 11/12, 13/14, 15/16, 17/18, 19/20, 21/
  22} \[Pi]` , on the other hand, if you check the function at these values, you see that the function is not defined at all at these values since at these values, the argument of $\csc \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{\pi -x}\right)$ will be integer multiples of $\pi$.    @bbgodfrey

Comment: So, does this mean that Mathematica is providing the roots that the function is not defined at those values? These points are also visible in the plots.      @bbgodfrey

Comment: @math2021  `NSolve` is seeking values of `x` for which `f` is approximately, not exactly, equal to zero.  Incidentally, `Simplify[f /. x -> (2 n - 1) Pi/(2 n), n > 1 && n \[Element] Integers]` spits out several error messages but finally yields `0`.  Probably, when it encounters an error, it tries a different order of simplification.