# Trying to extract the first four roots of an transcendental equation, but could not able to decide which are the first four roots

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the roots of the transcendental equation, for that, I have used  NSolve  function, but when I search for roots of b between 0 to 20, it will produce empty list, If I change the search range to 0 to 10 instead of 0 to 20, I am getting some roots. I am interested in finding the first four roots of the transcendental equation P. How to achieve this?  I have plotted my transcendental functions it seems there are so many roots, now I don't know which is my first root.  I am interested in extracting first four roots.

```
  P = -4 b^7 (2 K1 Cosh[b L] Sin[b L] Sinh[b z1]^2 + 
         Sinh[b L] (-K1 Cos[b L] + K1 Cos[b (L - 2 z1)] + 4 b^3 Sin[b L] -
             K1 Sin[b L] Sinh[2 b z1]));
    K1 = 1*^12;
    z1 = 1/3;
    L = 1;
    Plot[P, {b, 0, 20}]
    NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < b < 20]
```

Comment: `when I search for roots of b between 0 to 20, it will produce empty list` it works OK for me, using V12. screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQCE.png) if you are not using V12, try to upgrade. May be this is something version dependent.

Comment: you screen shot is not visible, it is too small

Comment: Works fine in versions 11.2, 11.3 and 12.0. I can read Nasser's screenshot easily, letters are as large as usual.

Comment: Please provide precise version information and exact steps to reproduce in a fresh kernel (in case there's something else to it than what you showed).

Comment: I am using version 11, and it is showing an empty list.  and How to put the screenshot, because I will put mine

Comment: "Version 11" is not precise. Please be accurate.

Comment: 11.0 is the  version I am currently using

Comment: There appear to be 5 roots. In M11.0 and earlier `NSolve` gives none, in M11.1 it gives one, and in M11.2 and later it finds all 5. This looks like a bug in earlier versions. As a workaround, I suggest you use `Plot` to identify the approximate locations and use `FindRoot` to get an accurate estimate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98606/discussion-between-acoustics-and-szabolcs).

Comment: If `NSolve[]` is not working, and you are constrained to earlier versions, try the methods in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/).