# Solve command does not solve this equation!

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to solve the following equation with Mathematica:

$\left(1-x^2\right) \left(n \left(x^4-2 x^2+5\right)-4 \pi  \left(x^2-1\right)\right) \sinh (\pi  x) \cosh (n x)+\sinh (n x) \left(\left(1-x^2\right) \left(\pi  \left(x^4-2 x^2+5\right)-4 n \left(x^2-1\right)\right) \cosh (\pi  x)-2 x \left(x^4-2 x^2-3\right) \sinh (\pi  x)\right)=0$

but the answer is:
"This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

I also tried Maple, the result was a long relation in terms of RootOf. 
How can I obtain an explicit solution for $x$ in terms of $n$?

```
(1/(4 (-1 + 
    x^2)^2))((1 - x^2) (-4 \[Pi] (-1 + x^2) + 
      n (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)) Cosh[n x] Sinh[\[Pi] x] + 
   Sinh[n x] ((1 - 
         x^2) (-4 n (-1 + x^2) + \[Pi] (5 - 2 x^2 + 
            x^4)) Cosh[\[Pi] x] - 
      2 x (-3 - 2 x^2 + x^4) Sinh[\[Pi] x])) == 0
```

Comment: can you add more information about the problem i mean the math problem what's more there!

Comment: is there conditions on x and n !!?? like been greater than 0 or Real or Integers !!??

Comment: $n$ and $x$ are reals and positive. Unfortunately, there is nothing more.

Comment: I modified the general equation. this is the most simplified form with all assumptions.

Comment: you need only to express x with respect to other variable n right !?
but you don't want the root of solution !

Comment: Please edit your post to include your equation as Mathematica code in InputForm.

Comment: I added the Equation in Mathematica input form. Yes, I just need to find $x$ in terms of $n$..

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes a solutions just does not exist in simple closed form primitives. You can try `Reduce` and see if it comes up with something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my answer to your [other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207694/731) question, this type of problem can be solved numerically using `FindAllCrossings` from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5666/731) answer.

```
With[
 {n = 1},
 FindAllCrossings[(1/(4 (-1 + x^2)^2)) ((1 - x^2) (-4 π (-1 + x^2) + n (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)) Cosh[n x] Sinh[π x] + Sinh[n x] ((1 - x^2) (-4 n (-1 + x^2) + π (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)) Cosh[π x] - 2 x (-3 - 2 x^2 + x^4) Sinh[π x])), {x, -5, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
 ]
```

> {-1.7736824298128102343}

What the function does is that it automates the method based on `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_, x_] := (1/(4 (-1 + x^2)^2)) ((1 - x^2) (-4 π (-1 + x^2) + 
        n (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)) Cosh[n x] Sinh[π x] + 
     Sinh[n x] ((1 - 
           x^2) (-4 n (-1 + x^2) + π (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)) Cosh[π x] - 
        2 x (-3 - 2 x^2 + x^4) Sinh[π x]));
```

`0` is a root for all `n`

```
f[n, 0]

(* 0 *)
```

For any root `x`, `-x` is also a root

```
f[n, -x] == -f[n, x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Finding the roots for specific values of `n`

```
sol = {#, Solve[{f[#, x] == 0, 0 <= x < 3}, x, Reals]} & /@ 
   Range[1/4, 15, 1/4];

ListPlot[Thread[{#[[1]], x /. #[[2]]}] & /@ sol,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"n", "roots"})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**supplement to @Bob Hanlon 's answer**

`ContourPlot` shows the possible solution directly:

```
ContourPlot[f[n, x] == 0, {n, 0, 15}, {x, -5, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**addendum**

The solution `x[n]` is evaluated using `NDSolve` in a given range of x.
The number  of solutions changes with n, that's why only pointwice solution is calculated:

```
sol[n_] :=  NSolve[{f[n, x] == 0, 0.5 < x < 5}, x, Reals  ]
nx = Flatten[Table[Map[{n, x /. # } &, sol[n]], {n, .1, 10,.1}], 1];
```

Comment: Increasing the `PlotPoints`, e.g., `PlotPoints -> 25` provides a more complete plot.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you so much. these plots can help me to solve the problem. But, the main problem for me is to obtain a general expression for $x$ in terms of $n$, I mean find $x=f(n)$ as a solution of the above equation.

Comment: @UrichNeumann Thank you so much. these plots can help me to solve the problem. But, the main problem for me is to obtain a general expression for x in terms of n, I mean find x=f(n) as a solution of the above equation.

Comment: @Baran Try `sol[n_] := NSolve[{f[n, x] == 0, 0.5 < x < 5}, x, Reals]` which gives you all solutions inside the prescribed x-range