# Is there an alternative way to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Any suggestions to obtain $x$ in terms of $n$ in this equation. Again Mathematica gives: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

$\coth (\pi  x) \coth (n x)-\frac{x^4-2 x^2+5}{4 \left(x^2-1\right)}=0$

```
Coth[n x] Coth[\[Pi] x] - (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)/(4 (-1 + x^2)) == 0
```

Any comment to solve this equation is welcomed.

Comment: `ContourPlot`? Then you can use `FindRoot` with initial guess from that curve.

Comment: I need to obtain an explicit expression for $x$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: Are you certain it's solvable? A lot of transcendental equations can't be solved analytically so you have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: @Alx would you explain more?

Comment: @MassDefect no, I am not sure!

Comment: @Baran, the idea is the same as in answer to another your question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207689/solve-command-does-not-solve-this-equation): use `ContourPlot` to see all the picture and solve numerically then. I'm afraid there is no analythic expression of `x(n)`, this can be done only numerically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for an analytical solution for a problem where it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that the type of numeric search, based on `ContourPlot`, that others mention in the comments, has been automated by Wagon, in his book, *Mathematica in Action*. J.M. gives a version of Wagon's function in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5666/731) answer.

Using his function, we get the following:

```
With[{n = 1},
 FindAllCrossings[Coth[n x] Coth[π x] - (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)/(4 (-1 + x^2)), {x, -5, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
 ]
```

> `{-1.9201894111730777583, -1.5082193798592498308}`

Let's check to make sure that the solution are ok:

```
With[{n = 1},
 Coth[n x] Coth[π x] - (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)/(4 (-1 + x^2)) /. 
  x -> -1.92018941117307775830055191944881406955`20.
 ]
```

> 0.*10^-20

```
With[{n = 1},
 Coth[n x] Coth[\[Pi] x] - (5 - 2 x^2 + x^4)/(4 (-1 + x^2)) /. 
  x -> -1.50821937985924983076925593990549242151`20.
 ]
```

> 0.*10^-19

Yup, it seems to be working.