# Efficient way to list zeroes of an oscillating function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, prime-numbers

From "[The First 50 Million
Prime Numbers](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF03039306/fulltext.pdf)" by Don Zagier: primes are integral roots of$$
1-\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi\Gamma(s)}s)}{\sin(\frac\pi s)}.
$$
The graph of this function looks like

[image]

I would like to produce the sequence of all positive real roots of this function in a given interval (say, from 10 to 12), with some given precision (say, $10^{-10}$). What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: What about `NSolve[{1 == Sin[Pi Gamma[s]/s]/Sin[Pi/s], 10 < s < 12}, s, Reals,WorkingPrecision->10]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Looks impressive, but 11 must be among the roots, and with me it goes like ..., 10.99682955, 10.99852262, 11.00128148, 11.00147394, ...

Comment: Since you are only interested in integral roots: `Solve[{1 == Sin[Pi Gamma[s]/s]/Sin[Pi/s], 10 < s < 12}, s, Integers]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[s_] = 1 - Sin[Pi Gamma[s]/s]/Sin[Pi/s];
```

Since you are interested in integral roots

```
sol = s /. Solve[{f[s] == 0, 2 <= s < 100}, s, Integers]

{* {2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
    61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97} *)
```

The integral roots are prime

```
And @@ PrimeQ[sol]

(* True *)
```

These are all of the primes in the interval

```
Rest@sol == Prime@Range[Length@sol - 1]

(* True *)

Rest@sol == NestList[NextPrime, 2, Length@sol - 2]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** To find the real roots use high precision for calculations, then reduce the precision for display.

```
solr = NSolve[{f[s] == 0, 10 < s < 12}, s, WorkingPrecision -> 100,
   VerifySolutions -> True];
```

Verifying the solutions

```
And @@ (f[s] == 0 /. solr)

(* True *)
```

The roots are dense

```
Length@solr

(* 1490 *)
```

Nonetheless, `NSolve` misses the integral root.

```
solr[[740 ;; 750]] // N

(* {{s -> 10.9867}, {s -> 10.9912}, {s -> 10.9924}, {s -> 10.9929}, {s -> 
   10.9968}, {s -> 10.9985}, {s -> 11.0013}, {s -> 11.0015}, {s -> 
   11.0024}, {s -> 11.0032}, {s -> 11.0033}} *)

f[11]

(* 0 *)
```

Combining the real and integral solutions

```
sol = Join[solr,
    Solve[{f[s] == 0, 10 < s < 12}, s, Integers]] //
   SortBy[#, Last] &;

sol[[740 ;; 750]] /. x_Real :> N[x]

(* {{s -> 10.9867}, {s -> 10.9912}, {s -> 10.9924}, {s -> 10.9929}, {s -> 
   10.9968}, {s -> 10.9985}, {s -> 11}, {s -> 11.0013}, {s -> 11.0015}, {s -> 
   11.0024}, {s -> 11.0032}} *)
```

Alternatively, do a search with [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
solf = Union[
   FindRoot[f[s] == 0, {s, #},
      WorkingPrecision -> 100] & /@
    Range[10, 12, 10^-4],
   SameTest ->
    (Abs[#1[[1, -1]] - #2[[1, -1]]] < 10^-4 &)];
```

This is much slower but identifies many more roots

```
Length@solf

(* 12440 *)
```

including the integral root

```
solf[[6200 ;; 6205]] // N

(* {{s -> 10.9996}, {s -> 10.9998}, {s -> 11.}, {s -> 11.0002}, {s -> 
   11.0003}, {s -> 11.0005}} *)

solf[[6202]]

(* {s -> 11.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the highly oscillatory nature of the function under consideration, an `NDSolve[]`-based method with event location (discussed by Daniel in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5680)) seems appropriate, as it is [more likely to be careful](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47776) about traversing the function under consideration. Of course, the price to pay for this carefulness is that the evaluations take quite a while.

```
zagier[u_] := 1 - Sin[π Gamma[u]/u]/Sin[π/u]

With[{u0 = 10, u1 = 12}, 
     AbsoluteTiming[rts = Reap[NDSolve[{y'[u] == zagier'[u], y[u0] == zagier[u0], 
                                        WhenEvent[y[u] == 0, Sow[u],
                                                  "LocationMethod" -> "Brent"]},
                                       {}, {u, u0, u1}, MaxSteps -> ∞,
                                       WorkingPrecision -> 20]][[-1, 1]];]]
   {36267.7, Null}

Length[rts]
   3290112

Norm[zagier[Take[rts, 10]], ∞]
   1.95*10^-9

Norm[zagier[Take[rts, -10]], ∞]
   0.0013240266
```

We see that the accuracy has degraded for the larger roots; one can still use these results as seeds for `FindRoot[]` to polish, however.

```
Nearest[rts, 11]
   {10.999999999995645962}
```