# Creating an interpolation matrix efficiently

Tags: matrix, numerics, interpolation, arbitrary-precision

I would like to know if there is a fast way to create the following matrix (note that the matrix is defined with arbitrary precision):

```
ny=500;
nyt=ny-100;
$MinPrecision=100;
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
If[ny == nyt,
  Miy = IdentityMatrix[ny + 1]
  ,
  ct[j_] := If[j == 0 || j == nyt, 2, 1];
  Cm = Table[
    N[2/(nyt ct[j] ct[i]) Cos[(i j \[Pi])/nyt], $MinPrecision], {i, 0,
      nyt}, {j, 0, nyt}];
  Cm = If[ny - nyt == 0, Cm, 
    Flatten[Join[{Cm, ConstantArray[0, {ny - nyt, nyt + 1}]}], 1]];
  CIm = Table[
    N[Cos[(i j \[Pi])/ny], $MinPrecision], {i, 0, ny}, {j, 0, ny}];
  Miy = CIm.Cm;
  Clear[ct, Cm, CIm];
  Print[" Delta t= ", AbsoluteTime[] - t1];
  Clear[t1]
  ];
```

This matrix is needed to interpolate (via matrix multiplication) a function `f(x)` defined on a Chebyshev grid with `nyt` points, into a Chebyshev grid with `ny` points, with `nyt>ny`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that one should use the fast Fourier transform instead of matrix-vector multiplication for that, but I am not knowledgable enough to work out the details.

Comment: By the way: have you run your code? It throws plenty of errors. Please be sure that it is correct before you ask other people for their investment.

Comment: For some reason, when I copied the string $MinPrecision into into StackExchanged, it got transformed into MinPrecision. It has been amended. It runs on my machine without any errors. Just takes way too long to run.

Comment: If you look at the first code block [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89692/4999), then variable `cc` contains the coefficients of the Chebyshev expansion of the interpolating polynomial at the Chebyshev nodes.

Comment: Thanks Michael. In your link, you seem to have access to ```f``` as a function, but in my case I only know ```f``` at some number of points ```nyt<ny```.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this matrix you're constructing?