# How to solve an algebraic equation with InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, interpolation

How to solve the equation `f[t]==0` for the function `f[t]` defined by differential equation,i.e. if `f[t]` is no analytic? That means that `f[t]` is the form `InterpolatingFunction`

For a dynamic system defined by differential equations, I find the inflection points, extremes et.c. For instance, let the system is the SIR model.

```
 β = 1.5; γ = 1/3; i0 = 0.001;
  sol = NDSolve[
  {s'[t] == -β*s[t]*i[t],
  i'[t] == β*s[t]*i[t] - γ*i[t],
  r'[t] == γ*i[t],
  i[0] == i0, r[0] == 0, s[0] == 1 - i0},
 {s, i, r},
 {t, 0, 104}]
```

The system has no exact algebraic solution. The output is in the form

`{{s -> InterpolatingFunction[...], i -> InterpolatingFunction[...], r -> InterpolatingFunction[...]}`

However. the `Solve` don't work as so as `NSolve`, `Reduce` et.c. Some failed attempts to find numerically a maxima of `i[t]`, i.e. solving the equation
 $$ \beta  i(t) s(t)-\gamma  i(t)=0. $$

```
NSolve[((β*s[t]*i[t] - γ*i[t]) /. sol) == 0., t]
NSolve[(Evaluate@(β*s[t]*i[t] - γ*i[t]) /. sol ) == 0., t]
NSolve[(Evaluate@(β*s[t]*i[t] - γ*i[t]) /. sol /. 
t -> τ ) == 0., τ]
...
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `NSolve` (and `Solve`) can't handle this equation involving `InterpolatingFunction` (at least now), but it's not hard to circumvent. The basic approach is to observe the plot to find the rough position of the root and use `FindRoot`:

```
eq = (β s[t] i[t] - γ i[t])

Plot[eq /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 104}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[eq /. sol, {t, 0, 15}]

(* {t -> 7.13011} *)
```

Notice the initial guess of `FindRoot` needs to be set carefully. You may also want to try the functions in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5663/1871).

Then here comes the slightly advanced solution:

```
Last@Reap@NDSolve[{s'[t] == -β s[t] i[t], 
    i'[t] == β s[t] i[t] - γ i[t], r'[t] == γ i[t], i[0] == i0, 
    r[0] == 0, s[0] == 1 - i0, WhenEvent[eq == 0 // Evaluate, Sow@t]}, {s, i, r}, {t, 0, 
    104}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]

(* {{7.1301355405901063248884664090806}} *)
```

The `WorkingPrecision` option is necessary or fake root will be found. (As we can see from the plot, the solution is so close to zero when `t` gets large. )

Comment: If only maxima of `i[t]` are required, `WhenEvent[i'[t] < 0, Sow@t]` works nicely (no extra `WorkingPrecision` needed).

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.

Comment: Event location is indeed the best method here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a difficult task!

Look at the plot

```
Plot[((\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t] - \[Gamma]*i[t]) /. sol)[[1]], {t, 0, 104},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

There "zeros" of your equation aren't well defined.

Perhaps you better look for the minimal time your equation approaches zero?

```
NMinimize[{t, ((\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t] - \[Gamma]*i[t]) /.  sol)[[1]]^2 < .001,10< t < 104}, t]
(*{13.2505, {t -> 13.2505}}*)
```

Comment: However, the `NSolve[(Evaluate@(\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t] - \[Gamma]*i[t]) /. sol ) == 
  0., t, 3.]`  does not work as well. I think the problem is not in the actual function `i[t]' but its presentation as 'InterpolatingFunction'

Comment: Perhaps  interpolation function are the problem for `NSolve` but you can solve it with `FindRoot` or `NMinimize`.  Look at the plot. Perhaps you have to help Mathematica a little bit. Are you looking for zeros `t>20` or `5<t<10`?

Comment: The `InterpolatingFunction`s are the problem. A simple example: `f = FunctionInterpolation[x, {x, -6, 6}];
g = FunctionInterpolation[2 x, {x, -6, 6}];
NSolve[f[x] + g[x] == 0, x]` Please see my answer for more details.