# Why does NSolve give singularities as solutions for this transcendental equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have this (rather long) transcendental equation, that has multiple singularities where it goes to infinity, then reappears at negative infinity. When I try and find the roots of the equation via NSolve (or Reduce), it gives me the positions of the singularities as well as the zero crossings, which is incorrect:

[image]

However, when I look for a single root with FindRoot, it will only give me the position of a zero crossing, even if I give FindRoot a singularity as the search point.
My question is - what command can I use to get the correct results I am getting from FindRoot, except for all roots within a certain domain, rather than one at a time?
And my second question is, why are NSolve and Reduce giving me singularities as solutions when they are not solutions?

Here is my code - transcendental equation:

```
resonanceCondition = (1.0215026378769585`*^-7 Cos[
    0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  0.012261290032792185` Sqrt[f] Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  367.9364783156771` f Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  1.7385441873343195`*^-12 f^(3/2) Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  1.9168458821735513`*^11 f^2 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  0.000905985363774135` f^(5/2) Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  27.186785669459642` f^3 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  3.5778253945592175`*^-17 f^(7/2) Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  7.294985015701372`*^9 f^4 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  1.349642838920257` f^(9/2) Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  0.0005593326523029028` f^5 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  7.617136885646142`*^-25 f^(11/2) Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  145698.31404595848` f^6 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  3.968314731945664`*^-16 f^(13/2) Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  1.190810871788677`*^-11 f^7 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  0.003101895368576676` f^8 Cos[
    0.038659981280734605` f] + (1.0215026378769585`*^-7 + 
     0.012261290032792185` Sqrt[f] + 367.9364783156771` f + 
     1.73854418733432`*^-12 f^(3/2) + 
     1.916845882173552`*^11 f^2 + 
     0.0008919683885642353` f^(5/2) + 26.766164635165886` f^3 - 
     3.577825394559219`*^-17 f^(7/2) + 
     7.075853251101013`*^9 f^4 - 1.349642838920257` f^(9/2) - 
     0.0005593326523029029` f^5 - 
     7.617136885646143`*^-25 f^(11/2) - 145698.31404595854` f^6 - 
     3.968314731945666`*^-16 f^(13/2) - 
     1.190810871788677`*^-11 f^7 - 
     0.0031018953685766773` f^8) Cosh[
    2.8222`*^-11 + 1.6937701111797905`*^-6 Sqrt[f]] - 
  3.9263268389666276`*^-8 f Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  0.00471284462232609` f^(3/2) Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  141.42292112410644` f^2 Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  9.035967129830372`*^-7 f^(5/2) Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  7.422693884237215`*^10 f^3 Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  470.7485518941833` f^(7/2) Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  0.04187499717395471` f^4 Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  1.8614725761418453`*^-11 f^(9/2) Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  2.1815699347445037`*^7 f^5 Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
  0.009697750162420625` f^(11/2) Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  8.2863`*^-10 f^6 Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
  0.4316929951106164` f^7 Sin[
    0.038659981280734605` f] + (2.866240292375598`*^-17 + 
     5.160603931704003`*^-12 Sqrt[f] + 
     3.0971854210038807`*^-7 f + 0.006196017403536449` f^(3/2) + 
     53.38370833435124` f^2 + 3.203873913991683`*^6 f^(5/2) + 
     0.020624423363802637` f^3 - 
     1.8346263052726576`*^-6 f^(7/2) + 
     1.0744746292968111`*^7 f^4 - 955.7888618948019` f^(9/2) - 
     4.248775821083848`*^-7 f^5 - 
     3.6303916368586526`*^-14 f^(11/2) - 
     221.34930665701606` f^6 - 
     0.00001891332246165412` f^(13/2)) Sinh[
    2.8222`*^-11 + 
     1.6937701111797905`*^-6 Sqrt[
      f]])/(f (5.329080691237708`*^-19 + 
    6.396596693986087`*^-14 Sqrt[f] + 1.9194891031013206`*^-9 f + 
    1.` f^2) (-1.2730400062331583`*^9 Cos[
      0.038659981280734605` f] + 
    3.007633699724958`*^-6 Sqrt[f] Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
    0.0902529952868547` f Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
    4.7019279839115955`*^7 f^2 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
    6.396596693986088`*^-14 f^(5/2)
      Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
    1.9194891031013215`*^-9 f^3 Cos[0.038659981280734605` f] + 
    1.` f^4 Cos[
      0.038659981280734605` f] + (-1.2730400062331583`*^9 - 
       3.007633699724958`*^-6 Sqrt[f] - 0.0902529952868547` f - 
       4.7019279839115955`*^7 f^2 - 
       6.396596693986088`*^-14 f^(5/2) - 
       1.9194891031013215`*^-9 f^3 - 
       1.0000000000000002` f^4) Cosh[
      2.8222`*^-11 + 1.6937701111797905`*^-6 Sqrt[f]] + 
    4.893155395016759`*^8 f Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] - 
    3.1263949972942227` f^(3/2)
      Sin[0.038659981280734605` f] + (-0.3572030481737306` - 
       21437.87990287647` Sqrt[f] - 71359.37236924547` f^2) Sinh[
      2.8222`*^-11 + 1.6937701111797905`*^-6 Sqrt[f]])) == 0;
```

Finding and plotting the roots with NSolve:

```
sol = NSolve[(resonanceCondition ) && 20 < f < 500]
p1 = Plot[((resonanceCondition) // First) /. f -> freq, {freq, 20, 
    500}];
pts = Table[{f /. sol[[j]], (resonanceCondition // First) /. 
     sol[[j]]}, {j, 1, Length[sol]}]; 
p2 = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p1, p2]
```

Comparing results with FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[(resonanceCondition // First) , {f, 165}]
FindRoot[(resonanceCondition // First) , {f, 164}]
```

Comment: Consider `Plot[((resonanceCondition) // First) /. f -> freq, {freq, 164., 
  164.4}]`.  Note the range of your plot and this one.

Comment: @MichaelE2 this means NSolve was correct, right? But OP said `where it goes to infinity, then reappears at negative infinity.` so I was wondering what is happening here. It looks OP then was wrong in this statement.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, I believe `NSolve` is correct.  The OP's plot shows the graph going to ±7, not to infinity actually.  I think the OP misinterpreted the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @MichaelE2. Your comment has definitely opened up a whole can of worms in my understanding of what this physical system is doing. Do you know why FindRoot is not giving the positions of the "singularities", then?

Comment: @Jeremiah, since you're finding the roots of a *ratio* of two functions, have you considered just applying `NSolve[]`/`FindRoot[]` to the numerator only?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties it turns out that NSolve's result was correct after all

Comment: Nevertheless, it would surely be less of a computational burden to just consider the numerator, unless you have good reason to believe that the numerator and denominator have common factors.

Comment: Update: turns out FindRoot[(resonanceCondition // First) , {f, 164.16}] actually does give me a root at f->164.163.

Comment: If you look at the plot in my first comment and keep in mind that to find `f -> 164.163` by Newton's method the initial point has to be somewhat closer to the root than the local max and min nearby, it should help to understand `FindRoot` with the different starting points `164`, `165`, and `164.12`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a long comment. Answer is given in comment above by @MichaelE2. The answer by `NSolve` is correct.

But if you want, you could always filter out solutions found, which are not as close to zero as you wanted as follows

```
sol = NSolve[resonanceCondition && 20 < f < 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sel = If[Abs[ First[resonanceCondition]/. #] >10*$MachineEpsilon, False,True] & /@ sol;
sol = Pick[sol, sel]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
p1 = Plot[((resonanceCondition) // First) /. f -> freq, {freq, 20, 500}];
pts = Table[{f /. sol[[j]], (resonanceCondition // First) /. 
     sol[[j]]}, {j, 1, Length[sol]}];
p2 = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just to add: it is possible to use the `MeshFunctions` capability of `Plot[]` to find initial approximations for roots, which can then be passed to `FindRoot[]` for further polishing, cf. [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663).

Comment: @Nasser I was just using sol[[1;;;;2]] to filter results. Turns out that approach was VERY incorrect.

Comment: @JeremiahRose I would suggest filtering based on sensitivity: `obj = resonanceCondition /. Equal -> Subtract; Abs[obj] < Abs[D[obj, f] * (f*$MachineEpsilon)] /. sol` (accept a solution if `True`) where $\Delta f = $ `f*$MachineEpsilon` allows for an error in the last bit of the computed solution for `f`.  Make $\Delta f$ larger if you want more tolerance.