# Passing RootSearch through NIntegrate?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to integrate a function that is itself a function of [`RootSearch`](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) (from the Wolfram Library Archive). Specifically, for a given value of parameter `t0`, I am using `RootSearch` to calculate a particular value (`FinalTime1`). This value is then used as a parameter for `Function1`. I am then trying to integrate `Function1` over all values of `t0`.

The code I have so far is as follows.

```
Needs["RootSearch`"]

a = 0.03; b = d = 1; d2 = 0; c = 0.5;
System1 = 
   ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == 
         Piecewise[{{X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*d*(X[t] + Y[t])/K1 - X[t]*d2,
             t >= t0}, {X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*d*(X[t])/K1 - X[t]*d2, 
            t < t0}}], 
        H'[t] == 
         Piecewise[{{Y[t]*b*(1 - c*g)*(1 - H[t]/HMax)*g - a*H[t], t >= t0},
          {-a*H[t], t < t0}}], 
        Y'[t] == 
         Piecewise[{{Y[t]*b*(1 - c*g)*H[t]/HMax + 
             Y[t]*b*(1 - c*g)*g*(1 - H[t]/HMax) - Y[t]*d*(X[t] + Y[t])/K1,
             t >= t0}}], X[0] == K1, H[0] == HMax, Y[0] == 1}, {X[t], 
        H[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0,5000}, {g, K1, HMax, t0}];
    
        
FinalTime1[g_, t0_, K1_, HMax_] := Module[{YTrajectory, Times1},
   YTrajectory = (System1[g, K1, HMax, t0][[3]]) /. t -> t + t0;
   Times1 = RootSearch[YTrajectory == 100, {t, 0.00000001, 500}];
   Max[Flatten[Times1][[All, 2]]]
]
        
Function1[g_, t0_, K1_, HMax_] := 
  NIntegrate[
    System1[g, K1, HMax, t0][[3]], {t, t0, t0 + FinalTime1[g, t0, K1, HMax]}
  ];
        
NIntegrate[Function1[1, t0, 2000, 2000], {t0, 0, 100}]
```

When I try this, I get a `RootSearch` error that says "False is not a well-formed equation." Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: What is `RootSearch` ? I see no such command in Mathematica 12.3.1

Comment: @Nasser RootSearch is a package one can download that allows you to calculate the roots of an equation.

Comment: Linking to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5663) in case you haven't already seen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RootSearch is a Mathematica package I wrote a long time ago and it can be downloaded [here](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/4482/). To install the definitions with a  recent version of Wolfram Language, I had to open (RootSearch.m) with WolframLanguage and click the button in the top right to (Run all code). To get this working, you should modify your code to use this:

```
RootSearch[YTrajectory[t] == 100, {t, 0.00000001, 500}];
```

where YTrajectory[t] returns a number when t is a real number. You may need to define YTrajectory[t] as follows

```
YTrajectory[t_?NumericQ]:= (* your code *)
```

Your code was too confusing for me to give more specific advice.

Comment: Thank you for this advice and for making RootSearch!