# How to draw some 2D curves in a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot several 2D curves (`Sin[x]` at `y=0`, `Cos[x]` at `y=1`) in a 3D plot, what function should i use?

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{0, y < 0 || y > 0}, {Sin[x], y == 0}}]
g[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{0, y < 1 || y > 1}, {Cos[x], y == 1}}]
Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen `ParametricPlot3D[]`?

Comment: In fact a more general question behind this is how to make a waterfall plot. I found some discussions [here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anybody_know_how_to_make_a_waterfall_plot_in_Mathematica_or_any_other_math_program)

Comment: To avoid analytic geometry, check out Graphics3D: Tube. Sometimes it is more useful.

Comment: `Plot3D` draws a surface, you need `ParametricPlot3D` with one parameter (for a curve) or points for `Line` and `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[u], 0, u}, {Cos[u], 1, u}}, {u, 0, 20}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.5, 2}, {0, 20}}]
```

[image]

**=== update - general thoughts ===**

I've seen the comments to this question and a few other approaches to the waterfall (or wire) plot are given in this question: [**Plotting several functions**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413). Also I cannot not mention one of my favorite Mathematica blogs - [**Archery with this post**](http://intothecontinuum.tumblr.com/post/27443100682) on the story of discovery of 1st pulsar and an its infamous graphics - code is given in the post:

[image]