# Phase portraits and StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I typed

```
StreamPlot[{y, x-x^3-0.3y+0.5Cos[1.25t]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

but all I got was a blank plot. What did I do wrong and can I fix it?

Comment: But I don't want to specify any value for $t$. Is there any other function I should use? Anything in 3D?

Comment: Related (similar system): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to specify `t` there is e.g. `ListAnimate` (or `Animate` etc.)

```
ListAnimate[ 
    Table[ StreamPlot[{y, x - x^3 - 0.3 y + 0.5 Cos[1.25 t]}, 
                               {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}], {t, 0.1, 2, 0.05}]
           ]
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like that would make an interesting bifurcation plot ...

Answer (score 8):

> ...Is there any other function I should use? Anything in 3D? – [Student](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/phase-portraits-and-streamplot#comment89206_28611)

One might stack the phase fields for a sequence of values of `t`, but as you can see, [Artes's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184) animation might be a better visualization.

```
Show[
 Table[
  Graphics3D[
   First@(StreamPlot[{y, x - x^3 - 0.3 y + 0.5 Cos[1.25 t]},
            {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
            StreamStyle -> Hue[Rescale[t, {-1.2, 1.2}]]] /. 
          Arrow[pts_] :> 
            Arrow[Transpose[Transpose@pts~Append~ConstantArray[t, Length@pts]]])],
  {t, -1, 1, 0.5}],
 Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also some of the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions) for more on combining 2D plots into 3D graphics.

Answer (score 8):

Or you could use the beautiful *LineIntegralConvolutionPlot* function - Documentation center link: [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{y, 
x - x^3 - 0.3 y + 0.5 Cos[1.25 t]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5},
ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rose"], StreamPoints -> 10, 
StreamStyle -> White], {t, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

[image: LineIntegralConvolutionPlot]

Comment: Blagodarq ti, Nikola.

Comment: Nyama zashto :)