# Plotting phase portrait from NDSolve (i.e., must plot x'[x], where $x=x(t)$)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm doing a double pendulum system and I wish to plot the phase portraits for each angle. I've successfully used `NDSolve` to solve for each of the angles. Let's just work with one angle.

What's confusing me is how $\theta$ is a function of time $t$ and I'm not sure how to "write out" $\theta'$ as a function of $\theta$. I've seen other questions and have read the answers on `StreamPlot`, but I find it a little confusing.

**My main confusion is with the actual arguments for `StreamPlot`.** I want to plot $\theta '$ as a function of $\theta$ (which itself is a function of $t$) over the range, say, `{t, 0, 100}`. But looking at the documentation for `StreamPlot`, it tells me I need `{vx, vy}` over `{x, 0, 100}` and `{y, 0, 100}`. I'm not understanding how I can turn this into something with only one variable `t`.

According to documentation:

[image]

I'm assuming we want to work with `{θ'[θ], θ[t]}` and (for example) `{θ, 0, 100}`, `{t, 0, 100}` which would "[generate] a stream plot of the vector field `{θ'[θ], θ[t]}` as a function of `θ` and `t`."

So I try:

```
StreamPlot[
 {Subscript[\[θ], 2]'[Subscript[\[θ], 2]] /. sol, 
 Subscript[\[θ], 2][t] /. sol}, {Subscript[\[θ], 2], 0, 
  100}, {t, 0, 100}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
]
```

[image]

I have no idea if this is the correct plot. I'm asking: is my syntax correct for the arguments of `StreamPlot` if I desire to plot $θ'(θ)$?

Edit: here is my code, though I'm more looking for a general solution to my problem of "how to put in the paramters into `StreamPlot`":

```
Subscript[m, 1] = 2;
Subscript[m, 2] = 1;
Subscript[l, 1] = 1;
Subscript[l, 2] = 4;
g = 9.8;
sol = First[
   NDSolve[{Subscript[l, 1]*
        Subscript[θ, 1]''[
         t]*(Subscript[m, 1] + Subscript[m, 2]) + 
       Subscript[m, 2]*Subscript[l, 2]*Subscript[θ, 2]''[t]*
        Cos[Subscript[θ, 1][t] - Subscript[θ, 2][t]] + 
       Subscript[m, 2]*Subscript[l, 2]*(Subscript[θ, 2]'[t])^2*
        Sin[Subscript[θ, 1][t] - Subscript[θ, 2][t]] + 
       g*(Subscript[m, 1] + Subscript[m, 2])*
        Sin[Subscript[θ, 1][t]] == 0,

     Subscript[m, 2]*Subscript[l, 2]*Subscript[θ, 2]''[t] + 
       Subscript[m, 2]*Subscript[l, 1]*Subscript[θ, 1]''[t]*
        Cos[Subscript[θ, 1][t] - Subscript[θ, 2][t]] - 
       Subscript[m, 2]*Subscript[l, 1]*(Subscript[θ, 1]'[t])^2*
        Sin[Subscript[θ, 1][t] - Subscript[θ, 2][t]] + 
       Subscript[m, 2]*g*Sin[Subscript[θ, 2][t]] == 0,
     Subscript[θ, 1][0] == Pi, 
     Subscript[θ, 2][0] == Pi/2, 
     Subscript[θ, 1]'[0] == 0, Subscript[θ, 2]'[0] == 0},
    {Subscript[θ, 1], Subscript[θ, 2]},
    {t, 0, 1000}]
   ];
```

Comment: You need to provide `sol` I'm afraid.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll provide more code, but I was mainly looking for a general solution to my problem. Like say I have `x[t]/.sol` and `x'[t]/.sol`, how would I plot the phase portrait?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Phase portraits and StreamPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/phase-portraits-and-streamplot)

Comment: @Artes what I"m not getting is how to actually put in the parameters for `StreamPlot`. I'm using that question as a guide but I'm not "getting it" for some reason.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue at this point (yes I have tried some other things and haven't gotten `Subscript` errors). The documentation for `StreamPlot` says to use `{vx, vy}`, and then a range for each `x` and `y`. My confusion stems from the fact that I'm using `{theta1, theta1'}` and a range for `t`.

Comment: If you want to plot $\theta'$ vs. $\theta$ for a specific known solution, what you want is not `StreamPlot`, it's `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: My last comment made it sound like that, but no, that's not what I want.

Comment: In that case, you should edit your question, because "I want to plot $θ(t)$ and $θ'(t)$, over the range, say, `{t, 0, 100}`" is precisely what `ParametricPlot` is for. `ParametricPlot[{θ2[t], θ2'[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MAgJO.png

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but immediately after that statement, I said I wanted $\theta' (\theta ( t))$. Anyways, I've tried to make it more clear. I'm just confused because the documentation calls for two functions, each with their own variable. In my case, I have two functions, both of the same variable.