# How to use mathemtica to plot phase portraits?

Tags: plotting

My question stems from exercise 4.3.3 in Murdock's book "Pertubations: Theory and Methods".

I am asked in the following:

Consider the problem $y''+y=\epsilon y^2$ $y(0)=\alpha$, $y'(0)=0$.
Draw energy and phase plane portraits.

How can I use mathematica to rdraw these?
I mean $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$ aren't given, do I need to choose numerical values for these?

The potnetial energy is $V(y) = y^2/2-\epsilon y^3/3$.

I am also asked to determine conditions on $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ under which the solutions are periodic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait) and (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/phase-portraits-and-streamplot).

Comment: @ChrisK I don't see it as a duplicate of any of them, in my question there are parameters $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ which don't have a specific numerical value, but a continuum of possible values.

Comment: I think you'll need to pick a value for ϵ in order to plot the phase portrait; α is in the initial conditions, which don't contribute to the phase portrait so that doesn't matter.

Comment: Multiply the equation by `y'` and integrate to obtain surfaces of constant energy, which can be plotted using `Plot`.  By the way, this looks like a physics or math problem, not a Mathematica problem.