# How to draw the following plot in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I have a function (x^2-9)^2. I can plot it with x-range{-3,3} so that three extremum s can appear in the plot. I add  another axis y ranging{0,10}. I want to plot the previous function (x^2-9)^2 at y=0,4,8. Obviously the last two will be the replica of the first one. Just have a look in the image for a rough idea..[image]

Comment: Try adapting this `Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[
  Cases[ #, 
    Line[L_] :> 
     Line[Thread[{L[[All, 1]], #2[[1]]/5, L[[All, 2]]}]], -1] &, 
  Table[Plot[(x^2 - 9)^2, {x, -3, 3}], {10}]], Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 600, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False]`

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are looking for is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions):

```
f[n_, x_] := (x^2 - 9)^2 + n
ParametricPlot3D[{x, #, f[#, x]} & /@ {0, 4, 8}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

For start introduce another parameter v:

```
  ParametricPlot3D[ { v,u, (u^2 - 9) ^2 }, {u,3,3},{v,0,8}, Mesh->10]
```