# Question in ParametricPlot3D, how to join the minima of a {x,y} function

Tags: plotting

Thanks to my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65493/1356) I have plotted the function with the following code:

```
a[x_, y_] := (x^2 - 3 - 9*y)^2 + 50*y^2
ParametricPlot3D[{x, #, a[x, #]} & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, {x, -13, 13}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 350, Boxed -> False]
```

Now I want to join the minima. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a[x_, y_] := (x^2 - 3 - 9*y)^2 + 50*y^2
```

**Plot3D with MeshFunctions**

Using a single `Plot3D` with multiple `MeshFunctions`:

```
Plot3D[a[x, y], {x, -13, 13}, {y, -.001, 12.1},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1,
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, 
          ConditionalExpression[Derivative[1, 0][a][#, #2], Derivative[2, 0][a][#, #2] > 0] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, {0}},
 MeshStyle -> Dynamic@{Directive[{Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}],
    {Directive[{Gray, Thick}], Directive[{Gray, Thick}]}} ]
```

[image]

**Plot3D with Exclusions:**

```
Plot3D[a[x, y], {x, -13, 13}, {y, -.001, 12.1}, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Exclusions -> {ConditionalExpression[Derivative[1, 0][a][x, y], 
                Derivative[2, 0][a][x, y] > 0]},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red, ColorFunction -> Hue,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}},
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[{Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}]} ]
```

[image]

**ParametricPlot3D**

```
soln = y /. Assuming[{x > -1/3},
    FullSimplify[Solve[{ConditionalExpression[Derivative[1, 0][a][y, x],
          Derivative[2, 0][a][y, x] > 0] == 0, x > -1/3}, y]]];
```

> $\left\{-\sqrt{9 x+3},\sqrt{9 x+3}\right\}$

```
b[x_] := {#, x, a[#, x]} & /@ soln
```

> { $\left\{-\sqrt{9 x+3},x,50 x^2\right\}$, $ \left\{\sqrt{9 x+3},x,50 x^2\right\} $}

```
ParametricPlot3D[{b[x], {x, #, a[x, #]} & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}},
 {x, -13, 13},  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Thick},
 ColorFunction -> Hue, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Because the local minima in $x$ are the zeros of the $x$-derivative, you could do something like this:

```
Plot3D[a[x, y], {x, -13, 13}, {y, 0, 12}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Derivative[1, 0][a]}, Mesh -> {{0}}]
```

[image]

This also includes the local maxima, but you can get rid of them by requiring the second derivative in $x$ to be positive. Then we remove the surface itself, and we have the lines you want:

```
Plot3D[a[x, y], {x, -13, 13}, {y, 0, 12}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Derivative[1, 0][a]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 RegionFunction -> (Derivative[2, 0][a][##] > 0 &),
 PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Use `Show` to put it together with the original plot.

[image]

---

The nice thing is that it still works when minima can appear and disappear:

```
Show[Plot3D[a[x, y], {x, -13, 13}, {y, -6, 12}, Mesh -> None, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6]], 
 Plot3D[a[x, y], {x, -13, 13}, {y, -6, 12}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Derivative[1, 0][a]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  RegionFunction -> (Derivative[2, 0][a][#1, #2] > 0 &), 
  PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, ClippingStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the minima with

```
pts = Transpose[Module[{yy = #, sol1, sol2},
     sol1 = FindMinimum[a[x, yy], {x, -13}];
     sol2 = FindMinimum[a[x, yy], {x, 13}];
     {{sol1[[2, 1, 2]], yy, sol1[[1]]}, {sol2[[2, 1, 2]], yy, 
       sol2[[1]]}}
     ] & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}]
```

and then show them together with your original plot

```
    Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x, #, a[x, #]} & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, {x, -13, 13}, 
          BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 350, Boxed -> False], 
         Graphics3D[{Red, Line[pts[[1]]]}], 
         Graphics3D[{Red, Line[pts[[2]]]}]
        ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I got you right, you want to plot two lines going through the minimums. If yes, try the following:

This makes the lists of the points of minimums:

```
 a[x_, y_] := (x^2 - 3 - 9*y)^2 + 50*y^2 ;
lstA = (NMinimize[{a[x, #], x < 11}, x] & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 
      12}) /. {c_, {Rule[a_, b_]}} -> {b, c};
lstB = (NMinimize[{a[x, #], x > -11 && x <= 0}, x] & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 
      8, 10, 12}) /. {c_, {Rule[a_, b_]}} -> {b, c};
lst3A = Transpose[{Transpose[lstA][[1]], {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, 
    Transpose[lstA][[2]]}];
lst3B = Transpose[{Transpose[lstB][[1]], {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, 
    Transpose[lstB][[2]]}];
```

and this makes a plot:

```
    Show[{

  ParametricPlot3D[{x, #, a[x, #]} & /@ {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 
     12}, {x, -13, 13}, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 350, 
   Boxed -> False],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[0.003], Line[lst3A], Green, 
    Thickness[0.003], Line[lst3B]}]

  }]
```

which is shown below:

[image]

Have fun!