# How to plot an implicit value funtion

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Previous question has been solved ([Gap in a continuous plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69976/gap-in-a-continuous-plot)). Here is a new related question.

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{6, 4}, {NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], 
       NormalDistribution[3, 0.3]}]

f[x_, y_] := y InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x + y]
```

**Given function `f[x,y]`, for any `x`, we can get the optimal value `y*[x]` to maximize `f[x,y]`. Notice: for some range of x, there are two local maximums for the function and we should select the global one. My question is how to plot `y*[x]` on support [0,1].**

The following codes may help you better understand what `y*[x]` looks like (**decreasing-> jumping up-> decreasing**):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[y InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x + y], {y, 0, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 2}}], {x, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[y InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x + y], {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, .5}, 
 ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Comment: Over what range of `x` do you wish to plot `y*`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, it should be {x, 0, 1}

Comment: You could make a `ContourPlot` of the zeroes of the $y$-derivative, like in [this previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65578/484).

Comment: @Rahul,could you please write down the code? I tried, but failed. There are two local maximums for some range and we should select the global one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Plot the objective function `f[x,y]` for 100 values of `x`:

```
plt = Plot[ y InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, # + y] & /@ Range[0, 1., .01], {y, 0, 1},
         Evaluated -> True, ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.1, 1}}];
```

Post-proces the previous plot to mark points corresponding to the global maximum on each of the 100 curves:

```
plt /. Line[x_] :> {Line[x], Red, PointSize[Medium], 
                    Point[Select[x, #[[2]] >= Max[x[[All, 2]]] &]]}
```

[image]

Get the points corresponding to global maxima:

```
ystarlist = Cases[plt, Line[x_] :> Select[x, #[[2]] >= Max[x[[All, 2]]] &][[1]], {0, Infinity}];

ListPlot[ystarlist[[All, 1]], Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"x", "ystar(x)"})]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using `NArgMax` (much slower than the above method):

```
ystarlist2 =  NArgMax[{y InverseCDF[dist, 1 - # - y], 0. < y <= 1. - #}, y,
    Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "PerturbationScale" -> 3,
      "BoltzmannExponent" -> Function[{i, df, f0}, -df/(Exp[i/10])]}] & /@ Range[0., .99, .01]

ListPlot[ystarlist2 , Joined -> True, Frame -> True, DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotStyle -> Thick, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"x", "ystar(x)"})]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

> *how to add the mirror image relative to 45 degree line*

```
ListPlot[{d1 = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]]/100, #} &, ystarlist[[All,1]]], Reverse /@ d1}, 
 Joined -> {True, True}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Blue]}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"x, BR(y)", "y, BR(x)"}),
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Style["BR(x)", 16, "Panel"], Style["BR(y)", 16, "Panel"]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Anyway to simply it? It's time consuming. Also, how to add the mirror image relative to 45 degree line?

Comment: @ben, producing `plt` takes some time, but it is much faster than using `NArgMax`. Re the "mirror image" please see th latest update.

Comment: @ben, you can speed up the plot by computing an interpolating function that approximates the inverse survival function a domain of your choosing, like this: `dsf[w_] = D[SurvivalFunction[dist, w], w]; nisf = NDSolveValue[{isf'[u] == 1/dsf[isf[u]],  isf[SurvivalFunction[dist, 10]] == 10}, isf, {u, SurvivalFunction[dist, 10], SurvivalFunction[dist, 0]}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2,Since I'm quite new to Mathematica, could you please post all the codes and the result? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kguler, Thanks very much!

Comment: @kguler, Which parameters should I change to adapt to a more complex distribution, like dist = MixtureDistribution[{2.5, 3, 4.5}, {NormalDistribution[1, 0.1],
     NormalDistribution[1.5, 0.1], NormalDistribution[2.5, 0.1]}];? I did try, but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @ben, it takes longer than the two-component dist, but you new dist with three components works in v9. Maybe you might want to play with  a higher number of x values in certain ranges.

Answer (score 3):

First some analysis.  The slowness is due to the time it takes to compute `InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]`.  `InverseSurvivalFunction` is a general purpose function and perhaps not optimized for mixture of normal distributions.  An improvement in speed can be obtained by using some calculus to reduce the number of times we have to compute `InverseSurvivalFunction`.  Another problem is that `InverseSurvivalFunction` cannot be differentiated in *Mathematica*.  We can again use some calculus to derive formulas for its derivatives.  In this approach we will use `NDSolve` to calculate approximations.  These should be fairly accurate, but if high precision is needed, one will have to adapt the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html) code or switch back to using `InverseSurvivalFunction` directly and put up with the slowness.  It may be possible to use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html), which usually can compute integrals more accurately than `NDSolve`, but that may be what `InverseSurvivalFunction` is doing anyway.

### Preliminary analysis and outline of solution

Let `sf` and `isf` stand for the survival function and inverse survival function, respectively, of our distribution `dist`.  The derivatives of `isf` may be written in terms of the derivatives of `sf` and the undifferentiated `isf`:

```
D[InverseFunction[sf][u], u]
D[%, u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the derivative of `sf` has a nice expression,

```
dsf[w_] = D[SurvivalFunction[dist, w], w]
(*  -(2/3) E^(-(50/9) (-3 + w)^2) Sqrt[2/π] - E^(-(50/9) (-1 + w)^2) Sqrt[2/π]  *)
```

we will be able use it to make more easily computed derivatives of `isf` with rules like the following (these will be adapted to our final code later, but I will need them in the present discussion):

```
derivatives = {
  isf[u_] :> InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u],
  Derivative[1][isf][u_] :> 1/dsf[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]],
  Derivative[2][isf][u_] :> -dsf'[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]] /
    dsf[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]]^3
  }
```

For a given value of `x`, one condition for a maximum of `y isf[x + y]` is

```
D[y isf[x + y], y] == 0
(*  isf[x + y] + y Derivative[1][isf][x + y] == 0  *)
```

Once we find such a maximum, its rate of change as `x` is governed by the **differential equation**

```
D[D[y isf[x + y], y] == 0 /. y -> y[x], x]
(*
  Derivative[1][isf][x + y[x]] Derivative[1][y][x] + 
    Derivative[1][isf][x + y[x]] (1 + Derivative[1][y][x]) + 
    y[x] (1 + Derivative[1][y][x]) Derivative[2][isf][x + y[x]] == 0
*)
```

where the first and second derivatives of `isf` are given by the formulas in `derivatives` above.  We can find initial local maxima for, say, `x == 1/4`, with `FindMaximum` by choosing convenient starting points.  Note we have to supply a derivative (via the `Gradient` option) for Newton's method to work.  Otherwise, `FindMaximum` will choose a non-gradient method, which will skip around more and will not always find the nearest local maximum.

```
FindMaximum[y InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x + y] /. x -> 1/4, {y, y0}, 
 Method -> "Newton", 
 Gradient -> {D[y isf[x + y], y] /. x -> 1/4 /. derivatives}]
```

We can determine the starting points by simply plotting `y isf[dist, 1/4 + y]`, or quickly scanning a table of values for sign changes of the derivative from plus to minus:

```
With[{signs = Sign@Table[D[y isf[x + y], y] /. x -> 1/4 /. derivatives // Evaluate,
                         {y, 0.01, 0.7, 0.01}]},
 Most @ Accumulate[
    Length /@ (Split[signs] //.
        {a___, n : {__?Negative}, p : {__?Positive},  b___} :> {a, Join[n, p], b})
  ]/100.
 ]
(*  {0.14, 0.57} *)
```

Feeding these to `FindMaximum` will yield the two distinct local maxima mentioned by the OP.

Once we have the two starting points we can solve the differential equation above.  It will yield two solutions for `y[x]`, each of which will trace the trajectory of a local maximum of `y isf[x + y]` as `x` varies.  Simply choosing the `Max` of these two at each `x` gives the `y★[x]` function sought by the OP.

### Implementation

For the above to work quickly, we need a way to quickly evaluate `isf`.  That is our first step.  It is done by integrating the derivative of the `InverseSurvivalFunction`.  This leads to the differential equation

```
isf'[u] == 1/dsf[isf[u]]
```

We need an initial condition, for which I chose a value for `u` very close to zero:

```
isf[SurvivalFunction[dist, 10]] == 10
```

Note that due to the nature of an inverse function, we do not even have to evaluate `InverseSurvivalFunction` once here.

```
Clear[isf]
dist = MixtureDistribution[{6, 4}, {NormalDistribution[1, 3/10], NormalDistribution[3, 3/10]}];
dsf[w_] = D[SurvivalFunction[dist, w], w];
nisf = NDSolveValue[
    {isf'[u] == 1/dsf[isf[u]], isf[SurvivalFunction[dist, 10]] == 10},
    isf,
    {u, SurvivalFunction[dist, 10], SurvivalFunction[dist, 0]}
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.019727, Null}  *)
```

In addition to the formulas in `derivatives` above (and repeated below), we will need numeric versions of them that use `nisf` above.  They, in `nderivatives`, should be used instead `derivatives` for speed.  In particular we will use them in the differential equation in previous section that gives us the local maxima as a function of `x`. It will take this form:

```
yeqn = Numerator[D[D[y isf[x + y], y] /. y -> y[x], x] /. nderivatives // Together] == 0
```

It is sometimes nice to get rid of denominators in an equation.  (Computer sometimes do not like fractions, just like people, although for numerical reasons.)  Using our starting points `{0.14, 0.57}`, we will find the local maxima and store them in `ics`.  These will each serve as an initial condition for each trajectory of the local maxima.  One might notice I used `derivatives` in the `Gradient`; it is because `nderivatives` produced a warning that I thought likely would contribute to error in the final result.

```
nderivatives = {
   isf[u_] :> nisf[u],
   Derivative[1][isf][u_] :> 1/dsf[nisf[u]],
   Derivative[2][isf][u_] :> -dsf'[nisf[u]]/dsf[nisf[u]]^3};
derivatives = {
   isf[u_] :> InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u],
   Derivative[1][isf][u_] :> 1/dsf[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]],
   Derivative[2][isf][u_] :> -dsf'[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]]/
     dsf[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, u]]^3};

yeqn = Numerator[D[D[y isf[x + y], y] /. y -> y[x], x] /. nderivatives // Together] == 0;

ics = y /. 
     Last@FindMaximum[
       y InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x + y] /. x -> 1/4, {y, #}, 
       Method -> "Newton", 
       Gradient -> {D[y isf[x + y], y] /. x -> 1/4 /. derivatives}] & /@ {0.14, 0.57};

{ysol1, ysol2} = NDSolveValue[
      {yeqn, y[1/4] == #},
      y,
      {x, SurvivalFunction[dist, 10], SurvivalFunction[dist, 0]},
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> True}
      ] & /@ ics; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == 0.38987189832043223`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

```
{0.163722, Null}
```

We get a warning `NDSolveValue::ndsz` which could be the end of the natural domain of one of the functions.  It turns out not to matter.  The integration has gone far enough that we can construct the function `y★` sought by the OP.  So I just ignored the message.

One way to get the function sought by the OP is to use [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaximalBy.html) to pick which of the functions `ysol1` or `ysol2` is greater at each `x`:

```
Plot[MaximalBy[{ysol1[x], ysol2[x]} /. 
    Indeterminate -> 1, # nisf[x + #] &], {x, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way is to construct a piecewise function, in which we have already determined when each function is the maximum.

```
x0 = x /. 
   FindRoot[
    ysol1[x] nisf[x + ysol1[x]] == ysol2[x] nisf[x + ysol2[x]], {x, 
     0.2}];
y★[x_] = 
 With[{yfns = SortBy[{ysol1, ysol2}, #[0.01] &]},
  Piecewise[{
    {yfns[[1]][x], 
     Simplify[
      Less @@ Insert[Flatten[yfns[[1]]["Domain"]], x, 2] && x < x0]},
    {yfns[[2]][x], 
     Less @@ Insert[Flatten[yfns[[2]]["Domain"]], x, 2]}
    },
   Indeterminate]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[y★[x], {x, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that with a `Piecewise` function `Plot` does not connect the discontinuity.  This might or might not be desired.  If not, one can add the option `Exclusions -> None`.  It appears from a comment that the OP is interested in plotting the function `y★` and its reflection.  Here is a way, with the segments of each graph joined because of `Exclusions -> None`; omit it if the segments should be disconnected.

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, y★[x]}, {y★[x], x}},
 {x, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Really really appreciate your effort and work. It's very clear!