# How to solve constraint differential equations using If function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have to solve a series of differential equations along with a constraint that has to be satisfied at each point of time where $t\in [0, 100]$ 
The model parameters are

```
β = 0.1; c1 = 10; c2 = 30; k1 = 100; k2 = 300; T = 100; 
δ1 = 0.1; δ2 = 0.3; Subscript[y, 0] = 1000; a = 4000; b = 200;
```

To solve the differential equations, I first assume that `μ[t]=0`solves the following in order to obtain $\lambda (t)$ and $x(t)$

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{λ'[t] == -((c1^2 - 4*k1*β*λ[t] - 
   2*c1*(λ[t] + μ[t]) + (λ[t] + μ[t])^2)/(
   4 k1)), x'[t] == -((c2^2 - 4*k2*(β*x[t] + δ1 (x[t] - λ[t])) - 2*c2*(x[t] + μ[t]) + 
   (x[t] + μ[t])^2)/(4 k2)), λ[T] == 0, x[T] == 0}, {λ, x}, {t, 0, 100}];
```

having `λ[t]` and `x[t]`, I calculate `ρ1[t]` and `ρ2[t]`

```
ρ1[t_] := (c1 - {λ[t] /. sol1} - μ[t])/(2*k1);
ρ1[t][[1, 1]];

ρ2[t_] := (c2 - {x[t] /. sol1} - μ[t])/(2*k2);
ρ2[t][[1, 1]];
```

Having `ρ1[t]` and `λ[t]`, `ρ2[t]` and `x[t]`, I have to solve the following differential equations where `

```
d[t_] := a + b*Sin[(2*π*t/25)];

s = NDSolve[{y3'[t] == d[t] - δ2*y3[t], 
y2'[t] == δ2*y3[t] - (δ1 - ρ2[t][[1, 1]]) y2[t], 
y1'[t] == δ1*y2[t] - ρ1[t][[1, 1]]*y1[t], 
y3[0] == Subscript[y, 0], y2[0] == Subscript[y, 0], 
y1[0] == Subscript[y, 0]}, {y3, y2, y1}, {t, 0, 100}];
```

The problem is my constraint is based on `ρ1[t]`, `y1[t]`, `ρ2[t]` and `y2[t]`. So only after calculating everything with the assumption of `μ[t]=0`, I can actually check my constraint to see if it is satisfied, the constraint is the following: if

```
d[t] - (ρ1[t]*{y1[t] /. s} + ρ2[t]*{y2[t] /. s}) >= 0
```

then `μ[t] = 0`.  Otherwise calculate the $μ[t]$ from below

```
μ[t] := (-2*d[t]*k1*k2 + c1*k2*{y1[t] /. s} + c2*k1*{y2[t] /. s} - 
 k2*{y1[t] /. s}*{λ[t] /. sol1} - 
 k1*{y2[t] /. s}*{x[t] /. sol1})/(k2*{y1[t] /. s} + 
 k1*{y2[t] /. s})]
```

and then I have to solve everything with from the beginning with new value of `μ[t]`. With `μ=0` I get something like this

```
Plot[{d[t], ρ1[t]*{y1[t] /. s} + ρ2[t]*{y2[t] /. s}}, {t, 0,
   100}, PlotRange -> {0, 6000}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"time", "d(t)-(ρ1(t)y1(t)+ρ2(t)y2(t))"}]
```

[image]

basically after the intersection point both lines should be adjusted (this should be taken care of by the new value of μ[t]) Is there anyways to code this model to check μ[t] at each point of time and see if the constraint is satisfied or not? do I need to create a loop to do this?

Comment: If you're using v10.0 or above, then you might want to look into `WhenEvent`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, no unfortunatly I'm using v9.0.

Comment: `WhenEvent` is in 9.  I think you will need to explicitly show the `u` dependance on `rho`, eg `rho1[t_,u_]:=..`

Comment: @george2079, the problem is I have first assume that $\mu(0)=0$ and solve all the equations to find $y1(t)$ and $y2(t)$ then check the constraint then if the constraint is violated then adjust $\mu$ and solve everything again. and this might happens several times in a planning horizon. any suggestion on how to write the code for this?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, sorry for typo mistakes. I addressed them in the edited version. the planning horizon is $t \in [0,100]$. I know that at least at one point of time my constraint is not satisfied i.e. `d[t] - (ρ1[t]*{y1[t] /. s} + ρ2[t]*{y2[t] /. s}) < 0` . what i have to do is at that point of time  i should calculate `μ[t]` and then go back to the first step and recalcuate everyhing based on the value of `μ[t]`.

Comment: At the end `μ[t]` seems to depend on `ρ1[t]` and `ρ1[t]` depends on `μ[t]`, which would lead to infinite recursion. Please clarify how `μ[t]` is to be defined. At first, it is just `0`, but why not omit it then? Or is `μ[t]` to be replaced at some point by another definition, and is `sol1` to be recomputed at that point?

Comment: @MichaelE2, at the beginning we start off by the assumption that μ[t] is equal to zero. but at a point of time that constraint is violated then I have to calculate the value of μ[t] from  `μ[t] := (-2*d[t]*k1*k2 + c1*k2*{y1[t] /. s} + c2*k1*{y2[t] /. s} - 
 k2*{y1[t] /. s}*{λ[t] /. sol1} - 
 k1*{y2[t] /. s}*{x[t] /. sol1})/(k2*{y1[t] /. s} + 
 k1*{y2[t] /. s})]` and then go back and compute sol1 based on the new values of μ[t]. so for example in the graph up to t=20  `μ[t]=0` is fine but after that I have to recalculate `μ[t]` and `sol1`.

Comment: I understood all that from the question. I guess I mean that your code does not reflect this "assumption," so I'm unsure how you implemented it. The following problem is confusing me: What is the definition of μ[t] when ρ1[t] is calculated? When you change the definition of μ[t], that changes the value of ρ1[t] and ρ2[t], which in turn might change when the constraint `d[t] - (ρ1[t]*{y1[t] /. s} + ρ2[t]*{y2[t] /. s}) >= 0` is satisfied. Do you mean to iterate the process and stop when it converges to a stable definition of μ[t]? Perhaps it just happens to work with a single iteration?

Comment: @MichaelE2, μ[t] act as Lagrangian multiplier in my model. Yes, you are right, so basically when as long as the constraints is satisfied with I'll continue with μ[t]=0 and when the constraint is not satisfied I have to recalculate μ[t] for that time onward. Obviously it should change ρ1[t] and ρ2[t] to satisfy the constraint again. I think i need to code some sort of loop. I'm not  sure if iterating the process do the job and how should i do it. I hope that I explained it better this time.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to change `μ[t]` everywhere, if the constraint is not satisfied anywhere, or that you need to change `μ[t]` only for `t` at which the constraint is not satisfied?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have to change `μ[t]` only for `t`  at which the constraints is not satisfied. so we have to switch from `μ[t]=0` to new `μ[t]` and continue with new `μ[t]` towards the end of the planning horizon.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  so lets say for `0<t<20` constraint is satisfied so we keep `μ[t]=0` and then at `t=20` we should  switch to new `μ[t]` and continue with that. I think depending on `d[t]` we might switch more than once.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I didn't completely understand the approach, and I'm not an expert in Mathematica coding. Is it possible for you to illustrate it?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thanks for the help tomorrow is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This interesting problem can be solved by iterating several times on `μ`.  (`WhenEvent` cannot be used, because this is a boundary value, not an initial value, computation.)

```
μ[t_] = 0;
β = 1/10; c1 = 10; c2 = 30; k1 = 100; k2 = 300; T = 100; 
δ1 = 1/10; δ2 = 3/10; Subscript[y, 0] = 1000; a = 4000; b = 200;
d[t_] = a + b*Sin[(2*π*t/25)];
y3[t_] = DSolveValue[{y3t'[t] == d[t] - δ2*y3t[t], y3t[0] == Subscript[y, 0]},
    y3t[t], {t, 0, T}];

Do[sol1 = First@NDSolve[
    {λ'[t] == -((c1^2 - 4*k1*β*λ[t] - 2*c1*(λ[t] + μ[t]) + (λ[t] + μ[t])^2)/(4 k1)), 
     x'[t] == -((c2^2 - 4*k2*(β*x[t] + δ1 (x[t] - λ[t])) - 
         2*c2*(x[t] + μ[t]) + (x[t] + μ[t])^2)/(4 k2)),
     ρ1[t] == (c1 - λ[t] - μ[t])/(2*k1),
     ρ2[t] == (c2 - x[t] - μ[t])/(2*k2),
     λ[T] == 0, x[T] == 0}, {λ, x, ρ1, ρ2}, {t, 0, T}];
s = First@NDSolve[
     {y2'[t] == δ2*y3[t] - (δ1 - (ρ2[t] /. sol1)) y2[t], 
      y1'[t] == δ1*y2[t] - (ρ1[t] /. sol1)*y1[t], 
      y2[0] == Subscript[y, 0], y1[0] == Subscript[y, 0]}, {y2, y1}, {t, 0, T}];
μ[t_] = If[.99 d[t] >= ρ1[t]*y1[t] + ρ2[t]*y2[t], 0,
            Max[(-2*d[t]*k1*k2 + c1*k2*y1[t] + c2*k1*y2[t] - 
            k2*y1[t]*λ[t] - k1*y2[t]*x[t])/(k2*y1[t] + k1*y2[t]), 0]] /. s /. sol1, {i, 5}]

Grid[{{Plot[{d[t], (ρ1[t] /. sol1)*(y1[t] /. s) + (ρ2[t] /. sol1)*(y2[t] /. s)}, {t, 0, T},
         PlotRange -> {0, 6000}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "d-(ρ1 y1 +ρ2 y2)"}, 
         ImageSize -> Medium],
      Plot[{μ[t], λ[t] /. sol1, x[t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {"t", "μ, λ, x"}, ImageSize -> Medium]},
     {Plot[{ρ1[t] /. sol1, ρ2[t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {"t", "ρ1, ρ2"}, ImageSize -> Medium],
      Plot[{y1[t] /. s, y2[t] /. s, y3[t]}, {t, 0, T}, Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {"t", "y1, y2, y3"}, ImageSize -> Medium]}}]
```

[image]

Several points are worth noting:

- The calculation of `y3` is independent of `μ` and can be moved outside the iteration process.  It is computed exactly here, although the gain in accuracy is negligible.
- `ρ1` and `ρ2` are calculated inside `NDSolve`, so that they are represented as single `InterpolatingFunction`s.  Otherwise, `FunctionInterpolation` must be used, so that recursive definitions of `μ` do not accumulate in them, causing the iteration to fail.
- A safety factor is needed in the definition of `μ` so that the sign of the first argument of `If` does not oscillate during the iteration.  However, this safety factor can allow `μ` to dip slightly negative near `t = 21`.  `Max` is used to prevent this, even though its effect is negligible.
- Convergence is rapid, yielding no visible changes to the curves after four iterations.

Edit: Simplified expression for `μ` and corrected typo based on recommendations by MichaelE2.

**Plotting Results for Several Parameter Values**

As requested in a comment below, curves for several values of a parameter (here, `δ1`) can be computed and plotted as follows.

```
Do[δ1 = j/10; μ[t_] = 0; 
Do[sol1 = First@NDSolve[
    {λ'[t] == -((c1^2 - 4*k1*β*λ[t] - 2*c1*(λ[t] + μ[t]) + (λ[t] + μ[t])^2)/(4 k1)), 
     x'[t] == -((c2^2 - 4*k2*(β*x[t] + δ1 (x[t] - λ[t])) - 
         2*c2*(x[t] + μ[t]) + (x[t] + μ[t])^2)/(4 k2)),
     ρ1[t] == (c1 - λ[t] - μ[t])/(2*k1),
     ρ2[t] == (c2 - x[t] - μ[t])/(2*k2),
     λ[T] == 0, x[T] == 0}, {λ, x, ρ1, ρ2}, {t, 0, T}];
s = First@NDSolve[
     {y2'[t] == δ2*y3[t] - (δ1 - (ρ2[t] /. sol1)) y2[t], 
      y1'[t] == δ1*y2[t] - (ρ1[t] /. sol1)*y1[t], 
      y2[0] == Subscript[y, 0], y1[0] == Subscript[y, 0]}, {y2, y1}, {t, 0, T}];
μ[t_] = If[.99 d[t] >= ρ1[t]*y1[t] + ρ2[t]*y2[t], 0,
           Max[(-2*d[t]*k1*k2 + c1*k2*y1[t] + c2*k1*y2[t] - 
           k2*y1[t]*λ[t] - k1*y2[t]*x[t])/(k2*y1[t] + k1*y2[t]), 0]] /. s /. sol1, {i, 5}];
ρ1sav[j] = ρ1 /. sol1; ρ2sav[j] = ρ2 /. sol1, {j, 7}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[{t, j, ρ1sav[j][t]}, {j, 7}]], {t, 0, T}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, .05}}, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, .7}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "10 δ1", "ρ1"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 14], 
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

and similarly for `ρ2`.  The plot design is based on the answer by Heike to question [1413](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions).

[image]

Comment: There are still syntax errors in the `Grid`...Check `FrameLabel`...Missing `{`: `FrameLabel -> {"t", "d-(\[Rho]1 y1 +\[Rho]2 y2)"}`

Comment: If you define `\[Mu][t_] = If[...] /. s /. sol1` with the replacements outside the `If`, you don't need `DependentVariables` and the code is shorter.  Some remark on how many times to iterate might be helpful, too.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your helpful suggestions, which I have incorporated and acknowledged.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's a very nice answer.  +1

Comment: @bbgodfrey- thanks, thats exactly how I wanted the model to work. its interesting because I was expecting to have jumps for paths `λ[t]` and `x[t]` when `μ` switches.

Comment: @Baboda  Thank you for accepting the answer.  `μ` enters into the equations for the derivatives of  `λ ` and `x`, so the derivatives change rapidly.  The variables themselves have rapid changes in their slopes, as shown in the figure.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I'm just wondering if it is possible to convert the pots into 3D plots in order to investigate the impact of constant parameters? for instance if I want to see how changes in `δ1 ` impact on `ρ1` and `ρ2`.

Comment: @Baboda  Any of the answers to [1413](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions) that involve a `Table` of 2D curves will do the job.  By the way, I believe that there is some much simpler way to solve your overall problem.  Perhaps, start by using `ρ1` and `ρ2` as the dependent variables instead of `λ` and  `x` in the first two equations, which would convert `μ` to source terms only in those equations and eliminate it entirely from the `y` equations.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I presented the solution based on the Pontryagain Maximum Principle hoping that I could t solve it analytically. So initially I wanted to find how optimal solution (`ρ1` and `ρ2`) behaves according to co-states `λ`  and `x`. I'm sure there are more ways to solve it but I'm not sure if I fully understand your suggestion. Btw, I still couldn't figure out how to generate a 3D graph from the answers to 1413 (sorry its my lack of experience in coding). how can I see for instance the changes in `ρ1` and `ρ2` over `t` for different values of `δ1`?

Comment: @Baboda  What values of `δ1` would you like?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Lets say delta1 changes on the interval [0.1, 0.7].

Comment: Done, based on the approach by @Heike.