# plot some functions versus a third variable

Tags: plotting

I have three functions as

```
For w=0.1   y=2 Cos[0.1 x]^2 + Sin[0.1 x]^4
For w=0.5   y=2 Cos[0.5 x]^4 + Sin[0.5 x]^2
For w=0.7   y=3 Cos[0.7 x]^2 + Sin[0.7 x]^4
```

the desired case for me is to obtain a plot such as below one that for different `w` I can have `y` versus `x`. How can I do that? (I accidentally saw this plot and is not related to my variables. Its configuration just is important to me)

[image]

[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/plotting-several-functions) is an answer but my question is different because the real positions for `w`s is not important. just legends can describe plots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func[.1, x_] := 2 Cos[0.1 x]^2 + Sin[0.1 x]^4;
func[.5, x_] := 2 Cos[0.5 x]^4 + Sin[0.5 x]^2;
func[.7, x_] := 3 Cos[0.7 x]^2 + Sin[0.7 x]^4;

ParametricPlot3D[{{x, .1, func[.1, x]},
  {x, .5, func[.5, x]},
  {x, .7, func[.7, x]}},
 {x, -2 π, 2 π},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
 ViewPoint -> {2, -2.5, .7},
 ViewVertical -> {.25, -.33, .9},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "w", "y"},
 PlotLegends -> {"w=0.1", "w=0.5", "w=0.7"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am so glad that I can see your answer. If `w` positions be clear the figure will be better, for example it is not clear what plot is related to `w=0.1` and so on (as legends). of course it is not important the exact value of `w` such as defined @ bill s. for example `w=0.1` can be not definitely in `w=0.1`

Comment: You can add options to the `ParametricPlot3D` so as to label the axes, or other such things

Answer (score 7):

Define a function y[x,w] of x and w and then Plot3D.

```
y[x_, 1/10] := 2 Cos[0.1 x]^2 + Sin[0.1 x]^4
y[x_, 5/10] := 2 Cos[0.5 x]^4 + Sin[0.5 x]^2
y[x_, 7/10] := 3 Cos[0.7 x]^2 + Sin[0.7 x]^4
```

Here's one way to plot:

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{w, x, y[x, w]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.01}, {w, 1/10, 8/10, 1/10}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Personally, when dealing with functions depending on a parameter I prefer the notation f[param][vars].

```
f[w_][x_] := 2 Cos[w x]^2 + Sin[w x]^4
```

You can plot f vs y for a given value of the parameter w

```
w0=.5;
Plot[f[w0][x],{x,-6,6}]
```

Or you can see how changing the parameter alters the value of f for a given x

```
x0=2;
Plot[f[w][x0],{w, 0.1, 0.9}]
```

Or you can have the whole she-bang with a Plot3D

```
Plot3D[f[w][x], {x, -10, 10}, {w, 0.1, 0.8}]
```

If your parameter has only discrete values, then you can create table of functions and plotting them all in a 2D graph.

```
funs = Table[f[w][x], {w, 0.1, 0.7, .2}];
Plot[Evaluate[funs], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Or in a 3D graph using one of the approaches suggested in the other answers. But let me add this procedure, taken from Bahder's "Mathematica for Scientists and Engineers":

> LinePlot3D[data_, opts___] := Show[Graphics3D[Line /@ data, opts]]

Its advantage is to be able to work on experimental data. To use functions like the one defined above, you need a simple line to generate the points

```
data = Table[{x, w, f[w][x]}, {w, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2}, {x, -10, 10, .1}];
```

and then you can plot the curves

```
LinePlot3D[data, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Done.
(EDIT: I just realized that ListPointPlot3D does what Table and LinePlot3D do, but in a single command - it wasn't there on version 2!)

Comment: I so much like this type of solution